# Why are there a lot of users with Reinstate Monica in the username?

Tags: discussion, users

Across all Stack Exchange network sites I have seen a lot of users with "Reinstate Monica" in the username, and I am not sure what this means.

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336283/377214) is the post that specifically asks users to adopt this in their username.

Comment: TechnicGoblin5R - The shortest possible answers is: because the company decided to remove a moderator. A thorough explanation and understanding of each of the more than 2 sides of the story won't be gleaned by reading a couple of links. Here's [one Q&A with 'reinstate group' posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335173/se-inc-director-of-public-qa-retweets-bad-faith-misrepresentative-tweet) not listed above. There are also *groups* (renamers) whom return weekly/monthly to explain that they will never come back. There are more sides than a disdyakis triacontahedron.

Comment: I see a non-sequitur between "Monica was mistreated" and "why someone adds 'Reinstate Monica' to their username".  *Why this issue?*  Why don't usernames instead say e.g. "Reinstate CC-BY-SA 3.0" or "Remove Inappropriate Advertising" or "No Mandatory Arbitration"?

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones No one bothered to make a post here urging people to change their names to support those causes. Also, there are holes in those cases: some people believe the license change to be legal, the six-month advertising test has since ended, and there is a way to opt out of arbitration, but there is no excuse for terminating Monica.

Comment: I'm just explaining why I feel this question (currently closed as a duplicate) is not answered by the duplicates and thus should be reopened.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones cause its easier to rally around someone folks know and respect - even many of monica's detractors are uncomfortable with the *manner* she was removed

Comment: The "agreement" post explains little to nothing; it's just legalese saying that they admit nothing and only regret that there was blowback.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Here's a good deal of insight:

- [Update: an agreement with Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio)
- [Stack Overflow is doing me ongoing harm; it's time to fix it!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/stack-overflow-is-doing-me-ongoing-harm-its-time-to-fix-it)
- [Monica's situation continues unresolved. Is SE hoping the problem just goes away?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335508/monicas-situation-continues-unresolved-is-se-hoping-the-problem-just-goes-away)
- [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper)
- [To reach out: on Monica, the Lavender community, and the future of the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336731/to-reach-out-on-monica-the-lavender-community-and-the-future-of-the-stack-exc)

In a nutshell:

Monica Cellio was fired from her position as a volunteer moderator for requesting clarification on a topic that was important to her. The request for clarification was taken the wrong way, and she was removed from her position as a moderator. She and other users want her back as a moderator and show their opinions through their usernames.

Comment: But it's not clear ! Clarification of what ? I can't stand reading all this argument about something very abstract. Did Monica object to, say, a transgender person being denied to call themselves 'she' rather than the 'he' they'd used at an earlier stage of life ? Is that what it's about ? Few would object to Monica or anyone else doing this. But all this vagueness and requests for clarifications is downright childish. Let's talk about the *actual problem* first, then the *actual response* off SE and what's wrong with that. We all know SE has always been fearful of taking a stand on anything!

Answer (score 11):

Thinking about it, there is even a much shorter and straight forward solution: turn to the profile pages of such users. Or at least, it should be that easy!

I do think that the large majority of users with such "Monica nicknames" also updated their profile page to explain the why!

Actually the whole point of the logo and nickname change was to get people to read the additional information given on the user profile. I admit that it doesn't work for all such users, but for many it does!

Comment: Then why not have a username like: `ReinstateMonicaClickToReadMore`?

Comment: Well, that would have been another approach 6 months ago. By now, this topic has come to an end, more or less.