# How best to find all my own posts where I employ pronouns?

Tags: support, search, code-of-conduct, be-nice-policy

Using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE), Google, or another tool, how can I search for posts, comments, and other content I've written over the last 11 years for common English pronouns?

Additionally, it would be nice if this were a network wide search because less than 25% of my posts are on any one SE site.

Comment: Searching for posts is easy enough using the normal search function. Comments, not so easy. But why bother?

Comment: You can use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1124222/user-specific-gendered-comment-count) to get a list of comments, or [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1124194/user-specific-gendered-comment-count) to see your gendered language percentage. Taken from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335164/360627)

Comment: This is a possible duplicate for [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335163/how-often-is-gender-actually-used-in-comments). (I cannot flag because I have suspended all moderator activities)

Comment: Eh, there's not really any tools for global search. Google doesn't let you find your own posts, and the global SE search doesn't cover user IDs too well. I can't search for my network ID anyway. SEDE might be applied, but that requires high-level SQL skills and knowing the database system as well as rene does, and for that bug that prevents cross-site queries from being executed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've written a [SEDE template for network-wide search](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1110482/networkwide-search-template) a while ago. I guess [this version](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1138215/networkwide-search-for-pronouns) is a reasonable approximation for your request.

Some caveats:

- only does common English (third-person) pronouns, as requested
- doesn't account for pronouns used in quoted text ([this](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/49063/12315) is one of the first hits when running it for my account)
- may yield false positives when you've posted content in another language than English
- SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning, so the results might be a little bit outdated

Comment: Might want to also add to the caveats that since `LIKE` is case sensitive, you won't get any pronouns with capital letters (like at the beginning of a sentence).

Comment: @scohe001 `LIKE` is usually case sensitive but I've specified a case-insensitive collation with `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` so that's not a problem right now :)

Comment: Ahh I was wondering what the point of those were. TIL. :)

Comment: As I am sure you know if the OP posts on language sites there will be false drops like 'he' in Spanish. I imagine the OP knows too but it can bite you.