# What tag is used for Stack Exchange rules and their respective enforcement instruments?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, stack-exchange, meta

Each site has a Tour, a Help Center and meta sites having [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) where the site's purpose, workings and features of the Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange system are explained. Also, there is [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/1359324).

Most of the content doesn't include **hard rules**; instead, they are written as guidance and provide instructions about how it's intended that each community works and how to use the system features. Tours, help center articles, [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and [moderator-faq](/questions/tagged/moderator-faq) explain the rules.

The tour, the Help Center homepage and some help articles can be customized to fit each community's needs, but most content is the same. Some might have variations to fit the community vocabulary according to their audience based on the work of their *core community* and under the guidance of the Community Managers.

Is there a tag for the Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange sites' posts about the standard rules for all sites and their enforcement instruments/implementation?

Related

- [Fundamentally, what should a Question and Answer site look like?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335179/1359324)
- [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/1359324)
- [We are updating our Code of Conduct and we would like your feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388860/1359324)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be specific to SO, the programming Q&A site - are you sure you want the [[tag:stack-overflow]] tag?

Comment: @bobble I think that we should see https://stackoverflow.com as something different from the rest of the Q&A sites listed at https://stackexchange.com/sites. While they share the same core elements, https://stackoverflow.com has several features and circumstances that are very different. I think that in questions like this, [tag:stack-overflow] and [tag:stack-exchange] should be used together instead of only using [tag:stack-exchange]. I think that the alternative might be to have "tiers" similar to those used in freemium services, like "basic", "technology", "Stack Overflow" and SOFT.

Comment: @bobble Probably, we should make room for one or two tags [tag:faq-proposed] (suggested ~1hr ago by [Oleg Valter is with Ukraine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388949/what-is-the-tag-used-for-stack-exchange-rules-and-their-respective-enforcement-i#comment1297047_388950)) and/or [tag:meta-faq].

Answer (score 5):

No single tag is used in all posts about rules, policies, guidelines, community
standards, etc., common to Stack Overflow and all the Stack Exchange sites;
instead, there are several tags.

> Note: Use tables to reduce the vertical scrolling. Tags are not set in
> specific order other than putting the most extended tags in the first column
> for better visualization.

### Rules

| Rules |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [feature-request-process](/questions/tagged/feature-request-process) | [terms-of-service](/questions/tagged/terms-of-service) | [licensing](/questions/tagged/licensing) |
| [moderator-agreement](/questions/tagged/moderator-agreement) | [code-of-conduct](/questions/tagged/code-of-conduct) | [be-nice-policy](/questions/tagged/be-nice-policy) |
| [mod-agreement-policy](/questions/tagged/mod-agreement-policy) | [copyright](/questions/tagged/copyright) |  |

| Types of rules |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [community-standards](/questions/tagged/community-standards) | [policy](/questions/tagged/policy) | [rules](/questions/tagged/rules) |
| [best-practices](/questions/tagged/best-practices) | [etiquette](/questions/tagged/etiquette) | [behavior](/questions/tagged/behavior) |

| Places holding rules |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [per-site-meta](/questions/tagged/per-site-meta) | [tag-wiki](/questions/tagged/tag-wiki) | [tour](/questions/tagged/tour) |
| [help-center](/questions/tagged/help-center) | [area-51](/questions/tagged/area-51) | [blog](/questions/tagged/blog) |
| [chat-faq](/questions/tagged/chat-faq) | [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) | [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) |

### Rule Enforcement

| Rule Enforcement Actors |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [stack-exchange-team](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-team) | [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators) | [users](/questions/tagged/users) |
| [community-managers](/questions/tagged/community-managers) | [community](/questions/tagged/community) |  |

| Rule Enforcement Process |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close) | [tag-block-request](/questions/tagged/tag-block-request) | [election](/questions/tagged/election) |
| [vote-to-reopen](/questions/tagged/vote-to-reopen) | [vote-to-delete](/questions/tagged/vote-to-delete) | [triage](/questions/tagged/triage) |
| [vote-to-undelete](/questions/tagged/vote-to-undelete) | [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) | [review](/questions/tagged/review) |
| [feature-request-process](/questions/tagged/feature-request-process) | [review-suspension](/questions/tagged/review-suspension) | [legal](/questions/tagged/legal) |
| [anti-recidivism-system](/questions/tagged/anti-recidivism-system) | [self-governance](/questions/tagged/self-governance) | [flags](/questions/tagged/flags) |

| Quality |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [question-quality](/questions/tagged/question-quality) | [answer-quality](/questions/tagged/answer-quality) | [quality](/questions/tagged/quality) |

| Rule Enforcement Algorithms |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [spam-detection](/questions/tagged/spam-detection) | [quality-filter](/questions/tagged/quality-filter) | [rate-limiting](/questions/tagged/rate-limiting) |

### Other

| Stuff not allowed |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [serial-voting](/questions/tagged/serial-voting) | [not-an-answer](/questions/tagged/not-an-answer) | [abuse](/questions/tagged/abuse) |
| [low-quality-posts](/questions/tagged/low-quality-posts) | [profanity](/questions/tagged/profanity) | [spam](/questions/tagged/spam) |
| [gaming-the-system](/questions/tagged/gaming-the-system) | [plagiarism](/questions/tagged/plagiarism) | [thanks](/questions/tagged/thanks) |
| [link-only-answers](/questions/tagged/link-only-answers) | [rollback-wars](/questions/tagged/rollback-wars) | [offensive](/questions/tagged/offensive) |
| [inappropriate-content](/questions/tagged/inappropriate-content) | [list-questions](/questions/tagged/list-questions) | [polling](/questions/tagged/polling) |
| [copyright-infringement](/questions/tagged/copyright-infringement) | [signature](/questions/tagged/signature) | [piracy](/questions/tagged/piracy) |
| [trolling](/questions/tagged/trolling) | [vandalism](/questions/tagged/vandalism) | [lmgtfy](/questions/tagged/lmgtfy) |

| Penalties |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [account-suspension](/questions/tagged/account-suspension) | [ban](/questions/tagged/ban) | [ip-ban](/questions/tagged/ip-ban) |
| [deleted-accounts](/questions/tagged/deleted-accounts) | [post-ban](/questions/tagged/post-ban) |  |

| Writing |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [spelling](/questions/tagged/spelling) | [grammar](/questions/tagged/grammar) | [english](/questions/tagged/english) |
| [writing](/questions/tagged/writing) |  |  |

| Bias and Stereotypes |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [fastest-gun](/questions/tagged/fastest-gun) | [problem-user](/questions/tagged/problem-user) | [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) |
| [experts](/questions/tagged/experts) | [bias](/questions/tagged/bias) |  |

| Iniatiatives |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [community-vp-questions](/questions/tagged/community-vp-questions) | [welcoming](/questions/tagged/welcoming) | [the-loop](/questions/tagged/the-loop) |
| [se-quality-project](/questions/tagged/se-quality-project) |  |  |

| Miscellaneous |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [stack-exchange-history](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-history) | [moderation-history](/questions/tagged/moderation-history) | [beta-phase](/questions/tagged/beta-phase) |
| [graduating-sites](/questions/tagged/graduating-sites) | [participation](/questions/tagged/participation) | [meta-faq](/questions/tagged/meta-faq) |

## Featured posts about rules

### Stack Overflow blog posts

- [A theory of moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)
- [Our Theory of Moderation, Re-visited.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/)

### Beta

- [The Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223674/1359324)
- [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/1359324)

### Guidelines for respectful conversations

- [It’s time to retire the term “rep-whore”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281787/1359324)
- [What does constructive criticism of a design change look like?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314089/1359324)

Comment: Consider making this a community wiki answer for ease of editing by low-rep users on MSE as the Q&A is basically a FAQ item?

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I'm open to making it a CW but before that would like some feedback from more experienced users like you. If you mod think that it's a good time to make this a CW, I'm OK with that. In the meantime, I would wait a few days or earlier if your comment gets more upvotes (at this time it has one).

Comment: No worries about the timing, it's merely a suggestion given that it already got a suggested edit. Let's see how it goes - might be worth making it a [meta-tag:faq-proposed] as well. I am a bit surprised it hasn't got any flak yet given my experience that such entries are often criticised as "excessive documentation", although I personally like such lists.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Maybe it's b/c the weekend :)

Comment: now have fun finding out the various variations of these wordings are used on individual site metas!

Comment: out of curiosity, why is there a section here on bias? Are you saying bias is not allowed? While that's a nice ideal and fits very well with the general "fact-based Q&A", how much of our guidance writings actually make points on bias specifically and explicitly?

Comment: @starball There is a specific section for stuff not allowed and an independent section for **bias**. Bias might cause two persons to behave entirely differently when facing the same situation and may lead to communication and behavior problems if they are not identified and appropriately discussed.

Comment: okay, ... but what does bias have to do _directly_ with the question you wrote here, which is "_What tag is used for Stack Exchange **rules** and their respective enforcement instruments?_". What you've shown is just an _indirect_ cause of problems. And since when do we police that as a _rule_, and not just by votes and constructive criticism in comments?

Comment: if you want to go as fine-grained as linking to things like the "rep-whore" post, then you're also missing a bunch of other posts, like https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137795/997587, other name-calling like "help-vampires", and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385093/11107541. I don't really get the need to go that fine grained. For points that are already covered by the code of conduct, just leave it at pointing to the code of conduct tag.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @starball . The name of the section, including links to posts, uses the word **featured** to clarify that the list should not be exhaustive; the feature posts are included to show the diversity of "rules" (as a broad concept), i.e., *hard rules*, policies, guidelines, community standards, etc. If you think there are similar posts to one of the already listed, please add a comment or an answer if you need more room to explain why that post should be featured and if that should be done instead of one already listed or added to the list.