# Perhaps someone from the Stack Exchange Leadership Team should hold a town-hall meeting?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, moderators

While Sara Chipps, the Director of Public Q&A, did make a [response to the Stack Exchange Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology), it has been very negatively received and the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag isn't enough to keep it visible to the broader network community. It also triggered [additional resignations and suspensions of moderator activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper).

Given that Stack Exchange is currently in the middle of on-boarding Prashanth Chandrasekar as the new CEO, perhaps it is time for someone from the [senior leadership team](https://stackoverflow.com/company/management) to schedule a [town hall meeting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Town_hall_meeting) to address the concerns of the community?

Comment: And do what? Double-down on their double down?

Comment: I really like this idea. Where?

Comment: @Oded if my math is correct, that's a quadruple down.

Comment: @SaraChipps Maybe it could be in a read-only chatroom where people can put in requests to ask questions and then they would be granted that permission.

Comment: to avoid SE staff from being mobbed with gotcha questions

Comment: Just bumping: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334015/an-open-letter-on-the-state-of-curation-and-moderation

Comment: @StephanS if they are afraid of being mobbed, they should not having a chat

Comment: @SaraChipps this will not end well.

Comment: Without an actual public apology first, what is there to say?

Comment: @StrongBad Maybe people would bring tar and feathers :-P

Comment: What about something sort of similar to moderator elections? Make a Q&A post where the "answers" are questions from the community. Highest voted posts get answers in a separate Q&A.

Comment: @Sklivvz I'm just trying to work within the mechanics of the site

Comment: @StephanS: But granted by whom? What if SE will avoid/ignore undesirable questions?

Comment: @Cerberus SE will avoid undesirable questions no matter what, might as well give them away to answer things on their term instead of not at all.

Comment: @TheWanderer: That sounds like an interesting idea!

Comment: If you're worried about the visibility of Sara's question (which is indeed problematic), then the solution is obvious. I hereby declare that I will put a 500-rep bounty on their question as soon as that option becomes available (42 hours plus change from now). Problem solved. Do consider, however, that more visibility on that question may not be the right move to make right now, as spirits are running high.

Comment: @SaraChipps The problem goes far deeper than Monica's accusation of failing. It began with restricting the community about moderation and curation of the site on behalf of gaining ROI for the company. You look just like canon fodder for me.

Comment: Perhaps another good idea would be to do an in-person televised debate between Sara Chipps and Monica Cellio themselves.

Comment: Perhaps someone from the Stack Exchange Leadership Team should give a sincere apology first?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog perhaps an actual *conversation* between Sara and Monica in private would be a good first step.  SE isn't taking my calls; I can't initiate that.  I still believe that there has been a profound misunderstanding that they could have fixed last week if only there'd been *actual communication*.

Comment: @user35594 What about the new CEO?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog We probably shouldn't burn Sara at the stake, the chances it was her decision to fire Monica from being a mod is very low, in other words, **don't shoot the messager**.

Comment: @StephanS The point of my mentioning Sara was *not* to indicate her as the one who made the decision, but simply as one who is familiar with SE's position on the matter.

Comment: OK, **stop asking for apologies.**  An apology and a dollar will buy me a cup of coffee.  *Ask for meaningful changes instead.*

Comment: @SaraChipps if you want my advice, start by addressing existing concerns before you start further discussion. There's a *lot* of questions to say the least that need to be addressed. With over 20 answers on the apology, there's a lot that needs to be addressed just there. Maybe clear that and start defusing the heat before you get more input to process? Going about the situation wrong after the "firing mods" meta post will only lead to further problems (and rightfully, at least so far).

Comment: A lot of people (including me) are angry. If that's converted into a chatroom and something goes very wrong (and, honestly, something tells me that's likely to happen), it will make the situation worse for all parties involved and the network as a whole. It's bad enough at this point

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'll buy you a cup of coffee, because you're right - there won't be any apologies

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's been pretty clear from the very beginning that along with an apology, what most of the community is asking for is that the existing procedures on CoC violations by moderators be followed. This would involve reinstating Monica and then following those procedures with transparency and community involvement. SaraChipps clearly admitted the policy was not followed, but dismissed the idea of following procedure. THAT would be "meaningful change". Saying, "we'll do better in the future" is NOT meaningful change.

Comment: @SaraChipps It's not too late to mitigate the damage SE has done, but stonewalling the community that is SE's lifeblood will not make this go away. You've admitted to not following your own procedures and that this situation was handled poorly. Therefore how can you possibly justify not even attempting to go back and doing it right? Imagine you were arrested, tried and convicted, but the court admitted you were not given due process. But then they said, "but what's in the past is in the past, let's just move on!"

Comment: @StephanS I've seen a lot of that "don't shoot the messenger" line lately, but I'm not buying it. If Sara didn't want to be in this position, she should not have accepted it. She should stand up for what's right. If someone wrote that "apology" and told her to deliver it, then she should have said "no, I won't do this, this isn't genuine. Let's listen to the community and come up with a real solution". Of course, it looks to me like she wrote it herself, so I don't think she's just a messenger.

Comment: @mason I think it should be stated that this is Sara's job, and the status of Sara's job depends on how situations like these are handled, we should understand that there probably pressure on Sara's from her higher-ups to fix this. I completely agree with you that we should take problem with the ton death responses lately but there really isn't a point of making Sara apologize for something that Sara didn't participate in because that apology would be as pointless as to if I apologize to you about Monica being fired as a mod.

Comment: @mason: It's more than that. Messengers are symbols. Not shooting the messenger is symbolic of basic trust in common civility. In some (extreme) cases, it may be more appropriate to do the opposite, e.g. expecting certain heads on platters (metaphorically of course) of people who have been insulting and disrupting, as a gesture of good faith.

Comment: @einpoklum Her job isn't "messenger". It's Director of Public Q&A. As in, the main reason the entire site exists. She's been promoting tolerance and acceptance of others, and her actions and inactions here are directly responsible for this community uproar, even if she isn't the only one at the wheel. This is an entirely self created problem - the company caused this. As the face of this company to our community, she needs to fix it, or step aside and let someone else take over.

Comment: @mason I'm kinda confused I can't seem to find any transcripts on that page...

Comment: @StephanS Agh, sorry. According to some of the comments there, looks like Reddit mods have removed the links because someone flagged them as containing sensitive/confidential material, since they were (giant) screenshots from the Teacher's Lounge chatroom the moderators use on SE, which is open only to mods/employees. Anyways I'll summarize:  Sara announced changes to the CoC (or changes to how it should be interpreted). Monica asked for clarifications from staff on how these changes would be enforced. Sara said their position was clear (but didn't answer Monica's questions directly).

Comment: @StephanS Some of the mods were challenging Monica's stance and eventually things deteriorated to the point where Monica felt she needed to leave the room because their viewpoints were incompatible. That's my best recollection of it anyways, I wish I still had the URL to the screenshots. I'm sure they're floating around somewhere.

Comment: @rjzii I'm not in the fight club, and not bound to any secrecy because I'm not a mod or employee. Stack Exchange (Sara specifically) [went to the media](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy), or cooperated with them (far more than with us), so I think being transparent on what actually happened would be best. Hence some whistleblower leaking this conversation to the public is a good thing, though of course there could be other things in the Teacher's Lounge that the generally community doesn't need to be privy to.

Comment: @mason Look Stack Exchange betrayed our trust, they've lied to us, told us we don't matter through their actions, even indirectly called us all idiots by expecting us to believe an apology that wasn't at all an apology but we still shouldn't insult one of their staffers, we should just walk away.

Comment: @StephanS I didn’t say we should insult her. I said she should be held accountable for her actions and inactions. If that’s insulting, well that’s too bad. If I make a mistake and someone points it out, I would be embarrassed. If that mistake actively harms someone or an entire community....don’t shoot the messenger pointing out the mistakes and asking for it to be fixed appropriately.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Related Meta post (relevant to your comment here): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334340/287826

Comment: @mason: She has not been promoting tolerance and acceptance for others. Other than that, I agree with you that Chipps should actually work to fix things or step aside.

Comment: For the benefit of everyone here who doesn't participate in US (I assume) politics, what on Earth is a "*town-hall style meeting*"?

Comment: @PeterTaylor you know, a lynch mob.

Comment: @SaraChipps these town hall style events have been done earlier in [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), you can find the announcement, procedure and topics of the first one [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278882/lets-experiment-with-town-hall-style-chat-events)  and the transcript of that first event [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/mse-town-hall-1-comments-part-1). IIRC it took quiet a bit of preparation for the involved CM's

Comment: @PeterTaylor My company does townhall-style meetings. Generally the CEO will stand on a stage in front of an audience of the company and frame the conversation, and say his statements, then some other execs will discuss particular topics. If there's time, questions from the audience are taken. These are livestreamed so that everyone in the company around the world can see it, and a chat is in place to ask questions they can answer for everyone. Politicians often do townhall-style meetings too, when they visit cities on the campaign trail. They're a chance for the common people to ask big Q's

Answer (score 71):

I don't see how this is any more meaningful or different than meta for this purpose. Town halls are for open conversations/discussion. Not preexisting questions.

In fact, in this case, I'd say this would be worse than nothing when there are so many clear questions on meta being ignored around the recent events.

Comment: also less public, just not what we need

Comment: And a chat would only open the door to abuse from the worst users.

Comment: The best and biggest questions on everyone's mind are floating at the top of the pool currently for all to see. In the words of Palpatine: "How ironic".

Comment: Imagine being able to be ignored in a real time public Q&A meeting.

Comment: @rjzii they just had like 3-7 days to work on this update/apology and this is what we got... as for other questions, they've had years, look through MSE/MSO and see the old questions and when they date from.

Comment: no one said the chat had to be a livechat, could be a super delayed chat where 3-7 days pass between each question @Script47

Comment: @enderland I can't tell if you're being sarcastic or not but why can't they just answer those questions..?

Comment: @rjzii they already have this option. Just be more open and communicate with us like they used to, no need for this new method. That option has never been removed from them they just seem more closed doors now.

Answer (score 44):

The only way this would work is if everyone agreed to put down their pitchforks or pointy implement of choice, and hear this from a neutral stance.

I...don't see that happening in the short term.  In fact, I see this as a prime chance for those who are just anti-Sara to simply throw her under the bus in any manner they can muster.

So how about *no*, we don't have a town hall on this. I for one am not interested in reading either side's arguments; not really keen on hearing for the umpteenth time about how things are gonna get better, and I'm not really keen on hearing about how such-and-such should've been phrased or how this should've gone or if heads should roll or any of that nonsense.

We've all got better things to do with our time.

Comment: A "Moderator questions and answers" style post would lend some much needed decorum and order to the proceedings... But yeah, I totally get what you are saying.

Comment: @RobertHarvey:  We lost the privilege for decorum and order on Sunday, if I'm going to be honest with you.  No sense in closing the barn door when that horse is already halfway across the county, y'know.

Comment: @rjzii:  I'm really not going to judge how long you've been in the corporate world, but every meeting I've had with leadership under these pretenses - both when directly facing them in academia and in the business place - it has been their MO to basically make "no" sound like "yes", and to spin optimism and hope while remaining intentionally vague.  I'm far too pessimistic to believe that anything that's conjured up *now* is gonna change that impression of mine.  Furthermore, I'm *really* not sure what you're expecting when that happens.  What do you want as an outcome/takeaway?

Comment: What neutral stance?  The rules are clear and published.  The actions taken by the parties involved are visible and can be inspected by anyone with an internet connection.

Answer (score 26):

> I believe there's a real urge that the new CEO introduces themselves to the community, and what are their plans to solve the actual problems.
> Meta is burning and many users are just confused.
> Don't forget: The community made the product you have right now!
>
> — Günther Makulik (@GntherMakulik) [October 3, 2019](https://twitter.com/GntherMakulik/status/1179882130836508672?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

Just citing my Twitter message to Joel Spolsky's announcement.

One thing I can predict for sure is, the company will fail without supporting their core product, which is the community and repository of Q&A.

The problems with Stack Overflow and other sites at the SE network go far deeper than the recent hype and storm of protest about Monica Cellio's kick-off from moderation.

There's need of intervention and clarity about what the company's direction is in cooperating with the community culture that has been build up since decades.

[The statement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology) of a subordinate company member like Sara Chipps doesn't mean a lot, and only addressing the particular case (which is only the tip of the iceberg) is useless.

Answer (score 11):

In this case, I believe it wouldn't accomplish too much. I'm willing to see it if it *were* to happen, but I think meaningful change should happen in conjunction with company transparency.

In my opinion, the best course of action for SE at the moment would be to make a few changes first:

1. **Release the new CoC**: As it's directly related to the recent debacle, this should definitely be released.
2. **Release the new method of relieving moderators that was [mentioned in the apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology).** It would show that positive change was being made in relation to Staff - Community Moderator relations.
3. **Release *some* information regarding the incident.** For legal reasons they can't release some of what transpired, apparently, but I do believe the *specific* reason for the moderator in question's dismissal should be mentioned.

All of this to say that meaningful change should be presented that should spark productive discussion. A lot of answers to the apology Sara posted earlier (many now deleted, to be fair) got off topic, and ventured more into the realm of "dunking" on her post rather than presenting meaningful solutions to future related problems.

Comment: The moderator agreement (a legally binding contract) only states that personally identifiable information cannot be released. Other things that are private aren't prevented from release as a result of legal reasons, but simply due to an informal agreement.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification. That makes request #3 all the more valuable... We need to know what happened *specifically*, and how the community as a whole can do moving forward, and offer meaningful, targeted critique to SE.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog companies generally don't have an informal agreement when giving someone access to privileged information such as a private chatroom. All agreements that companies and users (mods) have are probably legally binding.

Comment: @StephanS [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement) is the agreement all moderators are required to sign as a condition of becoming a moderator. Note that it only prevents the disclosure of "*personally-identifying information*".

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Whoever wrote this contract really knows how to departmentalize the elements of the contract to make it more confusing to follow but if you look at SS (i.) it states "I will abide by the then-current Terms of Service of Stack Overflow, and **other moderator policies** made available to me" this would include the agree the moderators agree to before entering the mod chatroom and other mod only areas, if you're looking for a more fleshed out answer about this ask the question on Law.SE and I can explain alittle bit more.

Comment: "agreement" not "agree"

Comment: This agreement may be legally binding, but what are the legal consequences of breaking it? If it is just "being revoked as a moderator", well, I got news for you...

Comment: @dim the contract doesn't actually outline what damages would be so it's more of what a court would determine the damages for breach of contract.

Answer (score 10):

## If it happens, it can happen now

The site already selected the questions we are having. It's pushing them to the top. This comes at the unfortunate expense of the official statement sinking to the bottom, but that's some pretty clear insight into the sentiment that is shared by all.

## My recommendation: answer what's already there

Stack Exchange is a site where people with questions can get answers. Silence, in my opinion, can be in many ways worse than an unpopular answer. The questions that need addressing have been at the top for hours and in many ways having a town hall where only a privaliged few can participate is throwing mud in the face of the people who cared enough to ask.

### **Disclaimer**

I am not a moderator, nor an employee. I do not have a personal understanding of what either go through on a day to day basis to get this tremendously helpful resource working, but I am a person who is concerned with the updates to the policy and licensing.

Answer (score 9):

This sounds like a great idea. Some suggestions for how this might be accomplished because the logistics for this type of thing can be tricky:

- Stack Exchange staff could collect common questions that have already been posted around the network metas, especially over the last week, but there may be relevant concerns from earlier that are worth addressing.
- Create a new, [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) MSE post soliciting additional questions from the community. Seed it with a community wiki of the aggregated questions from previous posts
- Stack Exchange hosts a livestream with leadership, with a public link for users to view. Maybe invite a few moderators to participate in the livestream as well so it can be a conversation.
- Pair the livestream with either an SE chatroom or something like https://www.sli.do that lets the audience submit (and potentially vote on) follow-up questions in realtime.
- Post a video and/or transcripts to meta afterwards as a public artifact.

Comment: I also suggest using a token system, where at most 3 questions can be answered with "unfortunately we cannot disclose information due to the sensitivity of the subject".

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thats kinda already their answer to all question I'm not sure a token system would change their minds

Comment: I like the idea of a meta post, in the same style as "Moderator Questions and Answers."  You can probably dispense with the livestream for awhile, at least until things have cooled down a bit.  I'm a bit worried that the community will see all this as a parlor trick, though; at the end of the day, the community wants to see change, not just more words.

Comment: Part of why I like the livestream bit is *because* I think it’ll take some time to plan and execute, which will give people time to cool off a bit. I also firmly believe this is a solution to be pursued in addition to - not instead of - better and deeper engagement with the community here on meta.

Comment: This sounds like a lot of humdrum for not a lot of result. Like, I think there's two big questions. One regards the CoC, one regards the relicensing. There's subquestions to that sure, but those concerns are well documented here and elsewhere. No reason to poll the community when the big questions are answerable here (in my opinion)

Comment: Exciting ideas!  Please edit to change to "invite a few moderators (past and present) to participate."

Answer (score 3):

My idea is similar to Laura's. I think it could work to create something similar to moderator elections:

A new question is created on Meta, where the "answers" are questions submitted by users. Other users upvote the questions they want to see answered. After a period of a week or so, the Q&A is locked.

However, instead of a livestream with a live chat, it might be better to create a new Meta post with the answers to the upvoted questions.

That way, there's a bit of a buffer, where overly-harsh or offensive questions are pushed to the bottom, and the ones the community most wants answered are the ones that actually get a response. Livestreaming it would open staff up to a lot of angry comments in realtime.

If there needs to be a follow-up round, there can be another post with the same process. I just personally don't think a live interaction would go very well, even if it could potentially resolve the situation more quickly. Also, even if the answers a pre-prepared, it's possible for the people reading the answers out live to misspeak or interject their own opinions without a review process.

Of course, the answers should definitely start with the questions that have already been asked and highly upvoted/discussed already. Compiling future questions into one Q&A, though, means Meta is a little less cluttered (not really the right word), and it's easy to browse through questions you might want to see answered.

Comment: I like how you want to create a Q&A as a question in a Q&A site about Q&A sites