# Update: an agreement with Monica Cellio

Tags: discussion, moderators, announcements, moderator-removal

Stack Overflow and Monica Cellio have come to an agreement. We believe that Ms. Cellio was not acting with malicious intent. We believe she did not understand all of the nuances and full intent and meaning of our Code of Conduct and was confused about what actions it required and forbade.

We acknowledge our responses to her requests for clarification were not satisfactory. The verbiage in our Code of Conduct could have been more explicitly detailed about what was expected. We always valued Ms. Cellio’s contributions to the community and respect her intelligence, integrity, and professional writing skills.

While our initial statement did not address her specifically, we regret that we used her name when responding to a reporter's follow-up. We regret any damage to Ms. Cellio's reputation and any other damage she may have suffered.

We have since updated some of our policies and processes to help ensure we are more careful in our public communications, and that there is a clearer process anytime a moderator's status is revoked as well as a process for reinstatement.

We respect Ms. Cellio and believe she is a good person with much to offer and contribute. We sincerely hope she remains an active member of our community. In recognition of the mistakes that led us here, we invited Ms. Cellio to apply for possible reinstatement on all six sites following our new reinstatement process. Ms. Cellio expressed concerns about the new process and has not applied.

Comment: The comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1448/discussion-on-question-by-sara-chipps-update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio).

Comment: Folks - this post had about 250 comments total and 3 pages of answers at this point. A few things to take note. Some of the comments have been pretty ugly - I realise this is emotive but personal attacks on anyone involved is unacceptable. *This includes calling for staff to resign* or trying to assign blame. I'd also add that this is pretty much a statement both sides appear to have legally agreed on- and I doubt any more details are forthcoming.

Answer (score 1435):

Maybe a harsh critique but I believe a fair and honest one.

Your post sounds as though your lawyers drafted this for you. The humanity has been sucked out of it, canned lawyer speak is what remains.

> Stack Overflow and Monica Cellio have come to an agreement. We believe that Ms. Cellio was not acting with malicious intent. **We believe she did not understand all of the nuances and full intent and meaning of our Code of Conduct and was confused about what actions it required and forbade.**

We had already established this. What wasn't established was why her requests for clarifications were shut down so forcefully.

> We acknowledge our responses to her requests for clarification were not satisfactory. The verbiage in our Code of Conduct could have been more explicitly detailed about what was expected. **We always valued Ms. Cellio’s contributions to the community and respect her intelligence, integrity, and professional writing skills.**

Really? Then you'd have done her the courtesy of responding sooner and not waited until it required lawyers. You'd have treated her with a little bit of dignity and decency by not talking to the press.

> While our initial statement did not address her specifically, we regret that we used her name when responding to a reporter's follow-up. **We regret any damage to Ms. Cellio's reputation and any other damage she may have suffered.**

Lawyer speak...

> We have since updated some of our policies and processes to help ensure we are more careful in our public communications, and that there is a clearer process anytime a moderator's status is revoked as well as a process for reinstatement.

You changed the policies as a result of the unending trouble. Not because you saw the light.

Let's be quite clear here, mods repeatedly tell users that they don't discuss user suspensions so why is it that an employee thought it appropriate to do so with press?

Gross negligence or plain simple malintent?

> We respect Ms. Cellio and believe she is a good person with much to offer and contribute. We sincerely hope she remains an active member of our community. In recognition of the mistakes that led us here, we invited Ms. Cellio to apply for possible reinstatement on all six sites following our new reinstatement process. Ms. Cellio expressed concerns about the new process and has not applied.

Lawyer speak and it makes you seem so unbelievably unaware.

How *NICE* of you to '*invite*' her to apply for reinstatement *EVEN* though you've acknowledged it was ***YOUR*** mistakes.

This whole post screams that you're making amends not because you genuinely feel a mistake has been made but because it's something your lawyers have said you ***need*** to do if you want things to settle. If you're going to apologise, do so without talking about the other person's shortcomings.

Monica must've had a real good case for y'all to even post this.

---

Anyhow, I'm glad Monica got a resolution she could sign off on.

Comment: "In recognition of the mistakes that led us here". This sentence is actually quite clever: it doesn't specify who made the mistakes.

Comment: Sure this is lawyers speech, what did you expect? If two parties come to an extrajudicial agreement, usually negotiated by their lawyers, you won't hear anything else from them.

Comment: Of course the lawyers wrote it. This post is most likely part of a legal settlement of the defamation lawsuit. I'd be surprised if a law firm hadn't been over every single letter a dozen times.

Comment: I expected an apology to be more human-like but I see your points.

Comment: "We regret any damage to Ms. Cellio's reputation and any other damage she may have suffered." That's not lawyer speak, that's a non-apologize. Change the subject and adverb with hitting someone: we regret to punch you and the concussion it caused. An apologize should recognize one mistake, not just regret the results.

Comment: @Braiam by lawyer speak I meant it as though something their lawyers had suggested to make it sound almost human but it fails magnificently at that.

Comment: "You'd have treat her with a little bit of dignity and decency by not talking to the press" *or retracting the statement after realising it was a mistake*. Making that statement was a big mistake, but it would have been a forgivable one if they had simply retracted it. People make mistakes - it's the fact they have proved to be completely unwilling to *rectify* their mistakes that is the problem.

Comment: I didn't read it as lawyer speak at all. Rather, well composed. Except that almost the entire answer set up expectations quite the opposite of the last two sentences.

Comment: @Script47 Boilerplate apologies are not apologies. It is especially ironic that she is offering an opportunity for Monica to reapply, with a possibility of further rejection.

Comment: @yshavit more like "I'm sorry your truck got broken." They carefully avoid admitting to taking any of the actions that led to the situation.

Comment: Monica Cellio is ok with the agreement, she even signed an NDA. The two involved parties are no longer in conflict, so why are we angry about again? Monica agreed to whatever is happening here.

Comment: @ByBw We do not know that Monica is OK with the agreement, only that she agreed to it. It might be that she is OK with it, but it also might be that she is tired of everything and agreeing to this is preferable to losing her health and sanity. I view the latter possibility much more believable.

Comment: @Amadan She was the one suing, not the other way around. She doesn't need to sign anything she doesn't agree with. If she isn't happy, all she has to do is not sign, without any consequences whatsoever.

Comment: @ByBw I can't speak for "we" but I can speak for myself, I'm not angry. What makes you think I am?

Comment: @ByBw - I don't think there's anything stopping SO from counter-suing Monica. If they take steps to do that, they could inflict substantial financial damage on Monica as they can afford a lot more legal muscle than she can. Her $30k GFM account won't go far against an army of SO lawyers.

Comment: _"What wasn't established was why her requests for clarifications were shut down so forcefully."_ - I would go so far as arguing that requests for clarification signify intent to comply with the new CoC, once it has been understood. Anyway, this was a forthcoming CoC and not an active one! Since when is SO the movie Minority Report?

Comment: May I please say here what I said directly to Monica herself: StackExchange is a great community with many, many amazing Users, but it also now it has a Hero: Monica Cellio!

Comment: "What wasn't established was why her requests for clarifications were shut down so forcefully." - Someone needs to answer for that, esp. whoever DID the forceful shutting-down.

Comment: @Steerpike : It would be a PR nightmare to counter-sue her and it would be easy to raise more money in such a case.

Comment: @Christian I really don't think SE cares about how it (would) look considering how long they let this situation fester.

Comment: @Script47 They don't care how it looks to meta users but they would care if it would become a major news story.

Comment: Don't forget the forced "binding arbitration" clause that SE added to the user agreement.  If Monica didn't explicitly opt-out, this whole thing could have been forced on one or both parties by the arbitrator.  Yet another reason to *always* opt out of binding arbitration.

Comment: @Steerpike SO almost surely doesn't have "an army of lawyers". Probably more like one or two lawyers, maybe a firm they retain as needed where they get assigned whoever is available.

Comment: @Kevin "I'm sorry your truck got broken." Seems to indicate you ("I") might've had some involvement. If you change it to how the statement is formulated you get "We regret that your truck broke down", which implies a dismay about the situation without having (inferred) involvement. Possible take even more distance from the situation by reversing the sentece a bit to "It is regrettable your truck broke down", but that's plain non-apoletic, making the previous one the one they also chose in their statement ;)

Answer (score 1170):

I can't comment further for legal reasons.

Comment: Can you at least comment whether this statement is true?  "Stack Overflow and Monica Cellio have come to an agreement."

Comment: @user-2147482600 just assume that any agreement includes "Monica may not comment on the terms of this agreement."  (Which would also preclude calling the terms fair or unfair.)  I'm just hoping for confirmation that they *have* come to an agreement, which should be possible to confirm regardless.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to Monica to try to speculate here about the terms, since she wrote that **she cannot comment.**  I do think it would be reasonable for her to say, "Yes, we have come to an agreement," but I'm not even going to conclude anything from the fact that she hasn't done so.

Comment: Related reading: [what Monica wrote previously on Meta about removal and reinstatement.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336236/307622)

Comment: @Wildcard: I assume that if Monica cannot comment on the current situation, it must mean that some agreement has been reached. The first rule of the agreement is: You do not talk about the agreement.

Comment: I'm going to assume this is a win for you, and that you agreed to some sort of Non Disclosure Agreement because you found the outcome acceptable, so Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations on reaching an agreement Monica!

Comment: @Wildcard It's perfectly normal for an agreement to include that the actual existence of the agreement must not be mentioned. I've had this (but of course, I can't give any details of what the agreement I came to was).

Comment: Since an agreement has been reached, so is there still any point in funding the legal process?

Comment: Great job, and glad to see it worked out :)

Comment: @Graviton No, the donations are closed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , and the money is refunded?

Comment: @Graviton, it says that the rest of it it's going to be donated. You can check the GoFundMe website.

Comment: I think you should apply for that reinstatement now. It doesn't seem that anything else will happen otherwise and I have a hunch that SE's lawyers told SE that if you ask for reinstatement they should honor your request.

Comment: Monica, I never got an opportunity to know you but this makes me very happy. Happy not for that you had to take the legal course of action but happy for the final outcome. No one should be ever taken advantage of! Your comments says it all! Congrats Again!

Comment: @user35594 For better or worse, not publicly discussing anything is a standard part of settlements in the US.  Likewise no one at SE can say anything beyond the statement that Sara posted in the update - whose wording was agreed to by both sides lawyers.

Comment: _"I can't comment further for legal reasons."_ I wonder if you actually found the outcome acceptable because this screams to me that you felt compelled to accept their conditions.

Comment: @user35594: if one side is entirely happy with the outcome, then the other side's negotiators haven't worked as hard as they could have. Monica is not going to say whether or not she's happy with the outcome, and presumably she's compelled to accept it (only) in the sense that it's better (perhaps marginally better) for her to do so than to continue the dispute. By whatever criteria she uses to define "better" or "worse" versions of a sorry mess.

Comment: The fact that you agreed to this statement which accomplishes nothing for you (but helps SE cover their legal backside) implies to me one of two things: One, they paid you a cash settlement to get you to agree to letting them get away without apologizing, retracting statements, or admit wrongdoing -- or Two, they threatened to counter-sue you and you decided to cut your losses. I Hope it's the former, I fear it's the latter, and it frustrates me that the rest of us may never know which =^/.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It seems odd to be that, if the agreement said that the existence of an agreement should not be mentioned, a representative of Stack Exchange would title this post "An agreement with Monica Cellio". That seems to be mentioning the existence. But I guess it is possible, for any number of reasons,  like a special exception to that rule so that this post could be made (I guess...?)

Comment: I think it ended as foretold in Monica's post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336526/stack-overflow-is-doing-me-ongoing-harm-its-time-to-fix-it

Comment: So we don’t really get to know what happened, even though people donated thousands?

Comment: @Stormblessed there will be a final accounting for the money when all the bills are in.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - To the extent you are satisfied with the result, congratulations, felicidades, and mazel tov! I wish you a speedy, complete reinstatement. I miss your leadership, and I hope you will choose to moderate at least some sites. // I'm confused about something. The cat that had impulsively run up the tree and couldn't figure out how to get down again has now finally figured it out and climbed down, with some important retractions. I would have thought that the terms of the settlement would include SE paying your legal fees. But if that was not the case, I'm sorry to hear it.

Comment: If Monica isn't allowed to comment anymore, then perhaps it's best if I don't participate on SE anymore, either. Sad as it makes me, I have a bad gut feeling about just carrying on here, anymore.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Would you like users to remove things like “reinstate Monica” from our user names now that an agreement has been reached? I understand that you can’t comment on the situation for legal reasons but, if an agreement has been reached and you thusly no longer require support from the community, it would make sense for us users to remove such tags from our names and profiles. If this situation has absolutely, fully concluded, there is no longer anything for us to give our support to. However, if you still need support, i have no doubt the community will continue to stand by you : )

Comment: @LiamMorris-ReinstateMonica We still need to push for full reinstatement. Unconditionally, without begging or gambling. Sure, she's "reached an agreement" & can't say much of anything now, but nowhere has she ever said she didn't want to return. In fact, she's been pretty clear over the months that she wants her diamonds back. If she were done with SE, she'd have left altogether, & she hasn't. Even if she were meh about returning (who could blame her), full reinstatement must be our goal. Not just for Monica; it's for all of us. SE should not withhold this from her. We need to keep pushing.

Comment: @CynsaysmakeMonicawhole Whilst i fully agree with you that Monica should have every single one of her diamonds given back to her, if the situation has been settled (even if its not the result we would like), theres not a lot more the community can do. Hypothetically, lets say SE has agreed to only give back Monica her diamonds if she goes through reinstatement. Monica has stated she doesn’t want to go through reinstatement as it means accepting guilt for something she hasn’t done. We’ve reached a stalemate. *continued*

Comment: Neither Monica nor SE can comment further about this situation as “an agreement has been reached”. So if SE is unwilling to give Monica her diamonds without her going through the process and won’t budge, yet Monica does not wish to go through the process because of the reasons she stated in a previous post (a decision which i respect), then no amount of pushing from the community will change that. Don’t get me wrong, I'm not advocating we just pack up and stop supporting her, but if Monica herself feels the situation has concluded and won’t change, it might be time for us to move on.

Comment: @LiamMorris-ReinstateMonica I am not going to stop pushing and I hope you won't either.  Of course there's more than one path to reinstatement!  It's only SE management that's pretending the only way forward is to do that new process that has no appeals, no transparency, no safeguards against bias, and no promises (as if they don't already know how they'll rule!).  Why should we accept their framing?  We need to push for what they should have done after their mistake (a mistake they claim to regret): full unconditional reinstatement with no hoops to jump through.  Please join me.

Comment: To be honest, I'm a little surprised that SO's statement here (falling well short of an apology) was not vitoed by Monica's lawyers, since in an equal scenario each side would get to agree to what the other side said about the situation down to the letter.  Monica's response here sounds more like she was gagged than any agreement was reached.

Comment: An apology a la "_I'm sorry you feel like you deserve an apology_". They just won't admit any wrongdoing on their side. Hence obviously also no reinstatement. Even worse, no retraction of the public slander. (They "regret" it - but probably mostly that people didn't just go along with it.) And a post from Monica where she doesn't _agree_ with anything - just saying that she's legally gagged.  **People, just connect the dots.** The _very best_ case is that she got a bunch of money to shut up. It's probably much more sinister.

Comment: @LindaJeanne "*implies to me one of two things:... they paid you...to agree to letting them get away without apologizing, retracting...or admit(ting) wrongdoing -- or ... they threatened to counter-sue...and you decided to cut your losses.*" I think you're right. But the respect for Monica's "professional writing skills" that SE, a company valued at about $500m, has expressed in its widely-read statement may help rather than hinder MC's employment prospects. Both sides have won. The company has shown partners it can deal with its "community"; MC has had her professional skills praised.

Comment: @laur34-protesting, are you thinking Monica isn't allowed to post comments on SE at all anymore ever?  I'm pretty sure what she meant, given the context, is that she can't comment further on this particular issue.  Your comment and your profile make it seem like you may think it's the former.

Comment: I can't comment on certain topics.  I am participating normally on Mi Yodeya.

Comment: I don't see any sign that Monica got anything.  The reinstatement process was already open to her (and somebody has already linked to her earlier explanation as to why this is inadequate).  And nothing further has been done (no retraction, as others have noted here).  Monica may have been convinced by her lawyers that there is really nothing more that she can do, but I am certainly not satisfied.  I must now resign myself to never being satisfied.  StackExchange is simply Quora with a better reputation system, not a community, and that's what it will always be.

Comment: Even tho this whole mess is between Monica and SE, the community got involved and this became a whole community issue. This cryptic post that does nos acknowledge SE blame plus Monica and SE not disclosing the agreement terms and what has been decided is actually hurting even more the community. For an entire network that promotes open knowledge and transparency this is beyond hypocritical. Hiding everything from the community and lack of information was how this whole mess started.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Was there a "no agreement" canary that has been removed?  We might know that way...

Comment: It would be good if you could confirm if you are happy that this issue is resolved or that you want us to continue supporting you. There are other issues than yourself at hand, but those might be better framed outside of your situation. All the best.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I hope you got a fat stack

Comment: "there will be a final accounting ... when all the bills are in." We can but hope...

Comment: My condolences. You had a good relationship with Stack Exchange, going back years, and they wrecked it. I imagine it’s much like going through a difficult divorce with someone who changed in negative ways over a period of years.

Answer (score 711):

I'm so <strike>happy</strike> disappointed that after months of frustration, hundreds of well-reasoned responsible adults advising you, and untold hours of people working to persuade your company to take action, that your lawyers *finally* allowed you to say the **absolute minimum** necessary to check all the boxes on the list of things to redress, under the threat of litigation.

So, let's be perfectly clear, that this does not read as a heart-felt personal apology. Coming from Sara Chipps feels calculated, or possibly *legally-required*. All language has become "We" now, as in "Stack Overflow". So, despite the personal level of the accusations that were initially leveled, this redaction is impersonal.

> The verbiage in our Code of Conduct could have been more explicitly detailed about what was expected.

We all already knew this, based on the countless hours of moderator and community feedback to Code of Conduct and FAQ changes. You literally proved every step of the way *after* taking the bad actions, that the CoC expectations were murky at best. There is **zero** value in stating the blindingly obvious at this point. What's absent here is an admittance and acknowledgement that despite knowing the expectations weren't clear, you took extreme action against one person, and created a hostile environment that made many, many others afraid of suffering similar extreme actions.

I know much of the member base and many employees want to start healing. Some people may see this as a form of closure that allows us to move forward.

It's not. **This is not an apology.** This is not a form of redress for *anything* except one of the wrongs done specifically against Monica: It serves to be evidence to clear her good name so as not to damage her reputation and threaten her livelihood.

This does nothing to make amends for the harm caused to the communities.

We still have valid fears of being harmed by You. Not all of us have Monica's network of support to raise enough funds for legal fears to scare you into *doing the right thing*. Most of us would be stuck.

We still have no reason to trust that You will do the right thing on your own. Our legitimate concerns and worries over how you handle our content (licensing changes, profile vandalism, intrusive ads) have not been addressed.

We still have no personal apologies from anyone for the hurt they've caused members. And this agreement all but guarantees that we won't, because your legal team is apparently disallowing any further comment on the topic, and was likely involved in drafting this coldly impersonal post.

We still have networks whose communities were irreparably harmed by the sheer volume of moderators and influential users that had to leave the network or cease contributions, because You dug in your heels.

So please, everyone, make no mistake, **this isn't good enough**. It may satisfy the company's *legally*-required list of requirements, but it does not satisfy their *ethically*-required list of requirements.

Stack Overflow, you need to do better.

Comment: @WebHead - on top of it all, the context involves a "code of conduct." I lack words to express the revulsion I feel considering that juxtaposition. How can anyone dissociate the "code of conduct" from the conduct surrounding it? You can't look at that page without remembering.

Comment: Monica is ok with what was said in the post. She copy-pasted it on her fundraiser and cancelled it. Seems that it's what Monica wanted, and what people wanted was resolution for her. People that keep steering the drama wheel seem to be more worried about complaining about everything than worried about Monica's well being and best interests.

Comment: _“It serves to be evidence to clear her good name so as not to damage her reputation and threaten her livelihood.”_ — at least the post accomplishes that… _hopefully_.

Comment: @ByBw Monica is just one aspect of our discontent with the network. An important one, sure, but only one of many. Speaking for myself, a public retraction of the comments made to the press would be a good start, this is just a tiny step in the right direction. But in any case, it only addresses Monica who was simply the straw that broke the camel's back and not really the core of the issue. She just came to represent our anger at SE.

Comment: @terdon-stopharmingMonica I'm talking about Monica's case in particular. She has moved on, SE has moved on, that conflict is done. There are more issues in the community and the network, of course, and we should address every single one of them in a constructive, assertive manner; but some people seem to be more interested in indefinitely perpetuating the drama around Monica's case than in finding solutions or having a constructive conversation.

Comment: @ByBw And some people seem to be more interested in letting Stack Overflow get away with how they treated the rest of us just because a single person got a _piece_ of a resolution that they hoped for. And "moved on" is quite a reductive way to say **"handled everything behind closed doors and are now legally bound to not talk about the resolution, including whether or not they're fully satisfied by the agreement reached"**.  How can I even have a constructive conversation if _they won't converse_ and now can hide behind "If it's even remotely related to Monica, we can't talk about it."?

Comment: @terdon I think it's more than that, yes. Monica deserved her own form of justice, absolutely, which maybe this "agreement" gives. But they didn't _only_ do it to Monica. The mishandling of this specific situation caused harm and discontent among the network, especially among moderators, and we've effectively lost the chance to get a satisfying resolution to the way that _we_ were affected. And for those who only cared about Monica's well-being, we can't actually be sure she's happy with this situation. There's a spectrum between "Ideal outcome" and "outcome possible given resource limits".

Comment: @ByBw You say "Monica is ok..." Have you heard / read that somewhere, or are you making an inference? B/C her actions could also be explained as someone who has been told by a lawyer that this is the best she's going to get. She could be anything from ecstatic to resigned. I see no evidence that strongly supports any one conclusion.

Comment: @ByBw - yes, of course there should be (far) more effort being put in to sorting issues. However, the recalcitrant top echelons at SE still seem to feel they're untouchable. They haven't yet given a genuine apology and admitted what they did wrong. What they say amounts to 'we're sorry - for being found out'. And their offers regarding Monica's re-instatement are derisory.

Comment: My number one takeaway is SO's continued claim that she violated the **then-current** CoC, which is simply not true.  She questioned a proposed, upcoming, not-yet-active CoC, and was punished for having violated that same not-yet-active CoC.  This is nonsensical, and it is actively wrong for SO to avoid acknowledging this.

Comment: **_(licensing changes, profile vandalism, intrusive ads) have not been addressed_** In the spirit of [XKCD #1053](https://xkcd.com/1053/), would you consider linking to other posts concerning the issues you mention in this statement? Personally, I'm only aware of two out of the three and have no idea what the other is referring to. I doubt I'm the only one missing at least one piece of the picture.

Answer (score 596):

I find this statement to be a continuation of your (= SE inc's) inappropriate, underhanded, approach to this matter and to relations with the SE community so far.

> We believe that Ms. Cellio was not acting with malicious intent.

This implies Ms. Cellio did something wrong (albeit inadvertently).

> We believe she did not understand all of the nuances and full intent and meaning of our Code of Conduct and was confused about what actions it required and forbade.

This implies even more strongly that you stand by your claim that she had broken your Code of Conduct. I remind you, Ms. Chipps, of [the highest-voted reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334605/196834) to your last post on this site: "[Did you lie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334268) in claiming that Ms. Cellio broke the code of conduct?" You seem to be claiming you didn't. Well then, again, what did she do that broke the code?

> We always valued Ms. Cellio’s contributions to the community and respect her intelligence, integrity, and professional writing skills.

This does not square with her termination on the spot as moderator - a termination you are still justifying and have not undone.

> While our initial statement did not address her specifically, we regret that we used her name when responding to a reporter's follow-up. We regret any damage to Ms. Cellio's reputation and any other damage she may have suffered.

And how will you compensate her for this damage? More importantly, what's to prevent you from acting in this "regrettable" manner against other users - even valued and respected contributors, to use your words - with whom you disagree?

> We have since updated some of our policies and processes to help ensure ... there is a clearer process anytime a moderator's status is revoked

In that case, then - please apply this policy and tell us why Ms. Cellio's moderator status was revoked.

Also note, that a "clearer process" does not help much when you can be sanctioned unilaterally without even the opportunity to rebut the charges against you.

> We respect Ms. Cellio and believe she is a good person with much to offer and contribute.

And yet, you still stick by her termination as a moderator; and have not reinstated her. Why?

> In recognition of the mistakes that led us here, we invited Ms. Cellio to apply for possible reinstatement on all six sites following our new reinstatement process.

That would be a **non**-recognition of the mistakes that led you here. Any terminated moderator can apply for reinstatement, after all.

---

**Bottom line:** You (= SE Inc.) seem to be "cutting your losses" w.r.t. the most legally vulnerable point, which is the slander in the media, while holding your position otherwise, and presenting all wrongdoing as an unfortunate conjunction of circumstances.

Comment: It's called "no admission of liability or wrongdoing" which is standard for extrajudicial settlements. Still, I completely agree with every word you've written.

Comment: The author of this answer (einpoklum) has been a repeatedly outspoken person w.r.t. the controversies on SE and appears to have been suspended. Seems like the mods are still deleting comments, answers - and now users - that they do not agree with. The staff of this god-forsaken website sicken me.

Answer (score 537):

> We believe she did not understand all of the nuances and full intent and meaning of our Code of Conduct and was confused about what actions it required and forbade.

What a patronizing comment; in the discussion on the mod Q&A back in January a large majority of the moderators agreed with Monica's interpretation, which proves that she's not the confused foolhardy individual that this sentence makes her out to be, but that there was an actual *disagreement* on what the CoC actually mandated from people. This is also demonstrated by the fact that the CoC had to be updated to reflect this: there would have been no need for an update if all we had was one confused individual.

Stack Exchange still shifts the blame on Monica, instead of recognizing that it repeatedly kicked Monica in the teeth and treated her like an anonymous internet troll over an (IMHO fairly minor) disagreement. The only party that *clearly* breached the spirit of the CoC is Stack Exchange.

In other words, I feel this is a non-apology, and it's a disappointment this is the best Stack Exchange can come up with after 3 months. It seems there is still little understanding of the *real* problems with the entire situation.

I'm happy there is a solution which satisfies Monica sufficiently so she can move on from this stressful and emotional situation, but this has done little to put my mind at ease about the future.

Comment: The patronizing irks me as well. It indicates that SE in general and Sara Chipps in particular have learned nothing. I can identify the "confused" party here, and it is not Monica. Unfortunately the contents, and perhaps most importantly, the tone of the post also does not indicate a change in attitude towards the community. The damage Sara has done is untold, and this post makes me believe it will continue.

Comment: Do you _know_ that Monica is satisified or are you making an inference? I don’t know the terms of the agreement or how Monica feels about them.

Comment: I don't know if she's *happy* with the terms, but she did accept them @canon. I don't have more information than anyone else, but it seems to have satisfied her sufficiently to accept them and move on.

Comment: You don’t have to be satisfied to give up on a legal battle with a corporation and take what you can get -if anything. Given that SE admitted no fault and has not vacated its original judgment, I sincerely hope there was something more than Sara’s post (and the deletion of the old one). I certainly _hope_ the terms were satisfactory. At this point, though, I personally wouldn't presume that Monica is satisfied; only that she's accepted the terms.

Comment: @canon Yeah, hence the phrasing of *"satisfies Monica sufficiently so she can move on"*.

Comment: I can't imagine Monica would be truly satisfied, since this "agreement" apparently does not even include a retraction in the press, which you'd think would be the minimum to try and limit damage to her reputation

Comment: @canon The SO user agreement has a binding arbitration clause.  If Monica didn't opt-out, then both sides would be forced to abide by the arbitrator's decision, whether they like it or not and with no chance of negotiation or appeal.

Comment: @bta: The SO user agreement has nothing to do with it, as moderators have other agreements which supercede it.  The option to opt out of binding arbitration available to the community probably never was available to moderators.

Comment: @BenVoigt The [moderator agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) is public, doesn't mention arbitration at all, and is written in such a way that it is not clear that it is actually legally binding on either party under US law, which I have to assume was intentional.

Comment: @rockwalrus-stopharmingMonica: All that really tells you is that it is not the entire agreement.  "and other moderator policies made available to me"  Not being a diamond mod I don't know what those are, but it's definitely been mentioned that there are such policies.

Answer (score 412):

You said (my emphasis),

> In recognition of the mistakes that led us here, we invited Ms. Cellio to *apply for possible reinstatement* on all six sites following our new reinstatement process. Ms. Cellio expressed concerns about the new process and has not applied.

I applaud you for admitting responsibility in this matter, but a better response would be to offer her her diamond back. Why should she go through a process without a clear likelihood of success if the problem was largely caused by your failure to communicate with her? If I want to make amends for hurting someone, I make them. I may ask them what they want or expect in terms of amends, but I do not give them a form and tell them to fill it out to apply for possible consideration.

Another thing to consider is *why* the initial actions took place. Admitting wrongdoing is hard, but I have read in multiple sources that lasting behavioral change requires an understanding of the contributing factors. In other words, "I'm sorry, my bad" is necessary but not sufficient. One must confront the source and handle it.

For example:

- Ignorant or poorly-qualified staff can be trained or educated in the proper procedures, policies, principles, ethics, or best practices.
- A rogue employee can be fired, and safeguards put into place to dissuade future employees from "going rogue".
- Bad legal advice can be handled by getting better lawyers.
- Conflicts of interest can be handled via recusal.
- Physically and/or emotionally burnt-out staff (who might lash out irrationally due to stress) can be asked to take a vacation to recharge.

In software development, we sometimes speak of "root causes". Maybe a particular kind of error keeps popping up, and it gets fixed each time the customer complains, but the real reason it is such a problem is a poor requirements-gathering process. What is the *root cause* of the mistakes above?

Comment: Technically SO *didn't* admit responsibility, just that there were "mistakes that led us here". They never said *they* made the mistakes, and the post seems to throw all the blame on Monica for not understanding the new CoC.

Comment: @Grey honestly, I thought it did admit responsibility, at least in a moral sense. It does have a lot of legalese (which I don't appreciate), but it is more than a "something went wrong" post.

Comment: I think there is honestly nothing to applaud here. Well, maybe (hopefully) the amount of money they had to pay, but I wouldn't count too much on it. They said "she didn't understand our rules, and since it was an honest mistake we might think about reinstating her". Pretty sure that what happened is that the lawyers said "Everything is fine, except for that going public thing. Apologize for that and you'll be ok. Here, sign this".

Comment: @GreySage Monica agreed to what is being said here. She copy pasted all of it on her fundraiser and cancelled it. Both parties are 100% ok with what is being said, monica even signed an NDA. There's no longer a conflict between them.

Comment: @ByBw That is one way to look at it, true. Another way is that she submitted to the stronger power (read: expensive lawyers) to avoid more trouble. That is not the same as being 100% ok with it.

Comment: @ChatterOne Submit to what? She was the one suing, and the one that signed the agreement and NDA. She was the one that brought lawyers, and started a fundraiser. Seems that she will make the legal costs public, so we'll know if it was a case of "can't afford it" soon enough.

Comment: @ByBw She could have been under threat of a countersuit or other arm twisting. There are lots of avenues that make it expensive for individuals to sue corporations. Even if the legal costs are made public, we won't know if that's just because she didn't expend the money because she realized it would be futile. Overall, this statement just tells the public that the two parties have decided to go separate ways and we will never know the details of that separation. It admits no wrongdoing on either side, and does nothing to rectify the situation. It just says it is over.

Comment: I know from personal experience that these kind of conflicts are very emotionally draining and stressful @SRM. At some point you need to make a choice and settle with a "good enough" solution – rather than the "fair" one – so you can move on with your life.

Comment: @MartinTournoij That's another valid possibility.

Comment: @ByBw I imagine she got some reasonable consideration out of the agreement. Hopefully millions of considerations.

Comment: First two strongly apply

Comment: What none one seems to know or say is that the SO culture is protective of the kind of lashing out that happened against Monica.  If the company did anything to censure the employee, even a paid leave to 'recharge', it would have a chilling effect internally, which would impact their hiring initiatives.  The company is better on their ease of culture/HR over the sentiment of their user base.

Answer (score 315):

> Stack Overflow and Monica Cellio have come to an agreement.

### Great!

I am happy that you have reached an agreement. I am especially happy that this happened sooner rather than later for Monica's sake. Clearing her good name as soon as possible was imperative here.

> In recognition of the mistakes that led us here, we invited Ms. Cellio
>   to apply for possible reinstatement on all six sites following our new
>   reinstatement process.

### Plain wrong!

After all the missteps you have done from day one handling this, you still had one chance to make things right.

### And you spectacularly failed.

You should have given Monica her diamonds back. If then she decided she is no longer willing to moderate sites on SE, she could step down on her own. While nothing could totally erase events in last few months, this would show good intent on your side and true desire to fix wrong moves and truly move forward.

Under the circumstances reinstatement process would be mere farce. I fully support and understand Monica in her decision to not go through the process.

---

This incident had great impact on how people perceive and value SE.

You have broken the trust between company and you users. The ones that provide you content for free. The ones that moderate sites for free. The ones that ultimately brought the company to the position where it stands today.

**I don't see how can you regain that trust now.**

Maybe you no longer care about mutual trust and cooperation. Maybe you think company can thrive without it. Certainly the platform is huge enough and has enough momentum to keep going for a long time.

But one day, mistake upon mistake and all the future mistakes (I am sure there will be mistakes - this kind of thing does not happen by accident, rather incompetence (at company level - because while one person can always make innocent mistake, others should act like safety mechanism and help correcting those) and inability to learn from mistakes and grow) will accumulate and become too heavy burden to keep on going.

Comment: Really, "sooner rather than later"? I think it's much too late already, and the affair hasn't been finished yet. If this was sarcasm, I didn't detect it.

Comment: @anatolyg It is both. From one side it is way too late... but on the other hand legal process could last for months and years (I am not familiar how fast it works in US) so having this part resolved now is much better option for Monica (even if it is too late by some standards), than having this issue unresolved and dragging on...

Comment: I don't think that Monica's *good name* was cleared. Put yourself in the shoes of a person who is not familiar with all this post-demotion thrashing. They may only know Monica's name (full name, mind you) from the article in *The Register*. They've concluded that Monica is a bigot because why else would a company take such a drastic action. Now they see this settlement statement. Would they change their mind about Monica being a bigot? I don't think so. These apologies and admissions are all about process and nothing at all about content.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk It is always hard to take back things that were publicly said. So, to a point her good name will never be cleared. But she has reached an agreement with SO and I assume that she was satisfied with it and with the statement (and other actions we don't know about), otherwise she would never signed it because clearing her name was (for her) the most (only) important thing.

Answer (score 303):

This doesn't fix the serious breach of trust SE committed by their actions for me. The agreement is of course between Monica and SE, and that is entirely her business, but the actions by SE were very public and have affected the way I and many other active users see the company.

I didn't have any high hopes for a legal resolution here, not every unethical action is also illegal, and there is a serious power imbalance here between a single person and a company. But I'm still disappointed that this statement doesn't actually resolve anything.

The problematic actions started much earlier than when SE talked to the press, or made disparaging statements on meta. The fundamental issue to me was that the actions by SE  put a huge target on Monica, and that was entirely predictable. And still, SE took several actions over a longer time that all made this worse, and put an even bigger target on a single person. And while I do believe that SE would not talk to the press the next time something like this happens, I am not convinced that SE won't create a next time.

Comment: "The problematic actions started much earlier than when SE talked to the press, or made disparaging statements on meta" - Or earlier, such as posting a *pinned message in the TL* announcing her dismissal. What assurances do we have that ex-moderators will be given at *least* the same level of courtesy as suspended problematic users?

Comment: @Mithical that's one part I mean, but even earlier the entire pre-announcement of the CoC change in TL seemed to be targeted at a single person. The language and emphasis of that announcement were simply too different from the actual CoC change.

Comment: I think your “I'm not convinced that SE won't create a next time" wraps up part of the gut feeling most of us have meanwile. +1

Answer (score 246):

### This is certainly a positive step.  But it's not enough.

Offering Monica the chance to go through your reinstatement process is an insult.  Either you're going to reinstate her to her previous positions or you're going put her through the wringer and reject her.

If you are planning to reinstate her, just do it!  The new processes don't apply to her anyway since she was not removed with them.  If removing her diamonds was a mistake, then fix the mistake.

**Why force her to go through this unnecessary review unless your end goal is to say "see, we were right to de-mod you all along!"??**

Comment: While I agree with your post, I suspect SE is working on a reinstatement process for any & all defrocked moderators. Considering Monica's sacking was bad procedure & poor procedure, that malpractice should have been overridden by an offer of *a priori* reinstatement directly from the company, without the need for resorting to due process. Strangely, institutions are never at fault in these situations. Thereby, reducing their liability. However, they should have just done it in reinstaement.

Comment: @a4android They have a reinstatement process.  They released it a couple months ago (after de-modding Monica).  There is also a new process for how to de-mod (also post-this fiasco).  It would have been easy for them to say "we took away Monica's diamonds before we had these processes, so we're going to give them back to her without making her jump through hoops."  Like super duper easy.  So why aren't they?  That's the question to ask.  Why make her jump through hoops at all?  The only reason is so they can officially refuse to reinstate her.

Comment: Yes I know & agree. Easy to say whoops! we made a mistake & fix it by reinstating her unilaterally. Now they're going all we have a proper procedure & this how we do it. And they don't need to, it's in their remit, gift & power to undo the harm to Monica. Everyone would know this would be the right thing to do. Instead they're trapped in their institutionalisation.

Comment: " So why aren't they?" -- I mean, could it be any more obvious that SE doesn't want to reinstate her?

Comment: @CynsaysmakeMonicawhole: It's even worse: there *was* an existing moderator removal process even before this whole fiasco. This process was *deliberately* ignored. What possible reason could Monica have to assume that she would be treated fairly under the new process when she wasn't treated fairly under the old one? After all, there have been *zero* consequences regarding the people involved. Which means that she would subject herself to judgment by the *exact same people* who broke her trust and ignored due process before.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Good point. You're right, there was a mod removal process, which was not at all followed.

Comment: "Offering Monica the chance to go through your reinstatement process is an insult." Exactly. Couldn't have said that better. +1 for that.

Comment: I disagree. This is not a positive step. This is a step taken to restore SE's reputation, not a step taken to undo any damage SE has done to others. "We are sorry that you feel hurt by what we did."

Answer (score 201):

**This seems like you are attempting to strong-arm Monica into losing any of her own legal leverage, by having her agree to go through your sham reinstatement process that rests on a presumption of guilt and tacitly agree to your lack of accepting responsibility.**

> > We believe she did not understand all of the nuances and full intent and meaning of our Code of Conduct and was confused about what actions it required and forbade.

This is quite similar to the assertion made before in a post where you stated that users disagreed with policy updates and other Stack Exchange issues for "reasons they do not understand."

It is perfectly within the realm of possibility that a user can believe things correctly based on the merits and that it rests entirely on the flawed approach of another person. If I announce to a group that I intend to remove the wheels from their cars at the stop light, and they protest, it seems absurd to me to react with "I am sorry that this group did not understand." It's deflecting responsibility.

> > Ms. Cellio expressed concerns about the new process and has not applied.

She wrote why in her response before. The new reinstatement process starts with a presumption of guilt, and the process of her removal was flawed to begin with. She should not lower her dignity further by taking up that banner of guilt to go through a reinstatement process that's not transparent or kind, and that process seems to be for a case any other than an abberant one like this.

It was a mistake to remove her, so the mistake should be reversed. Even in this post, you are agreeing with the (new) policy does not forbid neutrality. Her requests meet the policy. But even if her requests did not, the policy was not in place yet, and therefore I do not personally understand how it breaks policy.

For example, I am not beholden to a Google policy that Google will release in 2025. I am simply not, because as of right now, it's 2019, and not 2025. Do you disagree with this being reasonable? Or do you believe that I should have my Google accounts deleted for the policy that isn't out yet?

> > We have since updated some of our policies and processes to help ensure we are more careful in our public communications.

Where can we review this? Because last time I checked, it was an answer that Shog9 posted to a question that stated "No comment" is the policy moving forward. I'm not sure how binding a post is. I'd feel a lot better if it was in Terms Of Service or Privacy Policy, because a post feels like as binding as a note written on a napkin. I definitely feel like a more *codified* approach would give people more peace.

> > The last sentence reads to me that Monica does not want to go through the reinstatement process, so she won't be reinstated. So perhaps don't wait too long for that diamond to reappear, it sounds like it won't. – Tinkeringbell ♦

Is this interpretation from this user true? This seems quite unfair. This is contradictory to the other features and processes of the site. If someone were to unfairly serial downvote me, their downvotes would be reversed. If someone were to deface my question or do anything else to my question, that action would be reversed.

Imagine if we took what's happening here and applied it to these other cases. I'd have to go to you on my knees and apologize for the actions that other user took, and go through a process where you restore my content. This isn't morally sound to me. Just reinstate her.

Comment: Re: your last section - "Is this a fact?": ...No, it's just Tinkeringbell's personal interpretation of that line of the post. (Somehow I doubt either side's lawyers will let them comment further... Monica's answer, and a reply by Sara to a comment on the question, indicates that neither side actually *can* comment further, so it's likely a stipulation of the agreement between the two sides.)

Comment: To clarify: My comment was made in reply to one that stated something like `I'm glad to see this, I'll be waiting for her diamond to reappear` and is indeed only my interpretation of the last lines in the question: Monica refused the reinstatement process, so her diamond won't reappear, at least for now.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I think my writing was sloppy. I was asking Sara or Stack Exchange if your interpretation was correct. I'll modify what I wrote.

Comment: *you are attempting to strong-arm Monica into losing any of her own legal leverage...* We'll never know for sure, but it's almost certainly the case that Monica was paid to drop all legal claims arising from this and to keep all details secret for a long period (probably forever). I wouldn't call that strong-arming, I'd call that a mutually-agreed upon settlement. Here legal leverage got her paid.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell - Did she refuse it, explicitly, after the settlement result was announce?

Answer (score 201):

## ...But it isn't over yet

I invite you to give [this Radio Lab episode](https://www.wnycstudios.org/podcasts/radiolab/articles/radiolab-right-be-forgotten) a listen on the Right to be Forgotten.

You (SE) have irrevocably damaged Monica's reputation by allowing her name to be used in a public context alongside accusations of bigotry, in a format that can't be readily altered (as presumably, this article was featured in print form, as well as digitally). Furthermore, Monica herself cannot have these attributions redacted, as while they are *about* her, they weren't *from* her: they're from you (SE) and it is your (SE's) duty to contact *all* outlets where this article has appeared and request redaction. It's your fault, and you need to clean up the mess.

> We believe that Ms. Cellio was not acting with malicious intent. We believe she did not understand all of the nuances and full intent and meaning of our Code of Conduct and was confused about what actions it required and forbade.

Oh good, another non-apology.

"We're sorry you didn't understand" is about as sincere as moldy cheese.

It's not *Monica's* fault for not understanding the CoC; it's *yours* for not making it understandable. As part of Monica's responsibility to point out places where the CoC was not understandable, she did her job and said, "Hey, XYZ doesn't make sense, can you clarify?" and in response you (SE) said, "IT'S FINE, EVERYTHING'S FINE, ALSO THAT STATEMENT VIOLATES THE COC, BANNED!"

[image: Everything is not fine]

Comment: It's about as sincere as  _a bad banana with a greasy black peel!_ 

Comment: Where'd you find that comic strip? I need to get a new avatar.

Comment: @JL2210-SupportMonica: [It's by KC Green](https://thenib.com/this-is-not-fine) (language warning), who also made [the original "This is fine" comic](http://gunshowcomic.com/648) (slightly graphic cartoon imagery). Bonus: [a short narrative game based on the original, that's a little more hopeful](https://smashynick.itch.io/thisisfine).

Comment: Note: I specifically picked these three frames as to avoid swearing. :)

Comment: You need to put the eventually... in.

Comment: I'm all for supporting Monica, but can we please not invoke Orwellian legal abominations to do so?  The USA does not recognize a "right to be forgotten," and with good reason.  Phrased in proper active voice, it's a "right to force others to forget about you," which is a horrifying weapon to place in the hands of people with ulterior motives, and the uses to which this weapon has been put so far -- primarily criminals and politicians (but I repeat myself) hiding past misdeeds from public knowledge -- proves exactly why it's a bad idea that should never have existed.

Comment: As Monica didn't do anything wrong here, and thus has no sleazy misdeeds to force others to forget about, this doesn't apply even if it were recognized in the applicable jurisdiction; what's actually relevant is the much simpler (and far more legitimate) right to a fair reputation, to be secure against defamation.

Comment: @MasonWheeler But as the article *makes it appear* that she performed sleazy misdeads, she would just as readily want it "forgotten" (i.e. not to show up in a search for her name).

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, but that's not what the RTBF is about.  It's about taking down *true facts* that are supposedly "no longer relevant."  Taking down defamation is a completely different matter.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Yeah, I think _retraction_ would be what should be requested, not _redaction_. As in, SE should issue a statement to the media outlet to be included in an editorial note at the top of the article stating that their previous statements about Monica were false and unfounded and that they apologize for making them. But it would appear that SE didn't agree to that degree of civility in the settlement.

Answer (score 189):

Here is what I expected to read when I saw the title of this question.  IANAL and IANAW (writer), so this won't sound like legalese.

---

> Stack Exchange and Monica Cellio have resolved their differences.  Both sides have seen what a waste of time and resources it is to battle over something that started relatively insignificantly.  It was in the best interest of both Stack Exchange and Ms. Cellio to settle, so both parties agreed on a settlement.  While we and Ms. Cellio cannot comment on many specific details of the settlement, the following is what Stack Exchange is releasing publicly per terms of the settlement.
>
> Ms. Cellio is hereby **reinstated** as a moderator on all Stack Exchange sites on which she was previously a moderator.  Stack Exchange did not follow our own previously established process, and a lot of hurt has occurred either directly or indirectly because of our actions.  For this we are truly **sorry**.  We hereby **retract** all defamatory statements made to the press about Ms. Cellio.  By now you should be able to find an article online in the press about this retraction using your favorite search engine.
>
> Stack Exchange welcomes all positive, constructive criticism, and expects active users to ask for clarification if our communication is unclear.  Ms. Cellio did not break any of our rules, even if we previously mistakenly judged it differently.  She as well as we fully support inclusivity and everyone's combined effort to make everyone, regardless of gender, sexual orientation, ethnicity, nationality, age, religion, or physical disability **feel welcome and comfortable** posting and contributing to all Stack Exchange sites.
>
> While the Code of Conduct expects users to use proper pronouns upon request, Stack Exchange does not expect a user to know the pronouns of another specific user when not told first.  While Stack Exchange recognizes that there are many different, varied opinions on the legitimacy of such neopronouns, users are expected to use them when using a third-person singular pronoun as stated on a post.  Users may respectfully disagree, but if a user needs to respond on a post referring to a user with pronouns stated on that same post, then that user should comply.  No user shall be punished, either with de-modding or suspension, for disengaging, for avoiding any pronoun, or for using a gender-neutral pronoun.  Use of neopronouns does not necessarily mean that the user implicitly condones these neopronouns, but **it does show respect** for the referred user.  The bottom line here is that we expect all users to treat each other respectfully.
>
> Both Stack Exchange and Ms. Cellio **fully support** those users who identify with the Lavender community in ensuring that they feel as comfortable as any other user when posting on Stack Exchange sites.
>
> Per the terms of the settlement, there were damages awarded, although neither Stack Exchange nor Ms. Cellio are at liberty to discuss the amount.  Both Stack Exchange and Ms. Cellio have agreed to **donate any leftover funds** previously designated for legal costs to charities benefiting lavender causes.
>
> Stack Exchange realizes that while most users may not even be aware of this situation, many long-time, long-contributing users feel that **trust has been greatly damaged**, even beyond repair.  While we respect those feelings, starting NOW we intend to **earn that trust and respect back**.  Lately we have increased our Meta interaction, specifically addressing concerns the community has brought up, from both years ago and recently.  We understand if many never want to return, but we appreciate those have respectfully called for the right actions -- respect, civility, constructive criticism, transparency, honesty, and integrity.
>
> As part of this, Stack Exchange will be more transparent with our actions and business decisions.  While we reserve the right to make changes without consent, we will at least discuss changes that affect the community in a non-negligible way.  After all, the community makes Stack Exchange possible.  There are many that may not believe the preceding statements, but we believe that this is the **first of many necessary steps** that we will take to regain trust and improve relations between Stack Exchange and the community.

---

But that's not what I read.  This wasn't what was posted by Stack Exchange above.  It may look like a small step forward, but a giant leap forward was required, so it looks like things are still backwards.

Comment: This just makes me sad because it could have been this good :( And if it were, it might truly end the debacle

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a way that this could have been handled *constructively* in the contex of current US legal culture.

Comment: My take on this, having **absolutely no inside knowledge** of the situation, but based on my own past experiences (tangentially) with a number of court cases is: Monica could have pushed for more - and *likely* gotten it (as described in your wonderful sample above) - if she had the time, energy & money to continue the legal battle for several months. But unlike a corporate entity, she couldn't/wouldn't devote that time & energy to it. (Money is the "easy" part thanks to GoFundMe and similar options). So it ends in typical legalese with an outcome that satisfies SE (end of the "problem"),...

Comment: satisfies Monica enough (i.e., that she was willing to agree to whatever terms that satisfied some of her concerns) and lets her get on with her life, but **as is often the case with legal cases** leaves the rest of us scratching our heads. But we are not parties to the lawsuit, so that's the way it goes.

Comment: Very well put - and may you never become an L or a W, and forget how to do it! :)

Comment: Your pronoun obligation doesn't allow gender-neutral writing via not using pronouns. The CoC isn't clear about that, but in the reams of interpretation it does more or less say it's allowed. Which I support. Other than that I support this post. PS You "expected" something like this? You had very high hopes.

Comment: Cannot agree more that this is what SE must answer. Currently, SE tries to cover its wrongs and that destroys trust and good will.

Comment: @philipxy I spent my lunch hour yesterday writing this up, and I still forgot that particular point.  I added it.  High hopes?  Maybe.  I'm idealistic.

Comment: This would have been the ideal solution in an ideal world. Pity it wasn't so in our imperfect reality. A brilliant reposte in contrast to the actual outcome.

Comment: Perfect potential response from SE. Probably won't even be read by those in power, let alone considered! +1.

Comment: Although the pronoun issue was the trigger to Monica's unfair dismissal, it is not otherwise relevant here. The issue is: was the proper process followed in demodding Monica? The consensus is that it wasn't, no matter what the trigger was, so it should be considered null and void as if it never happened. After that it is up to Monica if she feels she can trust SE enough to continue as a moderator or resign. The middle part of your post would be better if it wasn't there.

Comment: “*Both sides have seen what a waste of time and resources it is to battle over **something that started relatively insignificantly.***” I would be careful with your wording. It may come across as dismissive to those who were hurt by the inciting incident.

Comment: You do realise you did better job in writing this statement than all the lawyers involved who took probably tens of thousands of dollars for their *work*, do you?

Comment: Wow. My jaws would have dropped beyond my ability to get them back in place without major surgery if SE's reply had been as good as what you've written. I think you might have a wonderful career in the future as a meta-moderator and communications officer of tech companies! 

Comment: And now they hire you to do the damage control :)

Answer (score 181):

This is a similar answer to Columbia's, but I have a slightly different take.

The last paragraph just doesn't make sense to me. It's nice that Stack Exchange seems to be admitting fault, but that's negated by the last couple sentences.

Monica was removed without warning or process. As far as the rest of us know, she didn't even have a chance to argue her case before she was fired. Why should she have to be held to a process for "*possible*" reinstatement, if no process was used in her removal? That just doesn't make sense.

Of course, there's a very good chance Monica just doesn't want to bother with moderating for a company that essentially threw her under the bus, but that should be up to her, shouldn't it? If she was wrongly removed, she should have the option of being reinstated; not the option of applying for *possible* reinstatement.

Comment: We don't know what the agreement was. But usually there is a give and take from both sides. We don't know the full terms, so we should give it all some time and see how it plays out.

Comment: @ModusTollens There definitely could be, but this is the information that the company decided to give us, so I personally think it's fair to respond to what we have.

Comment: Monica's apology was even called a "non-apology"

Comment: She [just commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio?cb=1#comment1139733_340914) that she *does* want to be re-instated. The fact that she has not *applied* to be re-instated under the new process is likely because of the fact that, as she explained in detail in her answer to the announcement of that process, she has reservations about the effectiveness and fairness of said process.

Comment: "I want to be reinstated (more specifically, for the removal to be reversed)"; she said she wants the diamond back. It might not technically count as the definition of reinstated under the new definition.,

Comment: Her (now edited) comment seems to imply that she feels that the removal was not following due process (the non-apology posted here seems to support that viewpoint), and therefore should be nullified. Therefore, she was never removed, and thus doesn't need to apply for re-instatement. I tend to agree.

Comment: I understand it to mean "reinstatement process" == "You are 'out' and get to go back 'in' but forever have it on your record" where "removal to be reversed" == "back to the previous status *as if the removal never happened*".

Comment: Sara  didn’t   admit fault, she just regret, that some events happened.

Answer (score 176):

In other words: "we wish this didn't happen, we're absolutely not sorry at all and did nothing wrong. Oh, and the new CoC obviously applied retroactively; shall we call you a waaaaambulance?" That is not an apology, that is yet another insult; do you think the users are bad at parsing it (yeah, you Did Something and that's it, fixed)? Merry Christmas to you, too (oh yeah, plus the traditional "posting this right as the holiday starts in the hopes of avoiding Streissand effect," very cute)

Edit: whence "this is not an apology"? A 
glossary:

- "I apologize": "I wish to fix my fault"
- "I'm sorry": "I acknowledge my fault"
- "I regret": "I wish I wasn't involved"

See what that means, and see the OP.

Comment: Quite right.  Man, I wish we could find a solicitor as good as whoever wrote the text at the top of this page.  It's hilarious that comments are now blocked, too.  (OK, if anyone is rude or personal - delete that comment.)

Comment: You're absolutely right: how typical of SE to post with such timing.

Answer (score 158):

> We believe she did not understand all of the nuances and full intent and meaning of our Code of Conduct and was confused about what actions it required and forbade.

## At the time of the relevant events, NO-ONE understood the Code of Conduct.

The details were still being worked out. FAQs were still being explained and re-explained. Problems in the wording were being addressed. No moderator, no-one in the community, and no Stack Exchange employee could claim in good faith to understand that which had yet to be defined.

As things stand, it's still not really the case that the community has come to a common understanding about these issues.

Monica was trying to help you guys out by helping to move the community towards a common understanding.

Saying "we believe she did not understand" sounds rather patronising.

Answer (score 158):

As a 35-year veteran of startups (including legal issues with employees), this is not as good an outcome for Monica as I would have hoped. I wonder if she spent any of the $30k from her GoFundMe account to get this 'agreement'? It doesn't seem like she got much for her money, if she did.

> We believe she did not understand all of the nuances and full intent and meaning of our Code of Conduct and was confused about what actions it required and forbade.

Not many posters today seem to be commenting that there were several COC's floating around at that time - the original one, and several draft versions of a new one. It's my understanding that only the new one(s) contained references to the 'gender' topic in detail, and this COC was not yet in force. So ... what exactly is 'our Code of Conduct' as referenced here?

> We regret any damage to Ms. Cellio's reputation and any other damage **she may have suffered**

I can handle 'regret' rather than 'apologize for' as basic legal weasel-words, but **she may have suffered** is a far cry from '**we may have caused**'.

Overall, this is a big non-apology. If, however, it hadn't been for the last paragraph, I'd have said - at least reading between the lines, 'this is an apology by the company and you can move on'.  But the last paragraph is a low blow.

> In recognition of the mistakes that **led us here**

(not 'mistakes we made'),

> we invited Ms. Cellio to apply for **possible** reinstatement on all six sites following our new reinstatement process.

This really sucks. Since she was - by their own admission - removed from the position without due process and without following stated guidelines, her removal should simply be 'negated' and she should be a moderator in good standing as if nothing ever happened.

My heart goes out to Monica. She must have been emotionally drained by this process and ready to accept this poor substitute for an apology.

As a startup with healthy venture funding, SO needs a squeeky-clean track record if they want to go public. Getting this issue swept under the rug was probably a priority.

Comment: Maybe they thought it was under the rug in this way, but their cheap cleaning solution is destroying the rug. They will see when they come back after holidays.

Comment: They're obviously looking for investors who don't know how to do Google searches.  Their mistreatment of Monica will be high in the results for a long time.

Comment: Aaah, thank you Steerpike, now I get the real reason for all this weaseling...

Answer (score 144):

When you state that

> We believe she did not understand all of the nuances and full intent
>   and meaning of our Code of Conduct

If I recall clearly, she was asking in order to comprehend such nuances and full intent. I believe this source of distrust will never be remediated, at least for users old enough to remember a different place and a different way of doing things.

For Monica, it seems, it's clear that the trust is not there.

Comment: There was a COC in place at the time she was asking for clarification on a new COC. She can't (logically) be accused of violating the 'new' COC as it was not yet finalized, so we must assume she's accused of violating the old (existing at that time) COC. It's not clear at all that she really violated the old COC.

Comment: @Steerpike But she DID lose her diamonds for supposedly violating the not-yet-in-effect CoC! Which is one reason, even without SE bad mouthing her to the press, why this whole situation is absurd.

Comment: Just to be clear: Stack Exchange has described the changes to the CoC as a "clarification" of the existing CoC, not as a "new" CoC. (I'm not getting into arguments in the comments over whether or not people believe that's the case.)

Answer (score 138):

**Confession is good for the soul.**

So far, you're still doing everything exactly wrong.  As plenty of people have already pointed out, this is a non-apology that essentially says "we're sorry that Monica misunderstood the rules and ended up accidentally breaking them, but we didn't do anything wrong."

Well... screw that.  Yes you did!  *You absolutely did do things wrong.*  I'm sure your lawyers are advising you to not admit wrongdoing "for legal reasons," but they're wrong.  That's how you deal with a case you expect to be able to win, but you can't win this one because you are clearly, objectively in the wrong.

**The only correct course of action in this case is to capitulate.**  Openly admit your guilt, reverse Monica's firing without any need for admissions of wrongdoing on her part, publicly retract your libelous comments against her in the media, and make restitution.  The things you've done were obvious enough and public enough, and angered enough people, that I honestly don't think the community will accept anything less.

This post?  This is beyond inadequate; it's straight-out insulting, both to Monica and also to all of us, for expecting us to be dumb enough to fall for it.

Comment: Perhaps there are more events in the pipeline that will be announced in the future. There is almost certainly nothing in legal agreement to prevent SO from doing all the things you suggested. In fact, the legal agreement almost certainly removes any legal repercussions for admitting all their guilt and coming clean about all **their** misdeeds.

Comment: @James You sure you're reading the same post I did?  Because it sure looks to me like they're trying to wash their hands of the whole thing and use their "legal agreement" that they oh-so-conveniently can't discuss as a shield to avoid actually addressing any of these important issues.

Comment: I am reading the same post, and no, there is nothing in it to make me hopeful for the short term. What I'm talking about is the legal agreement, not the content of this post. The company is now free to do everything in your paragraph *The only course of action...* without fear of **legal** repercussions. This will never happen with the current SO crop of managers, but employees move in and out of companies. Perhaps someone sane will take a job at SO and begin to right some of these wrongs.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct" here? Tactically or morally? If "tactically", then whatever you think SE's goals are, I think probably are not their goals. If "morally", then whatever moral code you hold to, I think SE does not hold to. And, for that matter, why would anyone expect one arbitrary person and one arbitrary corporation to fully understand each other's goals or morals?

Comment: @SteveJessop Sorry, but I don't believe in moral relativism.

Comment: Mason, your last sentence nails it for me.  I had hoped that something better would be the outcome, but am not surprised at how this turned out.  I appreciate the brevity with which you were able to hit the heart of the matter.

Answer (score 127):

**Enough is enough. The delay is far more than enough.
 We do not want another nonapology, this situation should've been ended way earlier than 2020.**

The post seemed ostensibly good, that the company officially acknowledged their misjudgment and revoking Monica's diamond. This is not a good statement at all. It already faced the same trajectory as her last post [now deleted].

## **Scenario**

**Imagine that:** You *deliberately* broke or discarded someone's collectible item, which could be anything ranging from a small toy to something as as valuable as a diamond. You promise you will buy a new and identical replacement later on and directly give it to her in apology.

*Will that person still feel the same to you after receiving the new "identical" diamond?*

**This is what Sara officially stated to “apologize”:**

> In recognition of the mistakes that led us here, we invited Ms. Cellio to *apply* for *possible* reinstatement on all six sites following our new reinstatement process.

What‽‽‽ She is asking Monica to *reapply* for the new diamond. Keywords are “apply” and “possible”; her application might be rejected. She is not *even* guaranteeing that she will give out a replacement diamond for her, in which being a staff she may *instantly give out to her* because this is an *exception that needs to be handled*. Figuratively, you [or an official statement under your name] sprayed more corrosive salt to the wound, which leads to more pain and even infection.

## Impact

It also affects other people who regularly contribute or even read this site including me, which at that time I am mostly away for work-related and research-related reasons. I only recently came back to SE and found out the gravity of this *exception*; I barely even contributed to Meta before that. I am not a high-XP user but just another SE user who shows general interest in programming, topics, and the site. Also, I am one of the first to see and comment on that post.

The best outcome is if this chaos never happened in the first place; that SE follows everything that should be done to moderators and ordinary users alike. Or that her diamond is found and given back seconds after; when Monica's diamond was given back minutes after her wrongful dismissal. Monica is very upset and many other moderators wholly lost their will to contribute. *The staff has delayed for months and months* and refused to give back the intangible diamond they took away.

Please, we need to take real action, not get into more "non-apologies" and "I regret that…" statements. Staff can give out the replacement diamond to her, and if they would otherwise offered the replacement minutes after taking it away, this *exception* won't even happen.

This is *not* even a halfway-acceptable resolution to a historic SOF event which resulted in the resignation of numerous diamond-moderators and an atomsphere of general distrust and exasperation among the SOF community. Indeed, it will not negate the damage already done, either to Monica, nor the collateral damage done to the other users. The post resulted in *zero* effective action despite her publicly statement that she [maybe representing all of SE staff acknowledges the company's miscommunication. Her response is **not a solution at all** to this catastrophic SOF event.

Comment: Latest archived [last post](https://web.archive.org/web/20191223041817/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology)

Answer (score 115):

So you're still not going to accept that your statements about her were actually wrong, you just "regret the damage to [her] reputation"?

It seems you've decided not to take your last opportunity to make this right and instead targeted getting the maximum you possibly could from the legal process. The community resentment and distrust will stay with Stack Exchange, and particularly the people most directly responsible, for years.

I'll be keeping the "Apologise to Monica" in my name for a while yet.

Comment: Also they are putting the blame on her, with statements about how "she was just confused."

Comment: I still feel "un-slander" needs to stay in mine -- I know it's basically an impossible option, but it's the only true resolution.    ... and "only sorry about the media..." that's like their "apology" before about "shipping on Friday", eh?

Comment: This **is** retraction of any slander, by any definition that matters to the parties involved. Whether you like or not, an agreement between SO and MC has been reached, and the issue is resolved as far as they can or will accept. Harping on about making apologies or retractions is to completely ignore the fact it has already been done, and only adds to the feeling that too many people are just here to attack SO using MC as a martyr, not actually caring about what MC wants or has.

Comment: As someone who formerly spent a lot of time on the [ell.se] Stack Exchange, I think this latest Sara Chipps post would a great example to explain the idiom [_a day late and a dollar short_](https://grammarist.com/idiom/a-day-late-and-a-dollar-short/).

Answer (score 106):

A disappointing, but unsurprising result that only confirms that Stack Exchange Inc. is now infested with a corporate culture that not only fails to take responsibility when it is wrong, but refuses to even admit it's wrong. That sort of mentality is well-documented to doom companies, and I for one cannot wait to see that happen, because sometimes the only way to fix something that has been unbelievably twisted beyond its original purpose is to let it destroy itself so that you can rebuild from the ashes.

As for Monica, I hope she received a decent settlement, although I doubt anything will make up for the damage to her reputation and personal distress she's endured. Part of me is sad that she didn't fight to get the apology and retraction that she deserves; but I also appreciate that she likely has little wish to continue dealing with the bad-faith actor that is SE Inc., and just wants this whole sordid business put behind her.

Amazing how much goodwill a simple apology can achieve... amazing how much goodwill the lack of one can destroy.

Comment: [**The Long-Forgotten Flight That Sent Boeing Off Course** - *A company once driven by engineers became driven by finance.*](https://www.theatlantic.com/ideas/archive/2019/11/how-boeing-lost-its-bearings/602188/) ... "For about 80 years, Boeing basically functioned as an association of engineers. Its executives held patents, designed wings, spoke the language of engineering and safety as a mother tongue. Finance wasn’t a primary language." ... nowadays planes are falling from the sky and basic security features are sold as "add-ons"

Comment: Sad to see SE turn into myspace, but it'll be so well-deserved

Comment: @brasofilo This seems like a familiar pattern with tech companies.

Answer (score 98):

I do assume that SE Inc. respectively the OP is telling us the truth, and that there is some sort of agreement between the two parties, and yes, we can find the **same** statement also on her [gofundme](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users) page. But let me say the following, which raised like all my eyebrows immediately.

You start with this:

> We sincerely hope she remains an active member of our community.

To then continue with:

> In recognition of the mistakes that led us here, we invited Ms. Cellio to apply for possible reinstatement on all six sites following our new reinstatement process.

Honestly, together that reads naive and awkward *at best*.

But it rather feels like a bully who challenged the wrong person and who still tries to put up their own rules, to then blame the other party who refuses to follow said rules.

If you really want her to stay because of her great contributions, then ask yourself  why you start with ignoring her objections about the process you want her to go through. To give her **back** something she earned from community members electing her. And which you **took** from her in the most dubious way possible.

I wish I could change my user name to

> Ghostcat says: SE Inc **should** have reinstated Monica

but alas, too long to fit into the 30 character name limit.

But that is what I feel and think right now. It is probably a good thing that there is an agreement between the two parties, but it is a sad day for **this** community that Monica won't come back as moderator (here). We lost a lot, and SE Inc. gained nothing!

Answer (score 87):

> While our initial statement did not address her specifically, we
>   regret that we used her name when responding to a reporter's
>   follow-up. We regret any damage to Ms. Cellio's reputation and any
>   other damage she may have suffered.

It is hopelessly inadequate. IIRC, part of the problem was the reporting of the incident to the press with all the implicit connotations made against Monica's personality. If this isn't followed up with a retraction in the press as well, then it's a bit of a nothing. "we're not even sorry we implied she was a bigot which will remain on the Internet forever, but we regret saying her name even though we didn't say her name, right".

The entire incident with the press was unacceptable, and now they simply wheedle out of it with more "and we did nothing wrong" faux apologies.

This may end the legal threat, but it (again) does nothing to suggest to us that SE is a reputable company led by people with integrity.

Answer (score 84):

Now… look what Santa put under the Meta.SE Christmas tree.

Geez, it is sad to see that it took ages for Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow to finally recognize that there actually might be some kind of problem for them to fix. Though, personally, I am not able to detect any hint that Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow also grasps that the problem is on *their* side. I mean, like it or not, but fact is that this whole drama was started by a knee-jerk reaction on the corporate side and has been evolving in a bad way ever since. It wasn’t something the community’s or an individual Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow user did.

I have long kept my mouth shut about why I once dropped my mod gig, but it’s about time to note that the way Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow – as a company with a community of hard contributing users – slowly slid towards where they are now, was one of the main reasons why I stepped down as a Crypto.SE moderator in December 2018.

Seeing how things evolved left and right during the past twelve months, then standing on the sidelines while watching this whole Monica event turn from a “misunderstanding” to a full fledged community drama fueled by Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow, and finally stumbling upon this post at Meta, merely confirms that my stepping down and pulling back from investing time and efforts in a Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow community site obviously was not the baddest idea. From my perspective, things got even worse than I suspected them to become. It feels like having to watch a company shoot itself in the foot in almost every way possible, while I can’t do anything to make it stop.

Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow was once such a great community to be part of and I loved contributing. Now, it just feels hostile – not because if its users, but because of the way the company running Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow handles things.

Just look at the most recent example:

> …we regret that we used her name when responding to a reporter's follow-up.

I mean, really?

It’s things like these that are **anything but constructive** and it’s things like these that strongly impact the public image of Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow as a company.

If it weren’t that sad, I would joke that it’s not the users but rather Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow as company who needs a working “Code of Conduct” for itself. One which would prevent Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow from bluntly kicking benign users and (as in Monica’s case) mods who represent the better pieces of the cake Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow Inc feeds on.

[image: user management – you’re doing it wrong]

<sup>(No worries, the kid is not tied up but rather standing behind the cardboard. It’s a halloween costume. [This is how it works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXbPE.jpg))</sup>

Last but not least, I would like to note that this *“Update: an agreement with Monica Cellio”* post **should actually have been posted in the Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow Blog**,  as that’s what the world sees and reads. Putting it on Meta.SE – where it is bound to be buried by the dust of time and new Q&As – merely underlines that Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow obviously has not fully grasped how their public image suffers from the way things like these are handled.

Anyway, merry Xmas to y’all.
Peace on Earth et al.

Comment: @e-sushi - looking at the bigger picture, I wonder if the downfall of SE started when they tried to apply the strict 'Q and A' process and supporting engine, which arguably applies well to techie questions, to more nuanced topics such as 'Christianity', 'worldbuilding', etc.  Trying to define one process (and associated toolset) that accommodates such a different set of subjects seems 'ambitious' (or naive).

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica, did you see any constructive dialog from SO Inc side during the last three months, in particular from Sara Chipps?

Comment: Also, to be fair about the last paragraph, Monica's demodding was discussed here, and the "apology" posts were made here too. It would seem strange to me for them to put it on the blog (whose audience is generally programmers, not the general userbase of the network) when it was never previously mentioned there. It would likely rehash the drama rather than resolve it (and rehashing the drama is obviously not something SE wants, but I don't think it's something Monica wants either).

Comment: @V2Blast Well, to be fair, Stack Exchange Inc's actions even spiralled this whole drama into the general media amd news outlets outside this website… where the audience isn't even part of this community and notneven part of the usual SE blog readers. See where I'm getting at? Once things left SE networks, stuff became generally public to everyone out there — therefore I think it's strange but very telling they now try to hide the end in the depths of Meta. SE was once hugged for its public comms, but not anymore.Yet, that's just my perspective of course.

Comment: @BelovedFool - That's actually a [Halloween costume](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Hannibal+lector+halloween+costume&t=ffab&atb=v112-1&ia=images&iax=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fi.pinimg.com%2Foriginals%2Fa0%2Ff1%2F0d%2Fa0f10d8dc5c6b824f65560fca40b3901.jpg). The child is dressed as [Hannibal Lecter](https://everipedia.org/wiki/lang_en/Hannibal_Lecter) - there are other examples that show that the child's feet are behind the cardboard so they can walk themselves around. They aren't as restrained as they appear, just so you know. I imagine it could be quite upsetting if you thought it was real.

Comment: "I imagine it could be quite upsetting if you [weren't familiar with this in context]." I don't know what the deleted comment said, but to confirm imagination, I was upset when I saw this post a few days ago. And I didn't feel like engaging with it. // Thanks to everyone for improving it! Particularly including the Hannibal Lecter link. Because I didn't recognize it, and trying to work out what that image meant led me to *other* dark places. (Setting aside the merits of the horror movie reference. Personally that doesn't bother me).

Comment: @sourcejedi It wasn’t a comment, it was an edit to put the image in a spoiler block to hide it. I thought it was important to let folks know it wasn’t what it looked like, because I wouldn’t want anyone having that image in their brain as anything other than a halloween costume.

Comment: @Steerpike there are a number of users with long standing, and a lot of new users at SE sites, who find that the shoe-horning of the techie centric Q&A model that works well on the professional stacks to be a bad fit for the "softer" stacks.  Been in a variety of discussions/metas on that very topic.

Answer (score 78):

So you've made an "agreement" that you're going to claim legally prevents you from even starting to do anything to win back the trust of your user community? (Such as giving the user community an explanation of what happened and what you've done to guarantee that other users who happen to catch the random unfounded ire of some SE employee won't be treated in the same way).

This is not a smart move.

I'm out.

Comment: Another clear message that will go unheard...

Comment: With their strategy, trying to burry this case and do as if nothing happened, it is a smart move. While the StackOverflow is being replaced with something else on the Internet (which will take some years) they will already have made a well established dominance with their 'teams' product, and that is all they want (Why should they, from the point of view of making profit, care about the community at this point? The community has delivered a website complete with an enormous amount of Q&A and meta data, we are not useful anymore).

Answer (score 74):

### Why are all of these sweeping — and somewhat dramatic — declarations from the staff to the “community” being made during various holidays and seemingly at the last minute?

So I am barely invested in this whole mess — and let’s admit that, it is a mess — but as a bystander who is looking at this from a fairly neutral high perspective, I want to dig up a fairly basic quote from you Sara Chipps from the now deleted October 3rd post titled, “An Update to our Community and an Apology.”

> “We learned (or were painfully reminded, rather) to never ship at 6 PM (EDT) on a Friday.”

Really? This was a lesson learned?

Because this post right here was posted on December 23rd, a day when many people are traveling for the holidays and on the second night of Hanukkah. And not for nothing, today — December 24th — is Christmas Eve; another fairly major holiday that affects a huge chunk of the Stack Exchange community.

Granted, Hanukkah is not considered the most important of holidays in Judaism, but still…

#### I’m not trying to be snarky, but seriously… Come on… Either everyone involved in truly unaware of the holidays this time of year or there *might* be an effort to bury this stuff so it just goes away.

I want to accept this post as heartfelt and true, but I read this and I see something “off” about this all: From the initial incidents, to the update about the initial incidents to this post itself.

I genuinely wish all who read this — and who are involved with this — have a happy holidays, but seriously… There are issues here that still suffer from open wounds and covered ears.

Comment: This latest message likely had **nothing** to do with holidays or even "end of year". It had **everything** to do with when the lawyers could hammer out an agreement to the satisfaction of both sides. That can happen at odd times.

Comment: @manassehkatz-ReinstateMonica: That was my thought as well. Monica would want the public slander retracted ASAP, and Stack Exchange Inc. ostensibly wanted the situation resolved as quickly as possible as well. Both sides would find it better to post about the agreement as soon as it's done, rather than arbitrarily force themselves to wait due to holidays.

Comment: @manassehkatz-ReinstateMonica Eh, I think we can all be “right” in a case like this: Yes, end this nonsense once and for all and as soon as possible before the end of the year. But it’s a fairly common political move to state and issue things at the end of the week, at the end of the day, before a major event, etc… Hopefully in a few months the dust settles enough so all are happy or at least not as “ruffled” as the community seems to be now.

Comment: Whether or not the timing is intentional, it's solid evidence that even the minor lesson Stack Exchange claims they were taught from this catastrophe is already forgotten, or was never really learned in the first place.

Comment: The timing may have been unintentional but the irony is truly unsettling.

Answer (score 74):

This is not a remotely adequate response from Stack Overflow.

Outside of a fairly weak response to the defamation (I'd expect a strong apology in the media linked in the question above, given that her name was publicly trashed in the media), there seems to be nothing here we hadn't seen months ago, and in fact it seems to be a strong step *backward* from the tone of David Fullerton's post. None of this remotely addresses the issues that led me to stand down as moderator. It seems to be an even more strident digging-in of heels, but now with Monica completely silenced to boot.

This is not how you mend fences with your community. It's now quite clear what the attitude is to people that contribute value to your company for free - one totally lacking in even basic respect.

Whatever the agreement with Monica, it presumably doesn't stop SO from reinstating her unconditionally (or offering that). *Then* if there was some problem, you can readily follow the proper procedures; it might give us a chance to see how they work (if at all). It would be a trivial matter to do so (to just reinstate her), but it's obvious why those proper procedures won't be followed -- because it isn't certain to get rid of someone you decided to get rid of; accountability and openness are just too difficult for SO, apparently.

Comment: What makes you think SO wanted to "mend fences with community" ? They have dealt with Monica

Comment: SO doesn't need to care about mending fences with the "community". This is, at worst, going to cost them a few single digit percentage of content generators, who will be replaced with new content generators within months, if not already. And as data-driven as the company is, they've surely run these numbers already and determined that it doesn't matter what you content generators think because you're still generating content despite everything. This is why I stopped moderating AND answering questions on SF 
the instant I first heard about this situation, and haven't done either since.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Even if I accept the premise that SO doesn't have a strong business incentive to mend fences, it's still seems to be the case that mending fences with the community has no downsides at all and could only help them business-wise. However small that improvement is, it's still an improvement. That's assuming that SO will act rationally in their own interest.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk If SO were going to act rationally, Monica would have gotten her diamonds back months ago and the lawyers would never have gotten involved to begin with...or she never would have lost them in the first place. I wouldn't hold out much hope of rationality, especially now that the lawyers _are_ involved, and probably advising SO to _not_ mend fences with the community.

Answer (score 72):

One good turn deserves another.

You've unconditionally, unarguably and unilaterally fired Ms. Cellio. Since you've admitted that it was your fault, now it's time for you to reinstate her back in the same manner.

That aside, I'm delighted to see a positive step towards a resolution of the ongoing stream of issues. I'm sure you're more than eager to **prove your sincerity with your actions**, aren't you?

Answer (score 69):

So... what's the agreement?

Besides the acknowledgement of wrongdoing here, nothing in this post seems to reflect a change from where we were months ago. The only bits that sound like any action has been taken are these...

> We have since updated some of our policies and processes to help ensure we are more careful in our public communications, and that there is a clearer process anytime a moderator's status is revoked as well as a process for reinstatement.
>
> We respect Ms. Cellio and believe she is a good person with much to offer and contribute. We sincerely hope she remains an active member of our community. In recognition of the mistakes that led us here, we invited Ms. Cellio to apply for possible reinstatement on all six sites following our new reinstatement process. Ms. Cellio expressed concerns about the new process and has not applied.

... but all those actions were already taken in October. (See [Under what circumstances will Stack Exchange, Inc. share private/sensitive information with the press?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335749/200582) and [Feedback post: Moderator review and reinstatement processes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336177/200582).)

I therefore don't understand, upon reading this, what's new. Is the "agreement" something that's happened behind the scenes (e.g. a payoff to Monica in exchange for her not pursuing her libel case and not publicly commenting further on this issue) that we're never to be privy to?

Comment: Any legal agreement was always almost certainly going to happen roughly like this: behind closed doors with us only getting some public lawyer-vetted statements. I do have to believe the agreement was at least somewhat favourable for Monica. I really would've liked to see them do more publicly to try to repair her image though. I wasn't optimistic about reinstatement; it's been way too late for that for a while in my opinion. It probably would've been hard to work together again after all this public conflict and lawyers.

Comment: My best guess is that this post is (part of) the agreement: By countering almost any negative claim about Monica that could be floating out there, it's a 'legal' but 'public' thing that can be pointed to whenever someone finds the negative claims, thus mitigating 'defamation'. JUST A GUESS though!

Comment: The "An Update to our Community and an Apology" which claimed that Monica "repeatedly violated our existing Code of Conduct" and that Monica was "unwilling to accept our CM’s repeated requests to change" was also removed yesterday @Tinkeringbell, which is almost certainly part of the agreement.

Answer (score 69):

To add my two cents worth...

Firstly, at the time that Monica was fired, *there was no Code of Conduct that covered her alleged and as-yet undisclosed infraction*.  Of course she didn't understand it... *no-one* did, since it was still being formulated.

Secondly, Monica was fired in error... The existence of this question is an admission of that error.  Monica has previously stated that she wants to resume her moderator positions, but that she is unwilling to *apply* to have them potentially restored, as that would be an admission that there was justification for their removal.

So...  Unless Monica chooses to state that she does not desire reinstatement...:

Stack Exchange,  please consider this answer to be an application to have all of Monica Cellio's moderator statuses restored, on the grounds that they were removed in error by your own admission, and that prior to the agreement being reached between Monica and Stack Exchange, Monica had repeatedly expressed a desire to resume her former positions as moderator of multiple stack exchange sites.

I would invite all Stack Exchange users who read this and who wish Monica to be reinstated to upvote this answer and add a comment indicating your support for Monica's full and unconditional  reinstatement.

Answer (score 68):

I'm glad some kind of agreement could be reached, and I'm hoping to see more of this light. This is a step in the right direction, but the paragraph below is something that needs a bit more work though.

> In recognition of the mistakes that led us here, we invited Ms. Cellio to apply for possible reinstatement on all six sites following our new reinstatement process.

Analogy: I'm sorry your foot hurts when stepped on, now you may ask me to get off of it.

Hopefully, it is easier to see the problem with it now.

Answer (score 66):

#### This is an empty apology

> We believe she did not understand all of the nuances and full intent and meaning of our Code of Conduct and was confused about what actions it required and forbade.

That is a strawman. It was not at all the problem.

> We acknowledge our responses to her requests for clarification were not satisfactory.

This is an extreme understatement. The responses were hostile.

> While our initial statement did not address her specifically, we regret that we used her name when responding to a reporter's follow-up. We regret any damage to Ms. Cellio's reputation and any other damage she may have suffered.

You hurt someone by means of misconduct, and the only thing that you do is just say that you regret it?

> In recognition of the mistakes that led us here, we invited Ms. Cellio to apply for possible reinstatement on all six sites following our new reinstatement process. Ms. Cellio expressed concerns about the new process and has not applied.

This is not a correction of the bad actions.

---

#### Is it really an agreement?

You could say that SE has been digging their heels in by trying to go to the bottom in the legal process and turning it into a battle.

- Instead of sincerely admitting their mistakes, apologising to Monica and do whatever needs to be done when you admit you made a mistake (no matter the legal  consequences, since a person that admits their mistake should agree with those consequences)...
- Instead of that they state they can not do and say anything for legal reasons and let their lawyers do the apology to Monica.

Maybe this has been settled, but it is very unsatisfactory for the community.

This ugly apology/update shows to the community that Monica has *not* been on the winning side of the settlement. It is prove, or at least an indication, of the maltreatment path that SE/SO takes towards their respected moderator (is this really respect?). This behaviour can now be hidden behind polished pretty words that do not mean anything.

SE/SO can show of their trophy *'that they reached an "agreement"'* and for the rest they can refer to a non disclosure agreement. Thus the settlement allows this sad story/apology, but it doesn't allow a single word/statement from Monica how she thinks about it? That sounds very much like a forced agreement to me.

Comment: For your first two points, you might be missing some context - Monica sent e-mails asking questions (/for clarifications?) And it looks like this is what the first couple of points are actually addressing... I don't disagree with the rest of what you've written though

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 we are still guessing here but is it those emails that caused her to be demodded? I was under the impression that it was for certain statements in the teacher lounge. Aside from that, the way that it is phrased is like 'sorry you did not understand us' and that is extremely condescending and denying that there is much blame on the side of SE/SO. Then note the second point, their response was not just unsatisfactory, they were hostile responses (demodding and defamation)

Answer (score 62):

> We acknowledge our responses to her requests for clarification were not satisfactory.

A good step in the right direction, however...

> We believe that Ms. Cellio was not acting with malicious intent. We believe she did not understand all of the nuances and full intent and meaning of our Code of Conduct and was confused about what actions it required and forbade.

This comes under the impression that Monica committed wrongdoing in the first place. Violating an unclear, unrefined code of conduct by *asking for clarity about it* that wasn't even applicable to the site as a whole yet in a private chatroom (the Teacher's Lounge) designed to garner clarity around difficult issues.

I'm happy that there's finally a degree of agreement between SE and Monica. It's been awhile without much update, but as the situation had turned legal, I suppose that's to be expected.

Lastly,

> We invited Ms. Cellio to apply for possible reinstatement on all six sites following our new reinstatement process. Ms. Cellio expressed concerns about the new process and has not applied.

Her issues with the reinstatement process were [rather detailed as an answer on your meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336177/feedback-post-moderator-review-and-reinstatement-processes/336236#336236) and the specific issues Monica had with it were largely ignored. Though to be fair, the comments got very numerous.

I'm firmly of the position that SE will never reinstate Monica without forcing her to go through the [reinstatement process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336175/what-is-the-process-for-reinstating-a-moderator). During which, as far as I understand, a single community manager can choose to halt the process entirely.

Instead of focusing on Monica's issue specifically, I feel as though we should focus on SE's rather erroneous lack of transparency not only on this issue, but on [many other issues detailed in this longstanding meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper).

Keep moving forward, SE. This is your chance to start to make things right.

Answer (score 62):

Everyone else has pointed out that this reads like lawyer speak, likely because it is and I'm guessing this is the outcome of the discussions between lawyers. Since nobody can talk about the actual agreement, there's not really that much to say.

I do note that there doesn't actually appear to be an public apology from Stack Overflow to Monica Cellio in this post. I also find it very interesting that you didn't just reinstate Cellio as moderator and are making her go through a "reinstatement process." Having seen similar situations, I'm going to interpret this as "Didn't quite have the legal grounds to fire you at the time, so if you apply for a job again *maybe* we will hire you again." Of course, most reasonable people don't want to return to work in a [hostile work environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostile_work_environment).

On a lighter note, I find it grimly ironic that as a child I was given detention for telling another student "I'm sorry you were offended by what I said." but as an adult I see similar language being dictated by lawyers.

Comment: That's not a lighter note.

Comment: What did you say to offend the student?

Answer (score 62):

After reading the "Update" and many, many answers I have a few thoughts. Some of my thoughts will echo what a lot of others have said.

*(This part is just my speculation)*

This "Update" sounds like it is *part* of an agreement, this is not the agreement. The lawyers made SE post a recant of their actions. Each paragraph touches on one of the points of pain here. CoC, the "warning", media, policies and processes, and reinstatement.

The reason neither side can comment is because no doubt there is a non-disclosure clause in the agreement. Meaning that when this is finally over and done, we (the community) will get to know nothing.

I can only hope the agreement Monica and SE have come to is fairer than this legalese.

---

As soon as I saw this I wondered about when this was posted... (Granted they did not post on a Friday afternoon.) Is it a coincidence this was posted during **the lowest point of activity for the whole year**?

Now SE can easily brush that off by saying "this was an important issue for many in our community, as such we wanted to get the information out as soon as possible."

But that's not good enough for me.
The Update reads like a coerced post, there is no soul to it. It is all meaningless words, and it sounds like SE's lawyers are trying to admit as little as possible, while maintaining their position.

From my perspective I'm again saddened by this "Update."

Comment: very astute analysis.  I agree

Comment: This is where SE should have been earning trust so the community can give them the benefit of the doubt. Because they have not, I have no choice but to assume the 12/23 date was deliberate.

Answer (score 58):

> ...we invited Ms. Cellio to apply for possible reinstatement on all six
>   sites following our new reinstatement process. Ms. Cellio expressed
>   concerns about the new process and has not applied.

People have already pointed out the assumption of guilt here, and I would like to add that this feels very much like a strategic move to "officially" torpedo, or at least severely handicap Monica's mod status. *Even if* Monica chose to go this route, [this reinstatement process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336175/what-is-the-process-for-reinstating-a-moderator) would put her mod status in the fate of 3 CMs who are supposed to be impartial, but I question if any SE CM would fit that description now (i.e, if there is anyone left who could approach this from a "clean slate" so to speak). Further still, if she passes this and isn't given the official thumbs down, the reinstatement process allows for arbitrary preconditions that she would have to follow "or else" - and I can only imagine what kind of conditionals would be enforced here.

Answer (score 57):

Many responses here to [Update: an agreement with Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio/341059#341059) deal with the last two sentences.

But given, the preceding text, the last two sentences don't come as a surprise.

The language used in the update induced me to search for "fake apology". Some apt quotes follow in the hope that there can be a beneficial closure to this sad affair:

From [The Top 12 Fake Apologies — And What Makes For An Authentic Apology](https://blogs.psychcentral.com/love-matters/2018/06/the-top-12-fake-apologies-and-what-makes-for-an-authentic-apology/)

> Apologizing can renew trust, soothe hurt feelings and return the lifeblood to a damaged relationship. But when someone hurts you and gives you a fake apology, it can make things worse, not better.

From [Sorry, Not Sorry](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2019/12/sorry-no-apologies/600742/)

> There was a time in American public life when atonement was seen as a form of strength—a way not only to own up to one’s missteps, but also to do that classic work of crisis management: control the narrative. (“I’m the responsible officer of the government,” John F. Kennedy said of the Bay of Pigs. “This happened on my watch,” Ronald Reagan said of Iran-Contra. “I take full responsibility for the federal government’s response,” George W. Bush said of Hurricane Katrina.) Bucks stopped. Power came with responsibility.

From [6 Types of Apologies That Aren't Apologies at All](https://www.cracked.com/blog/6-types-apologies-that-arent-apologies-at-all/) in the section *Mistakes were made*

> For those who feel that "deeply regret" is admitting too much responsibility, they can upgrade to "mistakes were made," the highest level of non-apology, used at the highest levels of government. Presidents as diverse as Reagan and Clinton have used the phrase, which one-ups "deeply regret" by not only leaving it open whether they are actually the culprit but existentially questioning whether there even is one.

Answer (score 56):

This statement was made strictly to address the libel Monica suffered at the hands of SE employees. The issue of libel is the *only* thing Monica is able to hold SE legally liable for. How SE chooses to manage mods on their sites is up to their discretion. So this is probably the most Monica could hope for via the lawsuit.

Reading between the lines, this statement was mandated by the settlement. But the people involved in stripping Monica of her diamond don't really want her back, and it's up to their discretion, so they're "offering" her a way to get her diamond back that they know she'll refuse. They're not the least bit sorry, and are continuing to wield their power in a toxic way. SE's relationship with the community is still really, really toxic, and the internal employees responsible for this are not changing tack.

(Conjecture: having it appear on "Featured on Meta" across all SE sites was probably also part of the settlement. Having this specific employee post the statement may even have been part of it too.)

Comment: If the company truly wanted to fix things up then, in addition to giving the diamonds back, the message would have been from the CEO. Other companies have done such things. SE did not.

Comment: Well, my guess is the person who posted the message may have been mandated by the settlement. To your point though, the fact that Monica's diamond wasn't given back is a sign of how SE really feels

Answer (score 54):

To sum up your statement: despite no evidence or details of Monica's alleged misconduct, you still believe she was in the wrong, but you are willing to (condescendingly) admit that maybe she didn't do that (whatever *that* is) on purpose. The only fault on your side is perhaps miscommunication. In light of that, you graciously allow her to *petition* for reinstatement.

// todo: insert "I am a merciful God" meme

Answer (score 46):

*About the agreement*: it's important to point out that both sides have published the same notice. Ms Chipps, as Director of Public Q/A, did it here, while Ms Cellio did it on her GoFundMe page (locked for now). Nothing has been posted on Monica's blog as of this post was written.

It seems important that we allow both sides to keep working, without disturbing/bothering them. Sure, we can still talk about the processes, about things that need to be improved around the network, but please, let's be careful not to harm Monica (who can't comment, as she stated). Under what seems to be a standard NDA, Ms Chipps can't comment either (as she stated in a comment). So, if we write or spread wrong things or ideas, it may do more harm than good, we should just be very careful not to do that.

This statement is a first step. Many people wouldn't think it could even happen, but it did. If Monica agreed to this, let's assume it's good enough for her? Negotiation is almost always a give and take game. Let's trust Monica to be smart enough to have gotten the best she could get for her because she's clever.

People who supported her can still do. People who fought for an improved community can still do. Defaming this statement, agreed by both sides, while same both sides can't comment or defend themselves, might not be the best way to discuss all still pending and related issues. Healing takes time, and we might just be still "licking the wounds". Just my two cents...

Comment: "They reached an agreement." That means they aren't going to "keep working"--they're done, it's over. Certainly Monica agreed to this, but it's plausible that Monica sincerely believed that this agreement was the best that was going to actually happen, & so it was this or nothing. It's hard to say that this agreement is something she actually finds agreeable on its merits. Her statement that she would like the removal to be reversed implies the agreement is not fully acceptable.

Comment: @gung : agreeing doesn't mean you're done talking and working. You still have sometimes a lot more to do before all points agreed upon are effectively reached. So, all that's important (to many of us), at the moment, is that she feels better (hope she does!) and that the process of her name being cleaned is on its way. 1/2

Comment: (2/2) and when a company agrees to let you go through one of their processes as part as an agreement, it's merely to say there was a process. By doing that, they let the person say "*no I don't wish to come back*". Or, if the person goes through and is reinstalled, company can say "*see how our new process is fair and good*". And not reinstalling the person would instantly light another equivalent fire and putting oil on it. They sure wouldn't do that IMO.

Comment: *...not reinstalling the person would instantly light another equivalent fire and putting oil on it. They sure wouldn't do that IMO.* This assertion is contradicted by the facts. Fact 1: There is no reason Monica should have to go through a process to be reinstated. Fact 2: Monica has already said no to the reinstatement process, and the SO notice here reinforces that. Fact 3: They could just as easily unilaterally reinstated Monica (i.e. given her back her diamond)  and Monica could've easily responded by resigning from her moderator roles.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk: if you (a company) publicly tell a person to go through a process *you* just put in place, you can be sure you can't fail or be blamed by that same company, unless that company wants to light another fire. Do they? Hm... *Automatic reinstatement* would say with too loud a voice "**we were sooo wrong**".  Going through the process would say: we made mistakes (who is we?) and we (SO Inc.) help fix them. Good guy, bad guy?

Comment: This statement is a steaming pile of legalese newspeak,

Comment: @Richard: as always... It couldn't be different, because, since the GoFundMe raising, it was only legal stuff. Lawyers involved means lawyers talk. Like in any case when you have a government/union/politician/spokeperson and the need to comment/publish anything. Always the same way, same ambiguous words, same "*I say it but I don't say it*" arguments. (shrug)

Comment: @OldPadawan It could have been different.  IANAL, but I have been around enough legalese to know the difference between sincere and insincere, and yes, both can be conveyed through legalese.  Just like when someone leaves a company.  If the announcement is "Left to pursue other opportunities", it means he was fired.  If it says "We wish him all the best in his future endeavors" he left on good terms.  This has all the sincerity of a 3rd grader being made to apologize in front of the class for pulling a classmate's hair.

Comment: Also, there are different ways of being ambiguous.  I have had to learn this because my autism makes it very difficult to lie.  Case in point, at my mother's funeral, a coworker she didn't like showed up and introduced herself.  I said, honestly, "Oh yes, she spoke of you often".  The implication there was positive.  Ambiguity can lean positive, negative, or be entirely neutral.  SE's statement was more negative than anything else.

Comment: @Richard: agree with you... You can almost always "*smell*" the taste of (in)sincerity in these kind of statements, no matter who wrote them. I won't comment because, as I said, I don't want to harm or hurt Monica or anybody else. Just hope she got the best for her. If other battles (for community's sake) need to be fought, they may be linked, but should be separated.

Comment: @OldPadawan I'm still debating as to whether or not I would walk away.  I did leave for a while, but came back when I found out about this mess.  This whole mess has become a bit of a zeitgeist now, reflecting what many believe to be the spirit of SE as a whole.  I don't know how SE will dig themselves out of this hole.  The negative votes are pretty much an indication of just how little trust the user base has, at this point.  At least the active user base.

Answer (score 45):

I don't believe that your agreement precludes you from admitting fault.

I do believe that the agreement protects you from further legal action.

If you are protected from further legal action then there is no legal risk in admitting fault. I can only surmise that you avoided admitting fault because you don't believe you did anything wrong.

This is clearly the **final nail**, and it's clear that you haven't been building a bridge.

Comment: Exactly. Or they could have offered to admit fault as part of the settlement without attempting to extract any concessions in return. Monica certainly wouldn't have objected.

Answer (score 44):

This announcement update reads like lawyer-speak; as others have already noted, likely because it is. It also reads rather like another of the series of non-apology apologies that have been posted in this matter, which at first glance appear to offer an apology but once you start picking them apart turn out to not be apologetic at all (except in the sense of "we're sorry we got caught").

However, Monica Cellio has, within the last few hours, turned off donations for the [Defend Monica from Defamation by Stack Overflow](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users) GoFundMe campaign and linked to the statement here from that campaign. Even though Monica is clearly not allowed to comment on the agreement, and Sara Chipps has stated that further comments will not be forthcoming from company officials, until otherwise indicated, and even though I do not know any details about the agreement beyond those posted in these two locations, **I'm willing to take that action of Monica's as a proxy indication that Monica accepts the outcome of the negotiations.**

> unfortunately I can't comment further. Apologies in advance for any frustration that causes. – Sara Chipps♦ 1 hour ago
>   we truly can't for legal reasons. – Sara Chipps♦ 1 hour ago

I'm hopeful that this agreement between Stack Overflow Inc and Monica Cellio is a positive, at least partial, resolution specifically between them.

**I also note that this does little to address** the many other issues raised by various members of the community over the recent months and year(s). Stack Overflow Inc therefore, in my opinion, still has a long way to go in repairing the damage caused by the events that have taken place since long before Monica was summarily dismissed as a moderator, some of which I have enumerated in other posts I have made on the network, and others of which have been discussed by other users.

Comment: It's plausible that Monica sincerely believed that this agreement was the best that was going to actually happen, & so it was this or nothing.  It's hard to say that this agreement is something she actually finds agreeable on its merits. Her [statement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio#comment1139733_340914) that she would like the removal to be reversed implies the agreement is not fully acceptable. I agree that, even if both sides are happy w/ this outcome, this does not address the other issues of concern to the community.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica *"Her statement that she would like the removal to be reversed implies the agreement is not fully acceptable."* Hence "at least partial".

Answer (score 44):

I won't reiterate in detail what others have said (for short: forced apology, false apology, "invitation for *possible* reinstatment", lawyer speak, etc...). Criticizing the wording and speculating about the reasons and implications of the wording won't help here anyhow.

But I'd like to express one concern:

Announcing an "agreement" for one particular case does **not** mean that the issue is resolved. And one of the root issues (abstracting from the specific case of Monica) is: The CoC established certain rules (particularly speech codes). The enforcement of the rules is *completely arbitrary*. The consequences of not following the rules are also arbitrary, and SE made an example of Monica: It shows the (abuse of the) unlimited power of the authorities. It proves that not only *violating* the rules, but also *questioning* the rules or (and that's a severe problem: ) even just **talking** about the rules can have devastating effects. This is confirmed to some extent by further cases, like that of Robert Harvey.

The case of Monica will undoubtedly have a [chilling effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chilling_effect). Even if there was an "agreement" for one particular instance now, hardly anybody will have the guts to risk damaging the own reputation, being defamed publicly and having to silently swallow false accusations that are made by SE. Hardly anybody can afford hiring a lawyer for that, and when there are dozens of GoFundMe-campaigns of people who try to stop SE harming them, none of them would achieve ~$25000 or even come close to an amount that could cover the possible expenses.

The bottom line is: There may have been *one* agreement, but this does not mean that any of the problems that are summarized in [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper) has been solved. Subjectively and personally, I won't even consider contributing anything to the main sites only because some people agreed on (probably not much more than) no longer talking about one specific instance of a much broader problem.

Comment: @cegfault see entry 7 of the resigned mods in the post linked in tbis answer (Firing mods, etc.)

Comment: Monica made the hugely innocent mistake of using her own real name as her 'username'. So it's much easier to find details about this situation by simple searching (googling) her name. If there were a public article out there saying 'user 'Tensibai' or 'user Marco13' was accused of ..., then it would have a less damaging effect on the real person.

Comment: @Steerpike That's true to some extent. Remaining *really* anonymous is not that hard, but *only* if you are careful *all* the time. And it's distressing that this seems to be *necessary* now. For example, I was somehow "proud" of my contributions here, and linked from my website to my SO profile and vice versa. In view of the recent events, I removed these links. But there are still dozens of answers/comments out there where I link to one of my GitHub repos. It feels uncomfortable... like just being a few hateful tweets away from having one's reputation ruined.

Comment: The moderator who felt the (frustratingly ironic) necessity to remove the comments about the issue of Robert Harvey should also have removed the first one by @Tensibai (this is like playing "hide and seek" with a 3 year old, who tries to "hide" by covering his eyes with his hands: "If I cannot see you, then you cannot see me"). History has shown that when things derail *really* badly, then it's usually not the fault of *one* individual, but the fault of *many* individuals.

Answer (score 42):

It's good that Monica finally has some closure.  To me, though, this post is, in a sense, worse than nothing.  SO Inc. (SOI) would have been better off simply stating that an agreement was reached, and leave it at that.  Everything else in this post is problematic.

Monica was hurt in many ways:

- Maligned publicly in the media.  A statement on Meta SE does nothing to repair that.
- Stripped of all her mod diamonds.  These were not restored, and subjecting her to a reinstatement process after all details have already been clarified and worked out in negotiations is a sham, and unfair burden.
- Put through a hellish process and treatment.  SOI made a business decision to settle, but clearly still presents that the underlying fault was Monica's.

So after enduring a long process and being worn down by the company, Monica accepted some terms to gain closure.  But this post would have been very different if the settlement was anything along the lines that the community would consider appropriate, righteous, and fair.

The current announcement still does not clarify what behavior was deemed as proper motivation for SOI's actions.  That affects all users.  In the first non-apology apology, SOI went so far as to acknowledge that the timing of its actions was inopportune.  In this non-apology non-apology, SOI acknowledges that some version of the CoC might have been a little ambiguous, so Monica might have been confused (but still the onus was on her and she did something wrong, which has never been explained).  In fact, the post acknowledges that SOI didn't satisfactorily respond to requests for clarification.

This post does express some regret, albeit with qualifications, that stuff happened, as stuff is wont to do.  It describes how much the company respects Monica, thinks she's a good person, has so much to contribute, etc., etc.  But apparently not so much that SOI sees fit to simply reverse its actions.  So really, how sincere can these compliments be?  Well, it's the kind of language the lawyers came up with that both sides can live with.

Where does that leave the rest of the community?  Chaos has reigned because of a host of actions and policies by SOI.  These were epitomized by Monica's treatment, but that was the tip of the iceberg.  Had SOI done right by Monica, it could have restored a lot of faith in the company.

Instead, this post crystallizes the concerns and opinions the community has had.  Anyone can make a mistake.  When it happens, own it and make it right. 
Here, company management just kept digging a deeper hole, ostensibly because stockholders and lawyers and the easy solution.  The deeper the hole, the more people must be thrown under the bus to fill it, rather than admitting and fixing your own mistakes.  That's not business decisions in the real world, it's just very ethically challenged.

This announcement does provide a kind of closure for all of us.  It makes clear how the company will operate.  We can come to terms that the platform is what it is and live with it, or there's the door.

Our decisions and actions won't affect SOI's policies or behavior.  It's their platform and they don't care.  We can piss and moan on Meta SE, but it appears that SOI is simply ignoring it.  At home, I DVR TV shows so I can fast-forward through the commercials and not have to see them.  SOI is doing the equivalent.  Who knows how much our protests may have affected Monica's outcome (it doesn't appear that we gained her more than lawyers, alone, could have done).  SOI has also doubled down on its policies and priorities.  At this point, it seems like we're accomplishing little more than marinating in our own toxic thought bubble.

Now I have a decision to make.

Comment: SO really don't have any solid assets other than a strong user-base at this point.  As a private company with venture funding, they are almost definitely hoping to go public, and for that to work, they need to demonstrate they can monetize their service. There's only two things they can monetize; job seeking, and targeted advertising. And for these two items, they need to demonstrate continued growth in users. They've added non-techie sites to grow users, which I think are a bad 'fit' for the technology, and they are struggling to attract new users (new COC was an attempt to fix this (1/2) ...

Comment: (cont...) So just as SO was an attempt to improve on expertsexchange, the time is ripe for a new site/service to replace SO.  There's really nothing proprietary about how they run the site, and one could argue it's in much need of an overhaul anyway.  Starting from scratch could be a great opportunity for someone.  All these dissatisfied users / moderators could find a new home and put their hearts and souls into it, and let SO suffer the fate it deserves (2/2).

Comment: @Steerpike, you might be interested in the link [in this user's "About me"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/251162/marc-2377).

Answer (score 37):

I think it's enough of discussion here. Monica has moved on, and so shall we. As per her [latest blog post](https://cellio.dreamwidth.org/2070224.html) - she has been recruited in a Community driven Q&A site.

Time for leaving Stack Exchange and join that new Q&A site - actions of SE shall decide.

Comment: Translation, SE it rekt so she took da $$ n ran.  Good for her.

Comment: Those "replace SE" projects are a dime a dozen. Codidact is too focused on debating about process. They've been at it since this mess started and still don't have anything live. I'm less familiar with TopAnswers, but they seem in desperate need of someone that's designed a website in this millennium.
There are a bazillion sites like SE out there... None of them get the traffic they need to come close to "replacing" SE.

Answer (score 35):

Ah, nothing like legalese BS.  and  **NOT GOOD ENOUGH**

**TLDR:**

1. NO admission of guilt on the part of SE
2. No admission of wrong doing on the part of SE
3. The implication that Monica is an idiot with this statement "she did not understand all of the nuances and full intent and meaning of our Code of Conduct"
4. You are lying when you said you respect her, if you did, you would have just reinstated her, rather than make her go through a process.  If she did nothing wrong, then there should be no process for her to go through.  But I assume your lawyers told you that you had to hold your ground on that one.
5. "We regret we used her name".  Nice, you don't regret what you said about her, only that you used her name.

In short, this is a transparent attempt to smooth things over without admitting just how effed up you are.

**FULL ANALYSIS**

> Stack Overflow and Monica Cellio have come to an agreement.

Translation: You were in the wrong, and still won't admit it.

> We believe that Ms. Cellio was not acting with malicious intent.

No, your lawyer told you to post this.  The timing of her firing (right before a high Jewish holiday) in addition to some of the comments I've seen made leads me to believe that there was a degree of antisemitism involved.

> We believe she did not understand all of the nuances and full intent and meaning of our Code of Conduct and was confused about what actions it required and forbade.

**Bascially, you are saying she's an idiot.  I don't believe this sentence at all.  If you thought she didn't understand something, you should have explained it, not fired her.**

> We acknowledge our responses to her requests for clarification were not satisfactory.

**By not satisfactory, you mean malicious, nasty, stone-walling, and libelous.**

> The verbiage in our Code of Conduct could have been more explicitly detailed about what was expected.

**It wasn't the verbiage, it was the malicious, draconian, selective enforcement, based on actions you claimed Monica MIGHT take.  Not only did you convict her without any sort of process, but without any sort of offense**

> We always valued Ms. Cellio’s contributions to the community and respect her intelligence, integrity, and professional writing skills.

**Complete and utter BS!  Your actions speak volumes, and you took no action at all until AFTER this went legal.  If you valued her, you never would have fired her at all, you would have responded to her inquiries, and you would have reinstated her once you realized your mistake.   All this is, is a collection of empty words, meaning nothing, drafted by a lawyer and about as sincere as a politician 3 days before an election**

> While our initial statement did not address her specifically, we regret that we used her name when responding to a reporter's follow-up. We regret any damage to Ms. Cellio's reputation and any other damage she may have suffered.

**What you regret is that Monica fought back, and that so many of us supported her.

you libeled her in a news piece.  You don't regret anything other than the legal entanglements your own bad actions caused you**

> We have since updated some of our policies and processes to help ensure we are more careful in our public communications, and that there is a clearer process anytime a moderator's status is revoked as well as a process for reinstatement.

**Too little, too late**

> We respect Ms. Cellio and believe she is a good person with much to offer and contribute. We sincerely hope she remains an active member of our community. In recognition of the mistakes that led us here, we invited Ms. Cellio to apply for possible reinstatement on all six sites following our new reinstatement process. Ms. Cellio expressed concerns about the new process and has not applied.

**If you TRULY respected Monica, there would be no process for her to go through to correct YOUR ERROR.  You see, this is where any semblance of sincerity on your part crumbles to so much dust.  You say that Monica did not act with malicious intent, and that at worst she didn't understand the policy.**

**Now, either you are saying that she's the dumbest person on SE, and that everyone else understood it, or you are just lying even more.  I have bumped heads with Monica in the past, but she is far from dumb.  If the policy was unclear to HER, that should have been a red flag to you that the policy should have been reviewed.**

You screwed up, and now you want Monica to crawl back and go through a process to fix the mistake YOU made.

Comment: You can't re-litigate this matter.  You may not like the outcome of the settlement, but that doesn't give you a position to re-litigate what the settled terms are.  Remember:  Stack Exchange sets the rules on how moderators are brought back into the system.  If someone doesn't want to participate in that workflow, then that person has no leg to stand on when it comes to reinstatement of any kind.

Comment: @Makoto You miss the point. Monica didn’t get the benefit of any process (the one that existed at the time she was removed or the new one). It was wrong to demod her and it should be corrected without any hoop jumping on her part. Unless someone doesn’t think it was wrong to fire her. There’s no “re-litigating” when there was no due process in the first place.

Comment: _"Stack Exchange sets the rules"_ Rules are not ends in themselves. Rules are guidelines to help people understand and choose the right action for a situation. (Especially when the wrong action may be quicker, easier, or more seductive.) When there is this wide of a gap between the rules and what's right, the rules are worse than useless, and calling that fact out _becomes_ the right action.

Comment: @ColleenVpartedways:  I don't disagree that it was abrupt and sudden to demod her *either*, but you miss *my* point.  In the official language posted by Stack Exchange and later echoed by Monica on her campaign page, the statement included language about an opportunity to re-apply.  **This implies that the settlement was firm about how she could return to being a moderator.**  The due process *was* the mediation, and everything I've read to this point makes me think that it didn't go the way a lot of people wanted and they want to push for it again.

Comment: @jscs:  You misunderstand.  Stack Exchange has set-in-stone *rules* for moderators and moderation.  There's no room for interpretation since the ultimate remedy to the violation would be removal - from modship, sites, or both.  This is *their* field, and anyone who wishes to participate is subject to *their* rules.  No ifs, ands or buts about it.

Comment: @Makoto People have the right to advocate for any outcome they would like, even if they’re just tilting at windmills, so long as they do it without disrupting the site or breaking the Code of Conduct. I understand that SE is not going to reinstate Monica. I did not reach an agreement with SE, so I am under no obligation to not speak about it or to let it drop. It’s not going to be resolved for me until it’s clear that SE understands that treating people the way they treated Monica is unethical, not just a series of regrettable mistakes.

Comment: I think you missed that Monica also was part of this "settlement" process. She had a say in what statement should be announced for public. If we interpret this the way you did, we basically believe that Monica wasn't competent and was manipulated by SE lawyers during the settlement. I'd rather not think that way.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not retrying anything, I am voicing my opinion, and dissatisfaction with the wording, and I believe I was quite clear about it.

Comment: @M-- Anyone who has ever been party to an arbitration knows that you aren’t going to get everything what you want and the deck is stacked in the company’s favor. Monica decided what was good enough for her to be able to move on, and I’m happy she got there so quickly. That doesn’t mean this is good enough for everyone that has a stake in SE’s relationship with its community and moderators.

Comment: @M-- I missed nothing and I did not interpret this in the manner you are implying.  As to whether or not she had a say in this statement, You do not know this unless you have been in communication with her.  The statement is garbage legalese and transparent as glass

Comment: @ColleenVpartedways Exactly.  I walked away from 15k in a legal manner one time, simply because it would have cost me more to fight for it.

Comment: @Richard first of all, I am not defending SE. I'm pissed off about their conduct not just about this matter but in many other ways. And I'm with you on BS legalese part. But I don't agree with every part of your interpretation. If I implied something that would be offensive, I am willing to extend an apology.

Comment: @M--  fair enough.  Maybe I'm just too irked about it myself.

Answer (score 35):

I can't stress this enough anymore:

**It's time to leave the Stack Exchange network.**

Without rehashing everything said in the top upvoted answer, it's clear SE wants to just bury this whole thing, and move on. Over the course of the last week, I've only grown more angry at this resolution: Leaving Monica without her diamond, and offering likely nothing but hush money, with a heartless legalize statement.

This isn't the Stack Exchange network I signed up for, and it's not the Stack Exchange network I intend to stay in. Me, employees of SE, and many others have done the same. It's time to send a message: Going down this path is going to lose the most loyal and trusted members of this network.

Comment: The problem with that is ... probably *these* members aren't the ones that *really* get the money flowing towards SE Inc. ... if the 100 top contributors on stackoverflow decided to go silent for a month ... I bet: Monica would have been reinstated after 5 days.

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. Then the only thing to do, is to spread the word, and prevent this type of injustice from occurring again

Comment: Many of the top 100 went silent.  SE thought that new blood was able to compensate enough. I feel the difference.

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. Monica should've been reinstated *immediately*. And Staff can do that to her!

Answer (score 33):

Sounded good enough - not really contrite but standard 'I'm sorry you were offended' style / could perhaps have done better / Monica is not REALLY the creature from the pit of hell / ... .

Bearable enough, probably.
Seemed to be leading up to a "So we have offered to reinstate 'Ms Cellio' [whoever] with a mutual understanding of the rules of engagement that now apply."

But, then, instead ...

> " ... we invited Ms. Cellio to apply for possible reinstatement on all six sites following our new reinstatement process. ..."

Why bother posting this?
What has **really** changed from the stuff we've been hearing 'for some while'?
Does anyone, of any persuasion, really think that that is an 'answer' to the 'problem'?
As opposed to "Well, we made the offer. So, we're OK .... It's in her camp."

Really?

Try this question: "If YOU were treated like this in circumstances that were essentially equivalent for YOU, how would you feel / react ?"

Really?

Comment: Added  2nd & 3rd question marks above as per @Peter M's edit. Rolled back balance of edit. If I'd wanted it in purest Queen's English I'd have written it therein from the get go. I'm happy with what I wrote. I consider the edits unhelpful, at best. || Adding  " ... we have italics and bold on this platform ... " as a comment to **ANY** edit is liable to mar the reception, *even* if it was, unlike in this instance, an apposite one.

Answer (score 33):

This seems so superficial. This is not even an apology for releasing her name to the reporter and maligning her name; attacking her personally.

It should be noted that this response has only come after legal actions are bring pursued. This is a half-hearted attempt at best and certainly not an apology!

Comment: Maybe there is another article by *The Register* to come? Who knows?...

Answer (score 33):

When I think I am wrong I say: *Sorry, I was wrong. Please, come back, if you want*.
When I think I am on the right side I say: *You misbehaved*, and possibly *You can come back, only if you apologise*.

In this regard, your statement  does not make crystal clear on what side is the wrongdoing (much like a politician's speech). 
The lack of a bold statement works against you, harming your reputation more than it is supposed to help.

**More Generally**
When you have the responsibility of affecting other people's fortunes and misfortunes with a click, it is unavoidable to occasionally click through in the wrong direction. In those circumstances, the best action is always to recognise the error, if there was one.

Answer (score 31):

This answer is filled with "lawyer speak", but if the sentence:

> We regret any damage to Ms. Cellio's reputation and any other damage she may have suffered.

is really true, then why does she have to *apply* to become a moderator again? You **regret** any other damage that she suffered (for example losing her job as moderator), so if you regret it so much, why not re-instate her and allow *her* to step down if she doesn't want to be a moderator anymore?

Answer (score 30):

You've got another window of opportunity. There's always another chance.

Reinstate Monica. Think about it: The above sanitized statement makes it abundantly clear that you've said what you've legally obligated yourself to say.

That means that if you reinstate her, it will be apparent that you are not doing so out of legal obligation, but rather out of a desire to do something decent, just because it's the right thing to do.

Give in to doing what's right. Trust me, it will feel good.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1450/discussion-on-answer-by-scott-hannen-update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio).

Answer (score 29):

I would like to point out that, out of all days possible to release this statement, it was decided to post it **again the day before a major holiday?** I believe Stack Overflow commented multiple times how one of the failures on the firing of Monica was the fact it was done the day before an important day? This seriously makes me doubt whether SO learned anything from the major outcry last time, or even worse, the promises made that communication like that would not happen anymore.

Other than that, this statement is so filled with void that I personally don't even feel anything positive or negative around it.

Comment: Note that the major issue with the specific holiday that this whole thing when down on was that it was a holiday in which Monica was going to be completely offline. Also note that this was not an issue here. I don't really see anything wrong with announcing something 2 days before a holiday where all the participants are available and willing. Given the worldwide nature of this site, it's kind of hard not to do something on a holiday for someone, somewhere.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Standing alone no, but when management promises not to convey major news / updates like this in perspective to major celebrations, they're clearly just breaking another promise. Which is the point of this answer.

Comment: Real question: did they ever actually promise not to announce something on/before any holiday? I don't remember them doing that.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I was expecting that question, but it seems as if previous apologies have been deleted, my urls return a "page not found". However, there's a remark here where it at least is being acknowledged. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps/334646#334646

Comment: In addition for context: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334370/avoid-shipping-news-on-a-friday-evening

Comment: _"We learned (or were painfully reminded, rather) to never ship at 6 PM (EDT) on a Friday. We didn’t follow that rule last week and as a result there was a lot of confusion over the weekend. Even more, this weekend was a religious holiday observed by many on the site. We’re sorry for the confusion and uneasiness that caused."_

Via: https://web.archive.org/web/20191223022626/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology

Comment: Right, and this seems like a comment different scenario to me. This very much doesn't seem to be a case of repeating that mistake. I'd rather people focus on the very real mistakes SE has made rather than non issues.

Comment: Your mileage may vary.

Comment: "Given the worldwide nature of this site, it's kind of hard not to do something on a holiday for someone, somewhere." There is no doubt that December 24-25 is a "major" holiday in BY FAR more of the world than any other "major holiday" anywhere. Furthermore, perhaps doing this announcement on December 23 would reduce the number of angry people that would see it. By the time they return from the holidays (for some people, all the way in January) they see it as older news and don't get as outraged. Alternatively, maybe they just wanted to get it done before the holiday and not wait till 2020.

Comment: @user1271772 If they wanted to try to minimize the number of people that see this they probably wouldn't have featured the post. It's possible that the timing was a way to reduce drama, but it seems more likely to me (as you also mention) that the timing was a result of when the agreement was actually done. It would make sense for both parties to want to resolve it before going on break for holidays. But yeah, I agree this timing certainly was one of the most prominent holidays worldwide.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose. I didn't notice that it was a "feature post". Yes they might have done this simply to get it done before the holidays, meaning that it was a coincidence that last time it was the day before Monica's holiday. It seems that they might be regretting it now because their Christmas might have been ruined by all this backlash (700+ downvotes, and several pages of angry comments).

Comment: @user1271772 Yeah, at the very least, if reducing the backlash was their goal, it didn't seem to work very well.

Comment: I don't get why people focus on announcements before holidays so much... During holidays is when you have more free time to slack around on SE. When you're at work, you should work rather than read and post on meta. No?

Answer (score 25):

### If Monica is happy, I'm happy

I think the two key points here are:

SO:

> Stack Overflow and Monica Cellio have come to an agreement.

and Monica:

> I can't comment further for legal reasons.

So, obviously Monica has settled. Since the statement contains virtually nothing of benefit to Monica in itself (not even an automatic reinstatement of the moderator flag), and since Monica is smart and has legal representation, I think it's safe to assume there is a financial settlement here.

If she's happy with the lukewarm apology and outcome offered above, then so should we be. It's still a shitty path that they have taken, and I'm sure there will be more of them, but as far as this particular battle goes, I think it's done.

Comment: The situation might have been settled. It did not benefit her in any way whatsoever.

Comment: I would find it extraordinary if there were no compensation. I don't see what she would have to gain in that case in agreeing to this statement, and agreeing not to comment further "for legal reasons". Unless perhaps there is still some pending legal action, but in *that* case it seems odd that SO would comment at all.

Comment: @MulliganReinstatingMonica Why would Monica sign an agreement and NDA if it didn't benefit her in some shape of form? She was the one suing.

Comment: @MulliganReinstatingMonica even if they did, Monica might not want it back.

Comment: I'm not happy with a lukewarm non-apology. This does nothing to reassure community members that the same will not happen to them the next time an SE staffer goes on an irrational vendetta against a user.

Comment: @ByBw - technically, did Monica actually sue? My understanding is, she was raising funds in preparation for a possible future legal action. Lawyers are not cheap. Just having a few preliminary meetings and then having the lawyers wade through all this 'noise' here on Meta and other sources (in order to decide whether she has a good case or not) would take a lot of hours. Her $30k GoFundMe account would not support a lengthy legal battle. So I would expect she was going through these preliminary stages. Similarly, SO could have made moves to counter-sue, to let her know what was coming.

Comment: Nothing about this suggests that she is happy, just that she agreed. I note that, if I got what I wanted in such a situation, I would be able to at least tell people that I was happy with the agreement, if not the specifics of what it actually is.

Comment: Your naivete is interesting. Settlements out of court in the USA (particularly, and most of the world really) almost always include nondisclosure terms. Forcing an allowance of discussion about the agreement would be advised against by your lawyer and fought against by theirs. If you actually hoped to settle, you wouldn't be left able to talk about it. @trlkly

Comment: I doubt monica is happy, but in the face of tens, or hundreds of thousands in legal bills while taking on a corporation, you are going to take what you can get.

Answer (score 25):

I don't see anyone mentioning the fact that the second round of clarifications showed that what Monica was asking if she could do was perfectly within the code of conduct. Her question was actually one important to the community at large.

This whole issue isn't just about Monica. It's about whether the desire to help trans people was ever legitimate in the first place. I at least still largely suspect that the whole thing was a PR stunt, and you needed some mod to be the fall guy so you could make a public announcement that you were fixing the problem. Anyone with any knowledge would know that revoking her privileges would cause a controversy, giving you a chance to get your changes into the news.

Everything you do is so clearly tailored to PR (like when you released this, at the lowest time of the year) that we have very little reason to assume any of this is legitimate. And you very clearly did not involve the SE trans community in making the new rules, as many were upset by Monica's removal.

You continue to act in ways that normal human beings do not act when actually sorry. You want to "save face," meaning you still only care about yourselves. Why should any of us think you actually have a social conscience if you're that selfish?

Answer (score 25):

> We believe she did not understand all of the nuances and full intent and meaning of our Code of Conduct and was confused

Usually settlements of lawsuits have some language that says each party promises not to speak disparagingly of the other. The statement above disparages Monica Cellio by suggesting that the mistake was hers: she did not understand, and she was confused. There is considerable evidence that the officers of the company have little ability to understand anything except software code, and that *they* were the ones who did not understand and were confused.

Maybe this public disparagement of her should be brought to the attention of the court.

Comment: Every indication that we can see indicates that Monica agreed to this statement as part of the settlement. If not, she certainly has the ability to indicate to "the court" whoever that might be in this case that this breaks their agreement. I'm not sure what you think that posting that here will do though. She's already more than aware of this statement and she's much more aware of the terms than you.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose : well, At least you admit you're not sure.....

Answer (score 23):

Thanks for posting this notice of an agreement. Here is my little feedback, for what it's worth:

> We believe that Ms. Cellio was not acting with malicious intent.

Unfortunately, you did not make that as clear as possible right from the beginning. The harm to her name has already been done and it will be lasting, no matter what, especially because this message doesn't sound very convincing (and there is no other statement).

> We always valued Ms. Cellio’s contributions to the community and respect her intelligence, integrity, and professional writing skills.

Then why did you harm her in the first place? If you really valued her contributions, there might have been other ways to resolve the conflict.

> ... we regret that we used her name when responding to a reporter's follow-up. We regret any damage to Ms. Cellio's reputation and any other damage she may have suffered.

This is the most important point for me and I would hope it could be printed in bold letters. This is indeed an apology, even though it's not placed very prominently in the text.

> We have since updated some of our policies and processes to help ensure we are more careful in our public communications ...

That's also important and good to hear.

> We sincerely hope she remains an active member of our community.

I sincerely don't believe a single word of this sentence. If that were true, I would have expected a much more sincere apology, one that never materialized. And that's indeed the main criticism of this contribution. I wish it would have been more sincere, open and ... in search of a better word, true.

Answer (score 22):

My ideas:

> Stack Overflow and Monica Cellio have come to an agreement. We believe that Ms. Cellio was not acting with malicious intent. We believe she did not understand all of the nuances and full intent and meaning of our Code of Conduct and was confused about what actions it required and forbade.

IMHO, she always understands the CoC. Also it doesn't seem (at least for me) that she will be harming.

> We acknowledge our responses to her requests for clarification were not satisfactory. The verbiage in our Code of Conduct could have been more explicitly detailed about what was expected. We always valued Ms. Cellio’s contributions to the community and respect her intelligence, integrity, and professional writing skills.

Again, if Monica was always valued on her skills, I don't think such a rude firing was needed.

> While our initial statement did not address her specifically, we regret that we used her name when responding to a reporter's follow-up. We regret any damage to Ms. Cellio's reputation and any other damage she may have suffered.

Okay.

> We have since updated some of our policies and processes to help ensure we are more careful in our public communications, and that there is a clearer process anytime a moderator's status is revoked as well as a process for reinstatement.

Why? How didn't Monica obey the previous CoC already?

> We respect Ms. Cellio and believe she is a good person with much to offer and contribute. We sincerely hope she remains an active member of our community. In recognition of the mistakes that led us here, we invited Ms. Cellio to apply for possible reinstatement on all six sites following our new reinstatement process. Ms. Cellio expressed concerns about the new process and has not applied.

A possible reinstatement? Just do it now? Why not? Also after this firing moderators crime, how would she be so happy to come back? She may not even want to come back. If she wasn't fired it would be peace.

---

Why even post this question? Just reinstate her. Nothing to talk about, or have the question title as "Monica is successfully reinstated!" and have Monica with her original position.

Answer (score 21):

> In recognition of the mistakes that led us here, we invited Ms. Cellio to apply for possible reinstatement on all six sites following our new reinstatement process. Ms. Cellio expressed concerns about the new process and has not applied.

Everything in the post is good for the community because you (Stack Overflow) are willing to solve this problem. But the last paragraph is a bit giveaway. The title and the remaining question sounds like you have realised what mistake was done. To correct that mistake, you are ready to reinstate Monica as a moderator.

But the last paragraph seems like that intention was clear.

> In recognition of **the mistakes** that led us here,

When you have written an apology post for the mistake happened from the company side, I think there's no issue in making clear whose mistakes led us here. Whose mistakes are you referring to?

As I understand, you have invited Monica to apply for reinstatement following current [moderator reinstate process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336176/357396).

If your intention is to reinstate her believing she is a good person and having no malicious intent, the process of long formal reinstatement wouldn't have been required now. We don't know for sure what was she exactly offered so we (users) can only speculate.

You invite her for reinstatement (which involves a long process) following rules but she was not removed through formal moderator removal process.

Comment: It's part and parcel of reaching an *agreement*. Offering Monica the official reinstatement process was part of the terms agreed. It's also  called "saving face". SE can state that Monica was *twice*  given the opportunity to return as a mod but each time she refused the process. Consequently,  the company doesn't look so much like the bad party.

Comment: She probably lost trust with SE altogether. She wants to get the diamond as if nothing has happened in the first place. She doesn't want another potentially convoluted reinstatement process.

Comment: @MariLouA No, they very much do look like the bad party. Attempting to save face is something that makes you look like you aren't actually sorry. It doesn't actually save face unless such attempts are not obvious.

Comment: “They willing to solve this problem”, but not to admit that they did  wrong things.

Answer (score 21):

First, thank you for posting an update on this. I think that dialog can go a long way here.

With that said, I'm confused about the last paragraph. It's never been made clear exactly what part of the Code of Conduct Monica was supposed to have violated (especially with the more recent version, which apparently allows what she was asking to be allowed to do). That being said, why is it only "possible" reinstatement? Why is there a question as to whether she'd be reinstated or not? Why does she even need to apply in the first place? Why not just reinstate her forthwith?

Comment: The dismissal was never the largest problem. Speaking as someone who was there, it makes perfect sense to me that Monica would have to go through the reinstatement process, because the dismissal was not a black-and-white situation. The lawsuit and the big issue was about the defamation. There is still other context (still in private, not leaked AFAIK) relevant to the dismissal, and expecting SE to just reinstate Monica without question is not a reasonable thing to expect and *shouldn't* be expected.

Comment: @Mithical - no one can argue against other factors that remain private. But since the lack of reinstatement is itself an implied defamation, I'm surprised they didn't take that route. Requiring her to go through the process is implied guilt. So by accepting, Monica is acknowledging guilt, which means, this isn't really clearing her name.   Curious - do we know what Monica does as a 'day job'? If she's secure in her current job, not a huge concern about economic damage caused by this event.

Comment: You answer is similar to others, created earlier. Also your hope for a dialog does sound naive.

Comment: @MiFreidgeimSO-stopbeingevil Admittedly, SE has a rather poor record of constructive dialog (especially given their lack of responsiveness to feedback and questions from the community about Monica's firing in the first place). With that said, at least this update is *something* (even if it's not everything we want). I think that it's important that we encourage them to at least give us information (rather than just complain bitterly whether they do or don't).

Comment: @Mithical I'm not a moderator and obviously wasn't there, but it was never clear (even to Monica) exactly what she was fired *for* (and SE persistently refused to give any more details beyond "trust us, we're doing the right thing," even when Monica and the community asked for it). Based on my knowledge of Monica, I *seriously* doubt that there was any malicious intent on her part. Plus, the new Code of Conduct [evidently permits what she was asking to be allowed to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337626/343810), so it's even less clear what part of the new CoC she violated.

Comment: @Mithical: I completely reject the "trust me --- I was there argument", and frankly I'm tired of it. Unfortunately, people tend to agree with trashing a person rights if that person is merely suspected of holding the *wrong* opinions. If you can't or won't explain what happened in that room then I give you no credit for being there.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk - I will not, both because everything happened in private and so I won't air it in public and because I no longer have access to the transcripts and records. It's certainly not a black-and-white situation, and I don't blame someone if they don't want to take my word for it, because I'm *not* giving out information. I will say that most people are operating without context, though, and that everything was mishandled from the start by everybody.

Comment: @Mithical: I understand and respect your decision not to reveal more detail. So where does that leave the rest of us? We do have *some* context, from both Monica and a staff member who goes by the username Sara Chipps. I'm drawing my inferences from that context, and I acknowledge that "inference" is just a fancy name for "guess".

Answer (score 20):

I'm writing this answer because I've just seen the latest episode of the tv show "The Show" which tells a story of several characters in the wake of the #meetoo movement, and so far none of the previous answers tackle an important topic for the future. Essentially, one of the show's main points was «if only people hadn't stayed quiet about these affairs, if only people had spoken up».

Well, with an NDA, a similar wrong signal is being sent. This seem to be symptomatic of larger behavioural issue that is beginning to show up. In my opinion, hushing this up, is self-defeating, specially for the purpose that Stack Exchange is implementing their new CoC. This way is not the way to go.

I don't know Monica's exact status at the moment, and I'm not trying to criticise specifically her action. What I'm saying is that if everyone will stay quiet, nothing will get solved, and more problems will just show up later on.

Maybe in 10/20 years, we'll see cases on TV of people who were tossed aside, and unduly mistreated for the seemingly purpose of ensuring wide respect for person's essential characteristics.

And, if Stack Exchange still exists at this time, we, from the community, will remember how and when that behaviour started creeping into society, and how it helped fuel exact extreme counter-movements similar to the ones we currently see in societies at large on the political scene.

If you want to protect the rights of the LGBTQ+ community, it must be done in unison, or at least in collaboration with significant part of the whole community in Stack Exchange. Otherwise, this will only fracture the whole community, and create more frictions. Take a too big of a step, one most people are not ready to take yet, and it will just create discord. And this is a critic to SE actions so far...

Answer (score 16):

First off, I am glad SE and Monica have come to an agreement.

But I am very disappointed by the (legalese) wording and the timing (close to holidays). As a company you are doing something very good in this world. The way this firing and this agreement with Monica is handled has been bad. You could, no should, have handled this better. And you have no excuse with the feedback you have gotten from this community.

We are human. We make mistakes. In how we fix those mistakes we show a lot of who we are. There might be very good reasons for why it has run this course, but I sure was hoping for more than this. Something good, something what heals, something that rights wrongs, something more human.

Comment: no one from se is reading anything here, it's all going into the void

Comment: I don't expect the void to react. But I got my disappointment out. There are others sites that will do this better. See you there.

Answer (score 15):

I’m going to post this as a separate answer from my previous one for voting purposes: why not just have an election or something (rather than having her go through the reinstatement process)? Since she’s a community moderator, why not let the community decide?

I’m not sure exactly how that would work with the legal agreements, but just a thought.

Comment: She's already been elected as moderator, over and over

Comment: @GeorgeMReinstateMonica Odds are she would be again, too. From my perspective, though, this would be the most fair way to settle the issue.

Comment: It's not like her communities unceremoniously booted her out

Comment: This suggestion does nothing about the lack of trust, and does nothing to address that she was de-modded without a process to begin with.  The best case for her as far as being a moderator would have been for her to be completely reinstated, then for her to resign immediately and never look back.

Comment: @GeorgeMReinstateMonica That's true - but a reinstatement process would likely erode trust even further if Monica wasn't reinstated (plus, Monica evidently already indicated that she's unwilling to go through that process), plus allowing her to stand for election again would allow SE a face-saving way to extract themselves from the whole situation. (If they just reinstated her without following the process it would be widely perceived as an admission of guilt on their part; as much as I'd *like* an unqualified admission of guilt from them, it doesn't seem too likely at this point).

Comment: @rgettman Why resign immediately?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica So she could leave on her own terms.

Answer (score 12):

I don't see much variety in the responses to this post. First, there's a presumption that there's a problem with drafting things carefully, as lawyers do. Second, there's a presumption that the company hosting this service needs to apologize for something. If you just read the post without making these assumptions, the meaning is quite clear.

It is about two people (one of whom is a natural person). One had a theory under which the other acted with "malicious intent" (i.e., acted in a calculated way to bring about concrete harm). The other had a theory that the other it suffered a damage in reputation due to the other's carelessness. These theories, when articulated, are threats. So the two have made an "agreement" (i.e., an enforceable promise) to stop threatening each other and mutually discontinue the challenged behavior.

Also no one has paid much attention to the fact that announcement of this agreement was made public. I don't think it's required under SEC regulations, etc. Announcement of the notice must then have been consideration in the agreement. This network being the main forum for the alleged intentional harm that one person must have been complaining of, it would have been essential for the onlookers lately rooting for a fight to know that the show is over.

Comment: Your presumption that there are presumptions in play here is presumptuous ;) *there's a presumption that the company hosting this service needs to apologize for something* No. There is no presumption, instead there are strongly articulated reasons why the company should apologize for specific actions. *It is about two people.* Yes and no, but mostly no. There is a third person involved, and its ... **you**. By that I mean the community. We care about about each other as well as the site and we won't be silent. If this is what you mean by the "show" then, as you can see. it's not over.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk Users have real, personal commitment and emotional attachment to a community that exists on a private corporation's servers. As far as the running of a business goes, however, the "community experience" is what is offered to get users to spend time on the site and generate marketable data. This incident should reassure SE that a little bit of controversy doesn't hurt traffic at all.

Comment: The notion that private corporate interests / profit making comes first and that everything else is subordinate is only one perspective. Some may argue that the community exists because of Stack Overflow Inc. Others may counter that Stack Overflow Inc exists because of the community. A holistic view might be that there is symbiotic relationship and that each exists because of the other. When one party attempts to turn a symbiotic relationship into a parasitic relationship, [both parties may suffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scorpion_and_the_Frog).

Answer (score 12):

I doubt this was posted with any intention of gathering or addressing feedback from meta. Meta isn't really the place for that sort of thing anymore -if it ever was at all. I suspect that <strike>Sara's</strike> legal's post is here on meta, rather than the blog or *nowhere*, specifically to satisfy some provision of the agreement.

Answer (score 11):

Referencing [@thebjorn comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336175/what-is-the-process-for-reinstating-a-moderator/336176#comment1121164_336176) on **[What is the process for reinstating a moderator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336175/what-is-the-process-for-reinstating-a-moderator)**:

[image]

Sharing the rules with community and following a due process is necessary but not enough. It is perceived that listening and taking actions accordingly is not fully attended by SE lately. I love what we have here and I want to believe that we can work together to put this behind us, while learning from it and improve. We have an open forum, so we can all talk, but we cannot be sure of SE listening unless they respond. And then we cannot take it as granted that SE is taking our feedback into consideration unless we hear their arguments; there will always be disagreements though.

Nobody expects SE to be bullied into changing decisions, but getting involved in conversations, stating reasons and counterarguments is vital. So responding to community's feedback should follow certain standards.

Now that we have an *"Updated agreement with Monica Cellio"*, which is the igniter of all this, and considering that *"Ms. Cellio expressed concerns about the new process"*, it doesn't seem like a bad idea for community to review the new reinstatement process and provide feedback. Shall be updates based on the feedback.

Comment: Actually - it was [discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336177/feedback-post-moderator-review-and-reinstatement-processes/336236#336236) way back with that specific post for feedback. [and you can find Monica's concerns here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336177/feedback-post-moderator-review-and-reinstatement-processes/336236#336236). Its worth considering though that the reaction to the actual posts isn't as negative as the feedback post. But these things *have* been discussed. Pretty much,there's no easy way to get trust back, and that's a core issue

Comment: @Journeyman Thank you. I am aware of that post. TBH, I think Monica's case is doomed anyway. All the unnecessary actions, bad decisions, bad timing, etc. made it impossible to come out of it with everyone's being absolutely happy. This legalese is the best we get. Last paragraph of my post is just an invitation for further involvement of community in discussions with SE, in lieu of condemnation. Most of it though, is about asking SE to make better decisions and actively trying to gain back as much trust as they can for future.

Answer (score 10):

To me this post looks entirely a lawyer text written down here just to defend yourselves in front of court.

My question regarding this is about the first line:

> Stack Overflow and Monica Cellio have come to an agreement.

Did Monica Cellio agree with any of the things mentioned in this post?

Comment: As mentioned on other answers and comments, usually, when both sides settle, they agree on many things, being (amongst other) 1. no further comment about the case 2. a notice (please note that Ms Chipps and Ms Cellio did publish the exact same statement)

Comment: @OldPadawan just because a contract is called 'agreement' does not mean that the parties who sign it (possibly under protest) agree with any of it's contents. It is a [fallacy of ambiguity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation) to call this agreement something that Monica would agree to.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: In this case it seems obvious that both parties agree to it. There's no other entities to apply pressure to the parties. Monica's lawyers work **for** her, not the other way around. The same is true for SO lawyers. Or perhaps you're suggesting that circumstances have forced their hands?

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk yes, given how SE/SO has been handling this I would not be surprised if they had turned it into an ugly legal battle, possibly even threating to countersue or threating her to pay high legal fees in case of a potential loss, where they have pressured Monica to sign some "agreement" (but under protest, meaning she is far from happy with it). Just because it is *called* agreement does not *make* it an agreement. It is obvious that SE/SO does not see their wrong doing and does not want to admit guilt, let alone reinstate Monica or do something else to relieve the pain

Comment: Given the pattern so far, I too would not be surprised if the plaintiff was put under pressure to sign a document which stipulated that they could never mention that they were pressurised to sign it.

Answer (score 8):

So in essence, SE is saying Monica made a mistake by assuming the CoC meant what it said, instead of divining its "full intent" and they forgive her, if she subjects herself to a questionable reinstatement process, which she won't do. And they now triple down on the implication that she did do some unspecified wrong, again without specifying what *exactly* that was, despite repeated - public - requests for such a clarification by Monica.

They also <s>apologize for</s> regret doing the thing they legally weren't allowed to do.

Why Monica accepted this settlement is beyond me, since it certainly wasn't about money. My best guess is it was the result of some binding arbitration she agreed to.

Comment: Here's what I take from Monica accepting it: While some of us are okay with the endless churn, and perhaps on some perverse level find it occasionally distracting in an almost entertaining way, she's just over it and wants peace from it. I wish her well. Despite the injustice of it all, if I were her I'd spend some amount of time in the fight and then want to move on and have my life be about something else.