# How can we find the fastest growing sites within the last year?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

How can we find the fastest growing sites within the last year?

(With a minimum of say a certain amount of marked answers (averaged of course) per month?)

Are there any good sites for this?

Comment: use SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: dont see a way to filter, if you know how can u show in an answer, or a better site

Comment: How do you measure "fastest growing"?  Is it number of questions, number of edits, number of users, or something else?

Comment: what data is available? use your best judgemeent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently wrote a cross-site [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query to answer [Are there any observable effects of a "strike"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334626/295232). It can be used here as well, if you think the number of questions or the number of answers is a good measure for site growth. I wrote it to compare two weeks, but [it works for full years as well](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1121616/comparison-of-of-posts-per-period?beginOfPeriod=2018-10-13&endOfPeriod=2019-10-12&beginOfComparedPeriod=2017-10-13&endOfComparedPeriod=2018-10-12):

[image]

(After running the query, you'll need to tap the '% more questions' column header to sort on it.)

(The real question is whether Software Recommendations can be called the winner here; they see a lot more traffic <s>thanks</s> due to the introduction of the Ask Question Wizard on Stack Overflow: [Recent proliferation of "How to code?" questions & SuperUser questions](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2809/23377).)

Please note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning. Feel free to [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/1121616) the query to adapt it to your own needs (e.g. set a filter for the minimum number of questions). If you want to learn more about SQL or SEDE itself, take the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).

Comment: fastest growing is ofc 5-30% total users / 70-95% total answers. based on someone's question that would be a good start, and if that user or others didnt know that, i'd say they likely shouldnt even try to answer.  this is informative & answers the question sufficiently, thanks good answer