# Get overall activity difference between two years

Tags: support, data-explorer, database

Recently the 'Moderation results' were published across all Stack Exchange sites.

On my main site, Drupal Answers, I noticed a drastic fall in moderation actions, flagging etc. from the results that were published last year.

I then wanted to discover further on SEDE to get the difference of the overall activity of the site from 2018-2019.

By the overall activity, I mean the amount of answers, questions, comments etc.

Since I don’t have experience writing SEDE queries I ask here for guidance how to write such a query. **One day I will look into writing SEDE queries and getting to know the database.**

---

I want to have a query that returns the difference of the following data from 2018-2019 (it should be possible to make start and end year dynamic).

- Amount of questions
- Amount of answers
- Amount of comments
- Amount of new contributors

Don’t know if there’s more that makes sense to include in the query, feel free to comment if you think there’s something that should be added to the query.

Comment: If you get 10K you have access to graphs of number of questions and answers.

Comment: I've just been [doing it manually](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/2019-a-year-in-moderation).

Comment: Not a query but this site comparing the dumps on a couple of things might help somewhat: http://sese.evbpc.com/

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I don't doubt that what you say is correct, but perhaps I could trouble you for a URL for the graphs you speak of on [worldbuilding.se].

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I think you're talking about the [Site Analytics](/help/privileges/site-analytics) privilege, but that's 25K.

Comment: .... Clearly my memory is a little faulty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The decrease of moderation activities might actually be a good thing in your case. According to [this metasmoke report](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/sites/dash?utf8=%E2%9C%93&site_id=86&months=24&tab=all), Drupal Answers saw much less spam in 2019 than in 2018:

[image]

I've written a SEDE query comparing the number of questions and answers networkwide, to answer [How can we find the fastest growing sites within the last year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335427/295232). It's a bit of overkill if you just want to use it for a single site, but [the number of questions has dropped by about 13% and the number of answers by 35%](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1121616/comparison-of-of-posts-per-period?beginOfPeriod=2019-01-01&endOfPeriod=2020-01-01&beginOfComparedPeriod=2018-01-01&endOfComparedPeriod=2019-01-01):

[image]

But I think you're better off using the queries Rubiksmoose used [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9663/22219):

- [Total number of questions, answers per year](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/958293/number-of-questions-answers-and-comments-by-year)
- [Comments per year](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/1173867/total-number-of-comments-by-year)

Comment: That "[Total number of questions, answers per year](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/958293/number-of-questions-and-answers-by-year#graph)" query makes for quite the [spaghetti graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NCU6.jpg); it's not particularly useful.

Comment: @Rob it misses an ORDER BY and I'm on mobile so I can't fix it :(

Comment: No rush, in the next few weeks (days ) would be great.

Comment: @Rob sure. It's not my query though, and if you're looking for an entry-level exercise into SQL, this is one. You can have a look at the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) (in particular [this page](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial/query-joins)) if you need to.

Comment: Glorfindel, it's more of a "suggestion for improvement" for your answer, the link is not a great example if the code is wrong - I appreciate that it's not your job to be our 'T-SQL Fixer". --- I was looking for a query to show questions per day over time, and ran into this answer (thought I would leave a note), while this other query isn't really what I was looking for it works: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer/293286#293286