# How can we put pressure on Stack Exchange Inc. without damaging the community?

Tags: discussion, community, company

Is there a constructive way to put pressure on Stack Exchange (the company) without putting any pressure on the community in general and the moderators in particular?

## Goals

1. Give Monica her diamond(s) back, with a public apology if the accusations were not founded.
2. Address the underlying issues that led to this blowing up:

   - Significant policy changes without review;
   - Not assuming good intent when people ask questions;
   - Dictating to—rather than working with—moderators and the community;
   - Attacking or going silent when challenged;
   - Insufficiently asking the community they claim to want to protect for their input on how to do so.

## Desired properties

The methods to achieve these goals should:

- Be constructive. No trolling, no personal attacks, no targeting of minorities.
- Be sufficiently effective to change some of the company's KPIs to red ([whatever they are](https://twitter.com/SaraJChipps/status/1182650441882058752))
- Not require any additional work from the moderators. There's an extreme amount of pressure already, but it's been mostly directed towards the community.
- Be reversible as soon as improvements are noticed. The goal isn't to permanently damage the company but to force the company to realign with the community. Stack Exchange is still doing a *lot* of things right.

## Past actions

Those actions didn't seem to impress corporate very much:

- [Mods resigning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/390071) (While it has a *huge* impact on the community and the content, there hasn't been any sign that the higher ups seem to care at all).
- [Thousands of Downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248/390071).
- [Strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334638/390071)
- [An open letter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334575/390071)

## What else could work?

- Offer a platform for SE employees to anonymously share information relevant to the current problems. Some of the employees clearly feel a strong link to the community, but they are apparently forced to either stay silent or repeat corporate buzzwords.
- Stop using Stack Exchange paid products at work (e.g. [Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams))
- Advise everyone to enable Ad-Blockers on Stack Exchange.
- Change our [avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGuXb.png).
- Reach out to a prominent Twitter user and let them publicly complain about one of the many recent problems.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I dunno... I think a lack of moderation activity is definitely having an impact.

Comment: Personally, I don’t know if I’d say "Those actions didn't seem to impress corporate very much” just yet. They’ve definitely noticed the pressure and have promised changes based on it (due Tuesday). That being said, it certainly can’t hurt to keep up the pressure.

Comment: There's another option: we could adopt [this image as our avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGuXb.png)

Comment: Post on Twitter. Stop participating. Troll. But really, do you really think there should be more pressure? I don't get it. What about waiting for their reaction next week? I don't like stirring up the mud much. The decent and professional way to react if your concerns are not heard is to simply walk away and nothing more. No more pressure is needed.

Comment: @Trilarion - I agree, even though I've stirred a little bit of mud myself. I wonder if this is what it feels like to be a sports fan. They never seem really happy.

Comment: Anonymous reviews are already found on Glassdoor. Not sure how legit they are

Comment: @Mari-LouA If I were Monica, I would not be wanting to be reinstated. I would be sueing them now.

Comment: Monica has asked to be reinstated, and presumably has her own reasons. (It might help counter the libel and clear her name, for one.)

Comment: Un-sign up for Stack Overflow for Teams.

Comment: @treatyourmodswell And I guess that if she ever gets to be reinstated, SE will treat her very badly from that point on.

Comment: I guess that KPI means "Key Performance Indicator". Given the context of that tweet, I think that it is just an euphemism for massively blocking people that might go to tweeter to criticize her.

Comment: To what end, meaning put pressure on them to do or not do exactly what specific thing? Improve load times? Fix bugs? Implement new features? Hire more employees? Hire fewer? Do away with chat? Change how community elections are run? Become a public charity? Send lobbyists to this or that legislature about some pressing regulatory concern? Please edit your post to say what you want them further pressured on.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm changing my Avatar. If a significant portion of the 1723 people who downvoted the FAQ (as an example of people upset with the current situation) changed their avatars, then the typical new/occasional user will see a reminder of the situation any time they read a Q/A from any of those users. That may do more for publicity among new/occasional users than anything else, which could snowball into major effects on all parts of SE. Or may just get ignored. We'll see.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Good suggestion. Is there an "official" avatar? I've seen a nicer looking one somewhere else, but I can't remember where.

Comment: The only avatar I have seen is the one I posted.

Comment: Instead of changing the full avatar, it would also be possible to add a small support ribbon to the avatar, which you might know from the [pink breast cancer awareness ribbon](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pink_ribbon.svg). There are many more examples on twibbon.com. It is a little more subtle, but still shows the point. But someone needs to design such a ribbon.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Here are some avatars I found on meta: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/179/isaac-moses) [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/312691/mbloch) [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/273494/colleenv) I suppose I'll use the second one, which you proposed.

Comment: Imho there is no effective way to exert pressure. The community has no leverage against the company - they already control all content (which would include avatars sporting telltale references), and their avowed focus is on _new_ users vs existing user base. A mod diaspora mostly harms the community. The Teams product is aimed at corporate clients, circumventing a community boycott. As SE is a Q&A site, the issues wouldn't be the prime concern of most users, if only for a lack of awareness - in-site means to increase that are controlled by SE. A new Q&A site may help but that takes time.

Comment: @collapsar: That's also the conclusion I came to. :-/ Still, I thought it was worth a try to at least ask this question and see if a creative mind finds any constructive way.

Comment: @EricDuminil Right, never underestimate hive creativity. I'd be happy to be proven wrong in my pessimism.

Comment: I suggested in an answer elsewhere that we could collectively extend one last olive branch with a time limit, where we actually kind of ease up and make moderation easier for the mods who are left. The pressure would come from the time limit. Didn't pick up much traction, either from lack of interest or visibility: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335772/630222

Comment: @Obscerno: It looks good and might be worth a try. Feel free to write an answer, even if it's just a sentence and link to your previous answer.

Comment: What is the actual goal, the goal section with the exception of getting a moderator reinstated seems to be methods to achieve pressure on SE Inc? Why should we apply pressure?

Comment: @pacmaninbw: General goal would be to show more respect to the community and to try to work with community. In particular, reinstate Monica (top priority IMHO), stop fake apologies, stop forcing a useless CoC down our throat, stop illegally changing licenses. But really, *any* sign that the higher ups really care about the community would be a good first step.

Comment: You wrote "be constructive", but the specifics you mentioned are not an illustration of what it means to be constructive.

Comment: @einpoklum Why, exactly? I think tough love, positive punishment and and [negative reinforcement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement#Reinforcement_versus_punishment) can be constructive. I mostly meant "constructive" as in "no trolling".

Comment: @EricDuminil can't hurt; I've posted it below: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336065/630222

Comment: @EricDuminil: I don't think most people interpret the term "non-constructive" as "not trolling", I'd consider rephrasing the former into the latter. Also - Helmar is mistaken, in that the company name is still Stack Exchange Inc.

Comment: @Helmar: No it isn't, it's just using SO as a brand. The company is still Stack Exchange Inc.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - how about *same image* and **same user name**? It's an *"[I'm Spartacus](https://youtu.be/-8h_v_our_Q)"* moment.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica oh gawd, who are you? No, don't tell me. No, go on.... That, my friend, would tilt the system. I might even adopt that measure but only if nothing concrete was achieved  after *Wednesday*. P.S *Who are you?*

Comment: @Makoto SFF is running fine, even with no active mods currently.

Comment: #2: Address the underlying issues that led to this blowing up -- significant policy changes without review, not assuming good intent when people ask questions, dictating to rather than working with moderators and the community, going into attack mode when challenged, asking the community they say they want to protect for *their* input... that stuff is all super-important; just reinstating me (though they need to do that too) won't fix the rest.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Thanks for your input. I took the liberty to copy your comment into the question. Feel free to edit if needed.

Comment: I'm nearly going to upvote, but I would remove "going into **attack mode** when challenged," and replace it with **silent mode**. What do you think @MonicaCellio? **Silent mode** is more accurate...

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Those are Monica's words, which are true when describing her case. I incorporated "silent".

Comment: @Mari-LouA they did both -- maligning my character and violating my privacy were attacks, and then they went silent.  Anyway, feel free to adapt however you like.

Comment: @MonicaCellio  it's the waiting for an answer, any answer while at the same time  being ignored that's the cruelest form of passive-aggressiveness, is it not?

Comment: @divibisan hey, do you have a link on that Tuesday thing you mentioned?  I was away since Thursday night and have been out of the loop on it.

Comment: @AJHenderson https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335868/388335

Comment: @ReinstateMonica and now there are two of us :-)

Comment: @ReinstateMonica - it's a start! ;)

Comment: The community has already been damaged beyond repair.

Comment: @HugoZink let's hope not. I mean, a long time ago, there was no StackOverflow community at all. It might take a long time to heal but I don't think anything is broken beyond repair, yet.

Comment: "No community" means you have a blank slate. What SE has today is something *worse* than merely a blank slate. They will never get those users back.

Comment: @HugoZink I think many users are addicted to the intellectual challenges that can be found in this site. They want to participate, they want to keep teaching and learning with random strangers all over the world. All it takes is to stop putting hurdles for their free contribution and they ll be happy to resume as if nothing happened.

Comment: Should you be determined to pursue this road, I fear Twitter is your best option. But I am not sure it will bring the results you hope.

Comment: Thank you for the avatar!  I have updated mine on all of my profiles across the network.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica, and now there are 3 of us

Comment: I got it just now, but then you pinged me. :D @ReinstateMonica I can now choose from two "ReinstateMonica"; after choosing, I cannot @ the other one.

Comment: At a shareholder level, profit and growth (i.e., future profit) is all they are looking at. The company's actions mostly flow from that. And their revenue plans are company secrets, so you will be forced to make educated guesses based on company actions. In order to effectuate pressure, you need to put this revenue at risk. But it can be hard because you don't know their plan. For example, most USA TV news channels feature editing designed to reinforce the beliefs of either the left or the right. It may be the SO Inc. foray into politics is not an accident.

Comment: @Reinstate Monica  Four now.

Comment: The only way that anyone will care about whatever you do is if people can no longer find answers to their questions here. Full stop.

Comment: "Advise everyone to enable Ad-Blockers on Stack Exchange." --> Knowing who sponsors SE is a _good thing_.  Folks can advise sponsors accordingly.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica five

Comment: @ReinstateMonica and ReinstateMonica and ReinstateMonica and ReinstateMonica and ReinstateMonica I like this idea

Comment: @ReinstateMonica he has become one of us, now.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica - oops, I just noticed (genuine mistake) that my [previous comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336024/how-can-we-put-pressure-on-stack-exchange-inc-without-damaging-the-community#comment1115837_336024) may via the new CoC (assuming gender). I chose it because it is a quote from Friends (Chandler). A light-hearted joke can that easily be offensive? Hmmmm...

Comment: Late to the party, but here I am.

Comment: I like this idea. Count me in.

Comment: Could me in too! V  for Vendetta!

Comment: Err, sorry folks, you achieve the exact opposite.  Reinstate Monica ... one two three ... who knows. By *removing* your individuality from your user name, you turn yourself into an undistinguishable swarm. The only thing you achieve is that it is **harder** to see how many folks are "in" that movement.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica : You're [at least 32](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=reinstate), now.

Comment: @EricDuminil Nice. I'm 5th in the list. :-D

Comment: @EricDuminil: [there are now 112 of us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=reinstate+monica)!

Comment: [Now there are 130 of us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=reinstate+monica). And the @ no longer works here for *Reinstate Monica*. :)

Comment: Who is `Monica`?

Comment: Hey... I thought only I used an ad blocker!

Answer (score 112):

I would posit that you can't put pressure on SE *without* damaging the community. Little else damages the fundamental engine of their profit *and* is plausible within your control. (Although hey, more work on legislation protecting or even *preventing* unpaid volunteers would always be welcome.)

My own approach so far has been this, and requires little to no ongoing additional work:

- Remove my name, image, bio, etc. from my profile (disassociate my personal identity)
- Stop providing my free services to SE (don't ask or answer questions, don't perform edits, don't flag problems...)
- Provide my services, free or paid, elsewhere (re-post my best answers on my own blog, participate in help IRC channels, check and participate in Github issues...)

Unfortunately, you can't meaningfully take back past contributions. SE has a license to your prior works, so if you were to delete everything, they could just roll back your changes as "self-vandalism", lock your account, and kick you to the curb.

Ceasing your contributions does not have an *immediate* effect, but probably has the *strongest* effect. The community will begin to slowly degrade right away, and will continue to degrade. It's also reversible: If you start contributing again, the effects will slowly be remediated. (But I would caution against putting in extra work in such a case. SE needs to not be able to gamble on this happening.)

They already have what they want from you. The most you can do is stop giving them more.

Comment: Good points, but I don't agree with "Unfortunately, you can't meaningfully take back past contributions." That's a good thing. There's a huge amount of knowledge over the network, and it should be cherished as the treasure it is. We can complain by not providing new content, we should still stay proud of what we've achieved so far.

Comment: @EricDuminil I don't think it's per-se a good thing. If it's treasure, it is still *my* treasure. I retain ownership, even if I did license it. I am proud of it, but if things go off the rails here, I am certainly not proud of it being here, or of my work being used by a company I am opposed to in order to gain revenue. Things haven't fully degraded to that point, but they certainly could, in which case I regret that my treasure is used as bait to lure people into something that has become detrimental.

Answer (score 94):

## Past actions have been effective

The actions have drawn attention to the updated CoC – over **100k views** in ***9 days*** with a score of ***-1745*** and counting. It led to the creation of Meta's 4th most [upvoted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper) in history with a positive score of **1606** and viewed over **121k times** in only **21 days**. The uproar also attracted the attention of the press, [here](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy/), and [here](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/08/stack_overflow_apology/).

Above all, the significant number of moderators resigning on Stack Exchange and on Stack Overflow has successfully drawn attention to the company's appalling handling of Monica Cellio's demodding.

## What is the mood among SE staff and its CEO?

In order to gauge something, I listened to the revived Stack Overflow podcast entitled: *[compilers, turtles,  and a brand new crew](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/15/the-stack-overflow-podcast-is-back/)* with host Ben Popper and guests; Sara Chipps, the director of Public Q&A at Stack; Paul Ford, a writer, technologist and CEO of Postlight; and special appearance by Prashanth Chandrasekar, Stack Overflow’s newly appointed CEO.

[image]

The first ten minutes of conversation isn't enthralling unless you are starting a career as a developer, computer engineer or programmer, the explanation of what a compiler does will probably be of interest and useful to know. What particularly struck me was how often Ms Chips interjected with her laughter.

Around 10:24 the new CEO is introduced to podcast listeners and around **15:27**, Chandrasekar begins to talk about his vision for the Stack Overflow community and company. In the first two days as CEO he talked to almost 130 Stackers which he said was an “eye-opening learning experience”, he soon realised what made the company ‘tick’ was the SO team

> …(16:45) that cares about this community so much and wants to do the right thing. There are probably a handful of companies in the world that has such a large impact around the world. With 50 million developers coming here to seek answers to their most technical questions, there is no way that you could replicate that magic. And so, we're really really blessed to have a phenomenal community of people that are willing to share so much, and be open about the knowledge that is resident in their heads and ready to promote a truly borderless sharing of information around these topics…

Around 19:45 the topic shifts to turtles. I particularly like freshwater turtles, they're cute, but my blood ran cold when I realized that small children could manipulate these poor turtles at their will, to draw things on computers.

My level of engagement plummeted from this point on.

Around 25:50 mark, the topic shifts to something called “Logo”.
Around 27:00 mark, the host (I think) talks about “Net Logo”.

## Feedback

The atmosphere on the podcast appeared to be relaxed, buoyant and cheerful. The host and guests chatted freely, little if anything seemed to be scripted, but it was clear the primary scope of the show was to introduce the new CEO to Stackers and users alike. Everyone showed a unified front, which did not even *hint* at any possible simmering tension.

Unsurprisingly, there was no mention  of the [diaspora of moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper) fleeing across the network, especially the resignations from SE's jewel in the crown, Stack Overflow;  [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389906/im-resigning-as-a-moderator-from-all-stack-exchange-sites), [George Stocker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390427/im-resigning-as-a-stack-overflow-community-elected-moderator) (a staggering 1,408 votes supporting his decision) and just two days ago, [Jon Clements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390525/yet-another-step-down-as-moderator-post). Unsurprisingly, there was no mention of the recently updated CoC, Sara Chipps' article, *[Iterating on Inclusion](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/10/iterating-on-inclusion/)*, which was published on the company's blog just ten days ago and praised by Fullerton on Twitter; where else?

> [image: Fullerton's congratulatory message to Ms. Chips]

Yet, in the podcast there was no mention of the importance of inclusivity, no mention of the LGBTQ+ community, no mention of the updated CoC, no mention of SO's infamy of being toxic and unwelcoming to minorities but how, finally, they were dealing with it, head on. And last but not least, no mention of Monica's **demodding from six SE sites**, nor how the dismissal was compared to shipping software by the Director of Public Q&A herself.

> [image]

Why? Simply because it's embarrassing to admit in public.

## Next course of action?

**I suggest that we wait.** We wait to see what Wednesday brings. My patience; however, is wearing thin, similar to that of an eggshell.

> [image]

On October 15, Shog9♦ wrote an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335607/223820) to the question on everybody's lips

### [Monica's situation continues unresolved, is SE hoping the problem just goes away?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335508/monicas-situation-continues-unresolved-is-se-hoping-the-problem-just-goes-away)

[Emphasis his]

> As noted in David's apology, we created a lot of the problems in play here by not following process. So now we need a process to follow for handling issues involving moderators that our *existing* process didn't seem right for, and also we need a process for what to do when a moderator has been removed and wants to come back. That last process is the process we need *here* - that's the big test, really: can we build a process that'll give Monica a fair shake even after all that's happened these last few weeks? Good question...
>
> […]
>
> …**If we get that process right**, then we'll finally be able to do something useful here. If we didn't, we'll likely keep circling. That's why, frustrating as it is right now, we're moving slowly.
>
> Believe me, I know how stressful this is to watch, especially when so little is being said. There's a lot I *want* to say right now, but it would be careless of me to do so; and again, we've already been a bit too careless with what we've said in some situations, and hurt folks by doing so.
>
> Thanks for both your patience, and your gentle prodding - it's folks like you being attentive to the work we're doing that keeps us focused.  @Shog9♦

### This is Stack Exchange's last chance

This is Stack Exchange's last chance to begin repairing bridges with its  core users, and rebuild that trust, which has been [slowly eroding for well over a year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331513/lets-take-a-look-at-the-interaction-between-staff-and-the-power-users-of-the). A trust that George Stoker, in his resignation, states began crumbling as far back as 2014

> 1. Stack Overflow Inc. has forgotten how to lead, how to persuade, and how to talk with the community. This has been a slow decline since 2014 and we are now at the point where the company's actions show they no longer want to build a relationship with the community they have.

He brilliantly summed up the proposed moderator process

[Emphasis mine]

> 2. Since the current people in charge also make the decisions regarding the Moderator review/removal process; I am not confident that moderators are seen as partners in community building; but rather volunteers to be tightly controlled. **The proposed Moderator Review process lacks due process**, **codifies the decision making in the hands of the same people who have created the mess we're now experiencing**, and treats oversight of the process in a token fashion. They may as well have retained their previous statement that "community moderators can be removed at any time, for any reason", because that's what the proposed process codifies, with the illusion of impartiality.

### There's not much room for optimism, is there?

> [image]

But there's a glimmer of hope, the process seems to have been vetted, and the moderators have been shown the draft and have suggested ways in which to improve it.

> [image]

Let's hope to see the company and Monica begin talking to each other, in private,  by Wednesday. Let's grant Stack Overflow Inc. this one last chance to get it right.

Comment: logo is a kids programming language involving moving a turtle around a screen if memory serves.

Comment: I am not sure how you can say, *past actions have been effective* they they steadfastly refuse that what they have done was wrong. As you point out, the only mistake they have enumerated specifically was *we should known better to not have done what we did on a Friday*, and now they are spinning it as *process failure*, that they did not have a *quick and fair trial, and then fire her*, so nope, in the past few years nothing can even be remotely considered *effective*.

Comment: @SomeoneWhoUsedToCare moderators resigning, users posting questions and answers on Meta, such as yourself, has meant that the news outlets have gotten wind. The SO team *know* that many are unsatisfied. You suggested, quite recently, that we delete our accounts, how would that have changed anything? Even if you were to have 1,000 users deleting their account it would be a drop in the ocean.

Comment: Someone who doesn't care wouldn't spend so many hours pouring their heart and soul in their posts. Someone who is indifferent, would easily walk away, silently delete their account or just stop contributing. @SomeoneWhoUsedToCare change your username!

Comment: 1000 random people, no big deal, 100 influential people is a completely different story.I can tell you in the [tag:java] tag the correct 10 people deleting their accounts and it got as bad as the [tag:php] tag! I saw the quality drop in the [tag:java] immediately when I saw ~10 stop voting to clean stuff up around the time I quit SO. It has just gotten progressively worse across all the tags so it s hard to relatively judge now, but on a whole the quality is approaching total entropy rapidly.

Comment: You seem to be describing how past actions have not been effective, and have possibly not even penetrated the bubble which is the CEO's consciousness.

Comment: @einpoklum I'm saying that we have reached a point where SE has one last chance to make good. If I was alone in making a fuss nothing would have been achieved, but there's a lot of users on Meta at the moment, and many are still making noises, and they're not shutting up nor shrugging their shoulders. And that also counts for the LGBTQ folk, which include also the more silent ones as well as the more vocal. I think that the time that Fullerton, Chipps, and maybe even Post thought the storm would blow over has long past. The storm is still present.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I see what you mean, but - that's not the bar for effectiveness. We haven't changed anything significant, if at all, to better fit our expectations or demands. So yes, perhaps we've not been feeble or negligible, but there's still far short of being effective.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Hmmm, does it now?

Comment: I have to admit, I had no enthusiasm in wanting to listen to it. After reading this, I have less enthusiasm. I feel bad for being critical of someone I don't know, but I'm just expecting it to be PR handling. Maybe I'm too cynical.

Comment: Negative comments on the podcast seem to be moderated away.

Comment: @ZevSpitz why am I not surprised?

Comment: I hoped the podcast had been recorded months ago, but that doesn't seem to be the case. As this crisis unfolded, my wife told me how every online community she's invested in eventually imploded, with one tell-tale sign that the end (for her) was imminent: when wide-scale dissatisfaction within the community was met with complete apathy from the higher-ups. She said, "It's hard, but you get to a point where it finally sinks in: _they **just don't care**_." I haven't listened to the podcast yet, but I'm afraid the Chipps laughter tells me everything I need to know: as usual, my wife is right.

Comment: Well, since Jeff Atwood left there is a history of content-free (as Scott Hanselman once put it when he was on a guest panel on the podcast) podcasts, going for 100% entertainment and even more disconnected from the actual site(s) (though there are exceptions, like the episode with the employee living in Brazil (I can't find the reference right now). The newest episode (2/145) also has some, about React and mechanical keyboards). Let us hope it will improve.

Comment: @PeterMortensen but this is *today*, the climate is not the same as it was six, five or even fours years ago. A mod was demodded by a director for violating a code that didn't even exist in print. We have something like 20 mods resigning, and dozens of others who have suspended their service. If that's not worthy of broadcasting, I don't know what is. The opportunity to discuss this in the open was ignored, when the new CEO could have tried unifying the community by promising to rebuild a more transparent future, missed.

Comment: Sorry if you explained this and I missed it -- but what is the significance of Wednesday?  How did you choose that day as your deadline?

Comment: @aparente001  On October 15, Tuesday,  Shog9 spoke about the upcoming moderator processes. I wrote this answer on October 20, which was a Sunday. I assumed that the new processes would have been communicated by Wednesday (23 October). The moderator processes were communicated on  [Monday, 21 October, 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336177/feedback-post-moderator-review-and-reinstatement-processes)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Thanks.  Funny, that seems so long ago now!

Comment: I just have to add: CMs, site site moderators, must adhere to the Code of Conduct, given they have authority to sanction users they claim violate it. Until the CEO, staff, CMs, moderators are strictly held to the COC they enforce on lil ole' users, this continues to undermine its purported "goals."

Answer (score 78):

As [discussed in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336024/how-can-we-put-pressure-on-stack-exchange-inc-without-damaging-the-community?noredirect=1#comment1110223_336024):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

A number of users (many dozens now) have changed their usernames to **"Reinstate Monica"** or some variant like **"{username} says Reinstate Monica"**, and/or changed their avatars to this image:

[image]

<sub>(if someone knows who to credit this image to, please edit it in here. [Mari-Lou A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/223820/mari-lou-a) posted the first link to it, I don't know if she designed it or not)</sub>

...and added text to their bios explaining and linking to relevant Meta posts for users encountering the issue for the first time. [For example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/39277/reinstate-monica), and see further discussion on [What would be good “call to action” elements for “Reinstate Monica” profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336839/what-would-be-good-call-to-action-elements-for-reinstate-monica-profiles):

> The recent actions of Stack Exchange have been reprehensible. The lack of professional conduct, the tone deaf way they've been dealing with the community, and the unfair and unjustified way they've dealt with Monica Cellio.
>
> Monica is an exemplar of the community, it's incredible how she's managed to keep a level head during this time when emotions have been very high.
>
> [REINSTATE MONICA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336283/39277)

**Pros:**

- If you have many high-views questions and answers on main sites, it's a good way to raise awareness of the issue to users who don't visit Meta
- It sends a very clear message, and shows Monica personally very clear support (not that I think she has any doubt that most of us support her, but still, it can't hurt to show appreciation)

**Cons:**

- The decision makers at Stack Overflow Inc. probably won't see it, because they aren't people who use Stack Exchange very much. That said, if they do (e.g. some are light Stack Overflow users), it might be a good wake-up call, especially if they find themselves using content from one of your high-quality answers.
- There are a number of users simply called "Reinstate Monica" now, which has a nice "I'm Spartacus" aspect to it, but can get confusing in comment threads when people @ notify someone. If you want to anonimise your profile in protest but still be @-able you could append your user number from your network profile page URL (e.g. mine is https://stackexchange.com/users/275533/user568458 therefore it would be `Reinstate Monica 275533`)

Comment: The first time I saw this avatar was when [J.R adopted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/180981/j-r) it (about 10 days ago?). He is an ELL mod, and soon after,  a co-mod,  ColleenV also adopted it.

Comment: Thank you for writing this excellent answer.  I'm the profile that you've quoted.  I considered the cons of not being recognised, but I felt that becoming a faceless user account with a single message was more important.  It might be insignificant, but it's my personal way of protesting.  I've also become more active, to increase visibility of my username. **If anyone has suggestions for improvements to my user profile message, I'd love to incorporate your feedback**.  I hope Monica does see this, and that she knows we're doing all we can for her, even if it's not likely to work. Thanks.

Comment: I'd love to see this gain some traction, it'd be great to see the avatars get adopted, or the usernames, or both.  It doesn't have to be prescriptive, but it'd be brilliant to see people with some form of this popping up all over the network.

Comment: If you want, using the avatar makes sense. Changing your usernames is silly though because it makes it seem (from the perspective of a reader) that there is just one of you and you are talking to yourself in comments.

Comment: I can get behind this idea

Comment: I've gone a step further:

Comment: This is a good idea.

Comment: As mentioned by Caleb, discussions between @ReinstateMonica users might look like "Multiple Personality Disorder" at first. Something like ["Username says Reinstate Monica"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1531124/ghostcat-says-reinstate-monica) might be a bit clearer.

Comment: I've seen things where you can access statics data from the underlying StackExchange DB. Could someone create a link that shows how many user names contain the string "Reinstate Monica", or some variant on it? (If they can go further and show a graph of that number over time, w.r.t. the date of this post that would be even more awesome!)

Comment: @ReinstateMonica--Brondahl-- Here's a start: https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=reinstate

Comment: I like that, if enough users adopt this, SE will have to do something about it

Comment: I think it started [with this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336024/how-can-we-put-pressure-on-stack-exchange-inc-without-damaging-the-community?noredirect=1#comment1110223_336024) - please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If you're reading this: [will you join us?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=reinstate+monica)

Answer (score 66):

1. Start a competing site.
2. Bring over all the Creative Commons Q&A
3. Do a better job managing the site.

If you build it well, they will come.

We can all think of several dot coms that fell to poor management and good competition.

**Update** See [codidact.org](https://codidact.org/), the [Codidact Meta](https://meta.codidact.com/), a place to discuss the best way forward to develop a community-driven alternative to replace Stack Exchange with something healthier, and the [current list of communities](https://codidact.com/).

Comment: Related question: would it be possible to migrate the reputations or is the information a property of StackOverflow? One appeal of the network is that it's a meritocracy. Experienced users might not want to start from scratch.

Comment: @EricDuminil technically this seems possible - if I understand correctly such rep-preserving migration already succeeded in an opposite direction when SE network on-boarded Math Overflow and Russian Stack Overflow

Comment: @gnat Was Math Overflow a completely separate entity at first?

Comment: @EricDuminil per my reading of their meta, they [started separate](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4016) and, possibly, still remain [somewhat separate](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/970): "should MathOverflow wish to migrate its data outside of the Stack Exchange network, Stack Exchange shall, within thirty (30) days of receipt of a written request from MathOverflow, provide MathOverflow with a complete and current database that contains all the data necessary to recreate MathOverflow on MathOverflow's own servers and software..."

Comment: Also, we shouldn't underestimate the amount of work SE is doing right. If the current situation can be saved, we should really try to save the relationship first. But yes, your suggestion could work as a last resort.

Comment: @EricDuminil: Good point. SE sites perform well, have good features, and almost never go down. It would be hard to replicate this.

Comment: +1 There's a big opportunity here to also do some big refused feature requests, like sorting answers by votes *weighted by recency* to avoid the "Fastest Gun In the West" problem, fixing HNQs, basic threading of comments so e.g. "we should/shouldn't close this" back-and-forth is in an accordion, adding a *very* basic, moderator-visible direct messaging system, allowing high-rep users to flag questions as "easy" or "hard" which is then fed into the front page algorithm so users who usually answer easy or hard questions see more of what they want, etc etc...

Comment: @EricDuminil you could migrate rep like for example, on your new site profile you hit a "migrate a profile" button and paste the url of your SE profile, it gives you a one-use code, you edit that code into your SE profile description to prove it's really you, it reads the page, validates the code, and migrates the rep. No action on SE side needed.

Comment: @user568458: Sure, it's technically possible. I'm not sure it would be legal though, if reps are copyrighted info from SE.

Comment: Then don't copy the exact number. The new sites probably won't have the exact same rep scoring anyway. It could be, for example, you get X * 500 rep on the new site for each X * 1000 rep you had on SE. No laws against reading a publicly published number then making a decision based on it.

Comment: @EricDuminil Are reputation scores considered a creative work?

Comment: Imagine that you screw so much at your community management job that you are the element triggering a whole schism of the most implicated part of your community.

Comment: A new site would need to calculate rep anyway (for ongoing contributions), so it's sufficient to import the posts and then calculate rep. Edit rep might be harder but is probably an acceptable loss if so.  A decision would need to be made about bounties.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I think bounties would be site specific.  Once the new site is up, you would need to bring over new posts at SE, presumably SE is going to do the same when it realizes it is losing market share to the new site. Ultimately both sites would host all the Q & A until one fails.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, seeing this now, I'm inclined to think we should seriously consider querying the *actual community* regarding an initial reputation score import (and in fact, the issue of reputation as a whole) once our platform launches...

Answer (score 53):

A note on this suggestion:

> Stop using Stack Exchange paid products at work (e.g., Teams)

Boycott campaigns can be very successful, but they succeed only **if the target *knows* they're being boycotted *and why***, and can *see* that the small dip on their charts has a clear explanation and could become a downward trend.

If senior staff in the Public Q&A team don't follow what the community behind the public Q&A are saying here on Meta, then the sales team *definitely* don't.

### Write to Stack Overflow Inc. and *tell them*

Don't just post here; very few Stack Overflow Inc. employees actually use their own network. It won't be seen.

Instead, write *directly* to the appropriate sales team – see for example https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact – and also post to social media and/or blog about it.

If hardworking sales professionals ***see*** that their hard work trying to promote their company is being 
actively undone because *one* colleague in a different team refuses to take responsible action after breaking the company's own rules while pursuing an inexplicable personal grudge against a valuable volunteer, they may apply the kind of pressure we can't.

### What can I do?

If you're a software developer:

- You can tell them how you advise colleagues to use other platforms for Q&A and knowledge sharing (e.g., GitHub issues) because of the failing quality control, moderation and community engagement you see at Stack Overflow. I believe that SO Inc. is complacent about Stack Overflow's (slipping) market leader position, but they must have noticed and have some concerns about how (even a year or two ago) its reputation began to fall steeply.
- **You are a key part of the target market for Stack Overflow Jobs.** You can tell them that you no longer use this for job searches, and that you tell companies who advertise there that it is a platform you won't use (e.g., in surveys, or if you see their own website link to a Stack Overflow Jobs page, etc).

  Something that could be quite effective is, any time you see a company advertise exclusively or primarily using Stack Overflow Jobs, you could send them an email saying that you do not use this platform due to the company's unethical treatment of its volunteers, and you therefore will not apply for positions at this company unless an alternative method is offered, **and bcc the relevant SO sales team in the email**.
- **Your employer is the target market for Teams and Jobs.** You can tell them that you have advised your company not to consider such products, because, as a long-standing member, you have observed that Stack Overflow is a burning platform. Even if your company was never considering such products, they will be hoping to reach companies like yours with their marketing and it will concern them to learn that their marketing will be reaching decision makers who are already briefed against them.

If you are a senior person in a software company (even a very small one):

- You can say very similar things to above but with much higher impact – "My company has made the decision to [x]" is stronger than "I am advising my employer to [X]",
- You could blog about it on the company blog, if there is one. This could be *very* high impact, if you get the tone right.

  For example: you supported their talk and ambitions about inclusivity, but having observed how the company appears to be abusing the name of inclusivity as a cover for staff to pursue unrelated personal vendettas against volunteers, you believe this is a company you cannot trust to be part of your company's operations. You now favour [x] for recruitment, [y] for internal knowledge sharing, and [z] as your recommendation for employees seeking support from the wider developer community.

**If you don't work in software**, it's harder to make an impact because the other sites are so much smaller and less monetised, but there could still be an impact if enough people directly tell them things like:

- You no longer promote the SE site among other enthusiasts in that field, and/or you promote [rival site] instead,
- You advise people you know in that field to use an ad blocker if they visit that site

Answer (score 45):

I think the only viable strategy at this point is getting media attention, be it Twitter or newspapers. However, attracting the attention you want won't be easy as going against woke policies is likely to be interpreted negatively. There're a lot of context and history which lead to this disagreement, so the story is hard to sell to readers.

Technically, moderators resigning is probably the hardest hit both to the company and the community. However, at the large scale, nobody is indispensable for big companies. Even if the site loses 10% of moderators and active users, it won't massively affect the company in the long run.

Whether you should suspend your activity or not, you should decide based on your own plans, relations and feelings. Going on a strike just to lower "KPI" is probably not a good idea and is unlikely to succeed. The same thing with using ad-blockers or not promoting Teams at work — you're likely a very small minority, so you should make such decisions yourself rather than join an inefficient strike and then measure random fluctuations on SEDE. But that's just my opinion. Maybe I'm overly pessimistic.

The company is clearly aware of the backlash, the reaction is unprecedented already, so I'd rather wait for the company's next step rather than focus on destructive actions.

Anyway, it's been proven many times that what really gets the company's attention is social media. Random posts on Twitter cause immediate reaction and massive changes. I don't know anybody who may be interested, but if you know any prominent users on Twitter, YouTube etc., you should try getting their attention. I think this approach has much higher chances of having a visible effect.

Comment: It's a sign of how backwards the company is right now.  Social media is irrelevant, and it's what they react to.  Quality community moderation is absolutely essential to their long term existence, and they want to pretend it doesn't matter.

Comment: @kbelder Spent half an hour searching, but stll couldn't find a post which discusses this problem... iirc, an employee explained in it why employees aren't biggest fans of Meta. Meta has been for some time getting more and more negative, so the employees naturally don't want to visit Meta and discuss things there. A lot of decisions are made by higher ups, so it's hard to blame either side. Anyway, as a result, Meta loses its value and it's hard to do something about it.

Comment: I would worry that if this story got a lot of media attention, it would end up getting out of our control. I worry that we’d pull in outside groups who don’t care at all about SE and just see the problems here as a opportunity to troll or push their political views. I worry, then, that the ultimate solution would then have to be built around satisfying those outside groups, not what would be best for SE and the community. I don’t know if I’m right and it might be naive, but I would really prefer if we could, somehow, reach a solution within the community

Comment: @Athari thanks for the answer. Meta must have become soul crushing indeed for the SE employees who grew with the community and still feel part of it.

Comment: @divibisan The angel sitting on my shoulder agrees with you that it's better to resolve the conflict without outsiders, but the devil on the other shoulder demands to know whether only one side is listened to on social media like some users claim. I'm torn.

Comment: @divibisan https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318341

Comment: @Athari I agree with you wrt a promising strategy (find social media bigshots to support the cause). This avenue is open to SE as well, so the promise may be limited ...

Comment: _Even if the site loses 10% of moderators and active users_ - but what if the 10% of active users are the 90% of experts who provide valuable content like in the [Pareto rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle). This would mean (huge) troubles.

Comment: The weaponization of Twitter (by someone outside of SO/SE) seems to be what got  the CoC uproar on META_SE going last year.  Your idea to apply Twitter as leverage isn't a bad strategy.  Whether or not it achieves the desired effect I cannot predict.

Comment: @ChristineH.Richards They'll still get 90% as much ad revenue so they won't care. Until 3 years down the line when there's a lack of up-to-date content.

Answer (score 28):

Not much of this would work sadly, not as you understand it anyway.

We're currently hearing *some* comforting noises but the effect is to be seen.

> be strong enough to change some of the company's KPIs to red

We would need to know what the KPIs are. And well - I'm pretty doubtful that anything we do can make a *massive* impact on SE's revenue streams. Historically the big causes of SE not meeting performance goals was... shooting themselves in the foot.

> not require any additional work from the moderators.

Literally any form of public protest involves extra moderator work.

> be reversible as soon as improvements are noticed. The goal isn't to permanently damage the company but to force the company to realign with the community.

Looking at current events, well there's always a risk things spiral out of control.

> Offer a platform for SE employees to anonymously share information relevant to the current problems. Some of the employees clearly feel a strong link to the community but are apparently forced to either stay silent or repeat corporate buzz words.

And such a platform would still be under corporate thumb

> Stop using StackExchange paid products at work (e.g. Teams)

We're often not the decision makers. Also if there *is* a widespread boycott, and losses - we can't be sure what the effect is

> Advice everyone to enable Ad-Blockers on stackexchange.

So far. for most part SE dosen't particularly mind if you use an adblocker.

> Reach out to a prominent Twitter user and let them publicly complain about one of the many recent problems.

Honestly if *I* had that sort of influence and could cause change, I would *never stop tweeting about it*

The moderator open letter and such had an effect. But what you want will determine what change you want.

I'd personally love to see more investment in the community -both in terms of "physical" resources like more employees on the community side and better *more productive* engagement from folks here. The latter might take a while at this point. Its what I would lobby and push for.

So a start would be *deciding what you want SE to be* and working towards that

Comment: Thanks a lot for the interesting feedback. You're probably right on all counts. I'll keep thinking about it and try to refine the question.

Comment: If you work out something let me know . We need like another dozen CMs

Comment: Also interesting homework question - maybe for myself. What is the actual value in the community for someone in the company, or investing in it in money, but not an active member of the community. What's the selling point of the community here, and how could we convince management that it is....

Comment: "Literally any form of public protest involves extra moderator work. " <- Not if it's physical rather than on-line.

Comment: Uhm. Who exactly is going to go to New York and start or join a picket line?

Comment: People already in or near New York? There must be quite a lot. Several of our Director of Public Q&A's posts differentiate between staff, who we are frequently reminded are "real people", and users and moderators, who it is implied are not. Maybe seeing some users for real might change some attitudes? This assumes the people who turn up can be trusted to be polite, respectful and dignified (no pies!), else that will just make things much worse.

Answer (score 25):

I think SE will respond in significant ways to a few actions:

- Customers dropping the Teams product because they don't want a vendor who's embroiled in social controversies, or is careless with releasing PII, or because IT decision-makers are making a stand against SE management.
- Negative press exposure, in a 'real' newspaper.  Not Hacker News, not Reddit.  Their worst nightmare, right now, should be the fear that some news magazine will write a sympathetic story about how Monica was betrayed by an organization she had trusted and volunteered for for years.
- Social Media... IF the critic comes with a certain level of popularity, and is active in the same social media circles as SE management.  That won't be of any aid to the actual SE community, of course.

Downvoting Meta posts is ignored.  Resigning moderators are an annoyance, but I suspect SE thinks that moderators are interchangeable, and can be easily replaced.  Of course, we're already seeing the average level of moderation descend as principled mods leave; but I don't think SE cares about the slow decline of quality.

Most of all, though, they shouldn't be given a break.  This is like chemotherapy, and letting up on the bitter medication will just allow the disease to re-establish itself even stronger.  The temporary harm to the community is nothing comparing to the death of the community if you give up.

If your only weapon is annoyance and pestering, which is all we have on Meta, it needs to be non-stop and never-ending.

Until they fix the issue.

Comment: What's "real" media depends on the audience. The people who decide on buying SO Teams in a company are usually people who likely read reddit and related tech news sites.

Answer (score 25):

> Is there a constructive way to put pressure on Stack Exchange (the company) without putting any pressure on the community in general and the moderators in particular?

Donate to Monica's [GoFundMe](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users). Of all the various avenues, this seems the most likely to get results. By donating, you are no longer just angry words on the internet, but show SE Inc you will hold them accountable. This also puts no pressure on the moderators or community.

Comment: Please edit to include the goals of the funding (legal action against SE).

Answer (score 23):

If you want to very quickly change your avatar without losing your original visual identity, and you don't feel like messing with real image-manipulation software, I recommend using https://addtext.com/ . You can drop your current avatar in, add "Reinstate Monica", and save the resulting image in less than a minute. It comes with a watermark, but I don't care much in this (hopefully temporary!) case, and anyway, it makes this simple technique more discoverable.

Example:

[image: My standard gravatar with "REINSTATE MONICA" superimposed at the top, and an addtext.com watermark at the bottom]

Comment: Good suggestion. There must be a website that provides this functionality without any watermark, though.

Comment: That's nice to provide moral support to Monica, but if you continue to otherwise use the site unchanged then they will be more than happy to ignore the protest.

Answer (score 22):

One way to help Monica without even involving the community of users would be to visit Monica's [GoFundMe](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users) page. This would be a below the radar way to really get SE's attention, privately, for the injured party, Monica. Tanks.

Comment: [Beat you to it :)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336980/386280)

Comment: I know, but the new username should get some needed attention, am I right? :)

Comment: Agreed! I may have to follow your lead there

Comment: Already has enough funds for the first atage

Comment: Beware that SE [may remove links to GoFundMe campaigns against it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338270/why-is-se-removing-links-and-community-ads-about-legal-issues).

Answer (score 21):

## Place community ads on as many sites as possible.

Based on [this design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336283/182566)

[image: dark ad]

[image: light ad]

[image: light ad outline]

Community ads are supposed to be relevant to the site they are posted on. I would argue that current issues relating to the network as a whole and its interactions with its volunteers and users are extremely relevant to each individual site, and how avid users decide to spend their time moving forward.

It would almost certainly help raise awareness of Monica's situation if this (or other community ads like it) were posted on all sites - or preferably if multiple variants of this ad were posted on each site on the network to increase the chance of it displaying to users.

**In case anyone else wants to make their own community ad or profile image:** [image]

Comment: Not sure if I should add a list of sites with the ads posted, but I just added one to Blender. https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2675/5426

Comment: I have to say the graphic looks a bit like a traffic accident between two Pacman ghosts. But whatever, this is neat.

Comment: I saw an ad that used my gravatar (the larger one from the GoFundMe page) and superimposed text/graphics.  So that's another approach.

Comment: This was a good idea, so SE decided to can it

Comment: @ReinstateMonica SE trying to silence the community's support for Monica almost creates more of an outcry than what they did to Monica in the first place. I hope everyone who sees what is happening donates to help her legal battle.

Comment: Someone should start a GoFundMe to make those ads paid.

Answer (score 19):

This answer is an offshoot of the [answer I wrote regarding possible SE violations of New York labor law](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337119/287826), where I share my research that appeared to show that for-profit companies are not permitted to use volunteer labor except for short-term projects.  See also https://www.dol.gov/whd/regs/compliance/whdfs71.htm and https://www.labor.ny.gov/workerprotection/laborstandards/PDFs/FAQs_NonProfit_and_State2016.pdf.

Here is the way I see the basic problem, from the point of view of the volunteeer moderators and community members who are frustrated about recent mismanagement of the network of public Q&A sites (this is going to be quite boiled down, that is, very simplified):

Traditionally, people contributed their time, knowledge, creativity and patience out of altruism, because the work was felt to be valuable, for oneself and for others, and it was rewarding.  But this fall, it has become a lot less rewarding for many of us, myself included.  (I am a garden variety participant.)

So I started thinking about how to encourage SE leadership to dialog with Monica and be more transparent with moderators and participants.

I reached out in several different ways to request the opportunity to speak with someone in a position of authority, such as David Fullerton. There was no response, ultimately.

Also, I looked into filing a complaint with JAMS (cost in most states in the US: $250).  See [my post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334482/287826).  However, after speaking with a labor relations expert, I came to have some doubts about the speed and effectiveness of filing with JAMS.

Then I became curious about where the volunteer moderators and the SE company fit together in relation to US and New York State labor law.  I've spoken with an investigator at the Wage and Hour Division of the New York Department of Labor, and with her supervisor.  I have a phone appointment for Monday with the next person up the ladder at NY DOL.  (I want to make sure I understand correctly the status of the volunteer moderators.  Even though the two people I've spoken with so far have given consistent guidance, I want to be triply sure I'm not misinterpreting something.)

Here's my current understanding:

Anyone living in the United States can file a Wage and Compensation violation complaint, regardless of state, and regardless of whether they are a moderator or not.

(A complaint could alternatively be made at the federal level.)

The initial complaint to the NY DOL would be filed by phone.  It can be filed as a systemic complaint.

The idea is to exert pressure on the company to:

> (a) create a non-profit network that would take over the existing Q&A
> sites;
>
> (b) donate hosting, software and technical troubleshooting to the
> non-profit;
>
> (c) treat the volunteer moderators and contributors with respect and
> transparency -- and that would include Monica;
>
> (d) and allow self-rule at the new network.

The company would still benefit from the effect on potential customers being able to see the software in action at the public network.  However, the public network would no longer provide a direct source of revenue to the company through advertising.

It would be up to the non-profit to decide whether to run ads, and if so, what kind.

The non-profit might decide to hire some paid staff.  Perhaps some or all of the CMs would be interested in applying.

The NY DOL has told me that once a complaint is filed, things move pretty quickly, on a time scale of weeks (not months or years, as I've seen happen at the Office for Civil Rights).

The first step would be for the DOL to do an initial evaluation of the complaint and decide whether to open an investigation.

The complainant(s) can provide a list of volunteer moderators and their contact information.  The DOL would then contact those people as part of the investigation.  They would be focused on moderators who perform their volunteer work on US soil.  In other words, if you are a citizen of Country Y (other than the US), but you reside part of the year in the US, then even if you're in the US on a tourist visa, the DOL would be interested in interviewing you.

The goal would not be to force SE to come up with enough money to cover all the moderators' unpaid back-pay.  I am quite hopeful the violation could be resolved by shifting the volunteer activities over to a non-profit.  There would hopefully be no need for the company to actually make reimbursement payments.

I do want to clarify that the idea would be to pressure the company to treat its moderators right, all the while avoiding a strategy that would make the company go bankrupt.

I do understand that nobody became a moderator hoping to earn some dollars.  The labor complaint would simply be a way to get SE to wake up and smell the coffee.  We've been writing persuasively for a couple of months now, but SE, and we, appear to be stuck in a holding pattern.  It may now be time to speak in a way that will get their attention.

I found some more interesting reading:

- [Review article about relevant case law](https://www.paulhastings.com/docs/default-source/PDFs/2262.pdf) by Blake Bertagna, an attorney in the Employment Law Department of Paul Hastings, LLP
- There is an ongoing [class action lawsuit against Vox Media](https://gbdhlegal.com/cases/vox-media-inc/) which bears some similarity to our situation.
- Here's a quote from the Supreme Court decision [Tony & Susan Alamo Foundation v. Sec'y of Labor, 471 U.S. 290 (1985)](http://cdn.loc.gov/service/ll/usrep/usrep471/usrep471290/usrep471290.pdf):

  > If an exception to the [Fair Labor Standards Act] were carved out for employees willing to testify that they performed work "voluntarily," employers might be able to use superior bargaining power to coerce employees to make such assertions, or to waive their protections under the Act.
- "[Wage Hour Laws: Avoiding the Quicksand and Land Mines](https://www.ebglaw.com/news/wage-hour-laws-avoiding-the-quicksand-and-land-mines/)" by Peter M. Panken, Lauri F. Rasnick.  This review article includes information about protections against retaliation.

[At the OP's request, the latest development is being communicated]

On Monday (2019/11/19), the NY Department of Labor emailed me to say that the next step would be to submit a formal question to the US Department of Labor, as a way to get more definitive guidance.

***Note to company staff and directors: I very much hope you will not delete this post, as I am really hoping we can work things out to everyone's satisfaction, and I would not like you to give the appearance of retaliating, based on my public announcement here that I am considering filing a Wage and Hour complaint with the NY Department of Labor.***

Comment: Interesting... One quick concern though - is there a danger of non-US moderators who do some moderation while in the US on non-business visas (e.g. while on holiday/vacation), who respond to DOL queries honestly and in good faith, then finding themselves in legal trouble, for "working" in the US without a work permit?

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8 - I asked about this and apparently this would not be a problem.  However, you and others are welcome to ask directly.  Also note that if someone, or some group of people gives a list of volunteer moderators to the DOL, and the DOL contacts the person to invite them to a phone interview, the individual *can decline to participate*. // I forgot to say, I believe SE has an office in London.  I hope someone will look into the labor laws in the EU and let us know what is possible there.

Comment: For the UK it's UK law and not EU, and was clarified recently after some controversy about exploitative unpaid internships by for-profits. The main relevant criteria are, minimum wage applies if "they only have a limited right to send someone else to do the work (subcontract)" and "they have to turn up for work even if they don’t want to", see https://www.gov.uk/employment-status/worker and https://www.gov.uk/employment-rights-for-interns - usually, UK for-profits can have unpaid volunteers so long as those volunteers don't have essential duties that only that one specified person can perform.

Answer (score 18):

## ASK QUESTIONS

Asking and answering questions is what this network is all about, isn't it? So, as long as the questions we ask are appropriate, relevant and and respectful, they can't possibly damage the community, can they?

Most people come here to learn, to share knowledge, or both. So let's do *just that*.

### What to Ask

We need to ask questions and provide answers about **every nuance** of the things that are bothering us.

### Where to Ask

On any and every relevant site,

For example, do you have questions about:

- Demoting volunteers? Then ask questions at [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)
- What "re-litigate" means? Ask at [English Language and English Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)
- How SE moderators are removed? Ask at [SE.Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)
- Moral philosophy? Ask at [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/)

Anything else? Then go and ask where you would normally ask.

### How to Ask

This isn't about generating spam. This is about asking good quality questions that generate good quality answers. That's what the community thrives on... and also what will raise awareness of every dimension of the issues that face us right now,

### Will it Work?

I think that it already is.

Comment: Other sites of possible interest: Community Building, Law, Interpersonal Skills, Writing, and maybe Skeptics.

Comment: Good suggestion. For the last sentence: do you mean that it's already being done or that it really is working? If so, how can you tell? Do you have links?

Answer (score 13):

I have moderate<sup>[1]</sup> activity on the Stack Exchange network and I don't often protest any person or organization. On the other hand, I like this community and feel responsible to do something against the events, which are harming the community and some users in person.

After observing the discussions (and the company's attitude) on MSE for a few weeks, I decided to take (and took) the following actions.

1. I uninstalled the Stack Exchange Android app.
2. I unfollowed @StackOverflow on Twitter.
3. I removed my Stack Exchange flair from my blog.

I believe these actions don't damage the community and they are easily reversible.

<sup>[1] 170 posts in 2.5 years</sup>

Answer (score 12):

Almost by definition, moderators are very involved with their sites, but every site also has a group of active users posting, reviewing, editing, etc.  It's clear to me that SE doesn't value this involvement by active users.

Since SE doesn't value a high level of involvement, my response is to be less involved.

A visible sign of my lowered involvement is that I've reverted to the default gravatar and I'm considering changing my username to userXXXXX.  (I think the latter step could have some impact if lot of active users did the same.)

It doesn't take a lot of time to keep on top of flags on Server Fault, so I'll keep doing that.  But I don't see myself doing any other clean-up functions: voting, closing/re-opening votes and reviews, etc.  On other sites where I was active, I'll probably still read and lurk, but nothing more than that.  (Except for meta.SE where I think some voting on all the discussion around these issues is warranted.)

Comment: Why don't you completely uninvolve yourself?

Comment: No, [the VCs are actually looking for highly engaged users](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY&t=8m50s) (continuation at 11 min 33 secs (after an ad)).

Answer (score 11):

I suggest we consider baking a Key Lime pie for senior SE officials. Perhaps if they taste the superb heavenly lemony sweetness of it, their cold, cruel hearts will soften.

[When they go low, we go pie.](https://www.thenation.com/article/pieing-egging-anarchist-entartage/)

[image]

<sub>You can also buy the pie if you're not much of a baker.</sub>

Comment: I thought we were supposed to chill their hot hearts with a cool island song?

Comment: @OrangeDog: Metaphors don't mix that well. But pie filling does!

Comment: I'm not American, is baking a key lime pie code for something? When I visit the link it tells me to disable my ad blocker... I'd prefer not to.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: It doesn't tell me that... maybe you should _improve_ your ad blocker. I use uBlock Origin and EFF Privacy Badger. Anyway, try [here](https://pastebin.com/Dg2EcU86).

Comment: It certainly advocates that the purchaser or baker toss the pie at the person's face, it's usually a politician: *Pieing is a particularly fitting form of political action in our troubled times. It is as ridiculous as its victims are malicious. It is guaranteed to go viral, especially when set to music, like a mazurka or a nice waltz. Pieing is safe for work, suitable for children, and highly unlikely to cause long-term damage to its victims (besides, perhaps, Pie-TSD.)* Your answer suggests that the directors and CEOs tuck into it! :P

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Wow, that would be quite the event, [wouldn't it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTENoPNaOCo)? Interesting suggestion.

Comment: A horrible video, the pie was thrown by a coward, they immediately fled.

Comment: This pie looks delicious. Do you happen to have the recipe?

Comment: @EricDuminil: It's a stock photo... but [here's a recipe](https://www.yummly.com/recipe/Best-Key-Lime-Pie-2678342?prm-v1) which results in a pretty similar one. The recipe is lacking with some final garnishing with thin lemon slices though.

Comment: I heard that they fired their pastry chef(s); https://www.businessinsider.com/chefs-at-stack-exchange-2014-2

Comment: My favorite meta post of the last 90 days.  Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 5):

Part of the difficulty is that the overwhelming majority of users don't know or care about how SE (the company) is ignoring the community; they're just interested in finding an answer to their question/problem.

Perhaps when writing questions or answers, we could insert a single-line banner, something like the following:

> The company behind Stack Overflow is ignoring the community. Please take action now, and feel free to spread this banner.

with embedded links to relevant Meta posts.

Recommended actions might include communicating with the CEO and others in management positions, with current and potential investors; making noise via social media, etc.

This would bring the issue to a wider audience than just visitors to Meta.

If enough people participate, this would also force the company to recognize just how much the sites depend on active moderation.

Comment: Hmm. My worry with this is, it'd create yet more work for the remaining moderators (inevitable edit wars where someone edits these notices out then the protester edits it back in again), for very little impact because the decision makers behind the main problems *don't really use StackExchange sites* beyond occasional google => copypaste and very occasional, *very* reluctant visits to meta (which is one of the root causes of the problem - they believe in magical answer fairies and magical moderation fairies; they don't understand what keeps these sites strong, and won't until it's gone).

Comment: (not my downvote btw, I think it's a worthy suggestion worth considering. There's got to be *something* like this that would work)

Comment: @user568458 Could we get the moderators' tacit approval? Nothing formal, just some sort of feeling that they'd let this slide?

Comment: Maybe, but you can't get the tacit approval of all the regular users who would see these notices and decide to edit them out. Maybe the notices could be accompanied by a link to a site-specific Meta page which demonstrates a clear consensus to allow these notices?

Comment: @user568458 Also, I would think anyone who is invested enough to edit content would also be invested enough in these issues.

Comment: Oh yes. And many of them will be *very* invested in enforcing the *"Questions and answers must contain only relevant content"* rule, which is why the edit wars will start. But I think many of these users would respect a clear, written consensus on their sites' meta.

Comment: The only way you will get "the overwhelming majority of users" to see a problem is if they can't get their questions answered. Full stop.

Comment: @user253751 True, but that could take 6-8 additional years of SE's community relations (mis)management. This would have a far more immediate effect. Particularly WRT answers, I think the average user who poses a question is eagerly awaiting an answer, and hyperfocused to some degree on getting that answer; when the user clicks through and is greeted by such a banner, that hyperfocus is involuntarily applied to the banner. Like GDPR notices -- you click on an interesting link, and get a GDPR notice; the net effect is that _everyone_ knows GDPR is a "thing", even if nobody actually reads the ...

Comment: @user253751 ...  particular compliance of the site with GDPR.

Comment: @ZevSpitz as a result, lots of people (especially USians) see the GDPR as "some stupid law that means I have to click through more popups". This may or may not be intentional on the part of the websites.

Comment: @user253751 Even having that kind of result would be better than the current situation, where nobody outside meta knows anything about all this. But such a banner would actually be less intrusive than a GDPR notice.

Comment: @ZevSpitz it will make people go "those stupid mods are such idiots, I can't believe they'd make people put these banners up." They will be on SE's side because SE doesn't like the banners either.

Comment: @user253751 Many people would certainly react that way. Others might just ignore it. But there might be quite a few people who would see the banner and be interested in understanding further. I think SE is actually terrified of these people, each of whom might be a powerful influencer in their own circles.

Answer (score 5):

> Be reversible as soon as improvements are noticed. The goal isn't to permanently damage the company but to force the company to realign with the community. Stack Exchange is still doing a lot of things right.

Don't worry about the company. The company is a means to serve the community, not the other way around. If the company breaks down, a new company will be very interested to support our community. This community can be used to make profit with very little investment; they just need servers and a listening ear. The other way around is harder; the company cannot do much without the community and it will have to pay its employees, and without money coming in, for which they rely on having a community, that's hard.

So basically, what you need to do to change a company's direction is to force it. There are two things the company listens to:

- money
- the law

### Money

You've already suggested two ways of attacking revenue:

> - Stop using Stack Exchange paid products at work (e.g. Teams)
> - Advise everyone to enable Ad-Blockers on Stack Exchange.

That's probably not enough. They'll get the bulk of their money from investors, and attacking that supply is hard as you'll have to convince investors not to invest. It's clear what's needed to change investors' minds. Make clear that it's a bad investment. The 'problem' is that it's not; SE has unique access to a great community.

Alternatively, you can make investors be more picky. They pay, and they can demand. This is again tricky. How do you convince investors that they'll have a better investment if they condition their money on certain demands? Can you even convince yourself that the requested changes have a meaningful impact on return on investment? If so, please provide the argument, and then share that en masse. Note that such an analysis is probably enough to convince many in the current leadership to change. As Clinton strategist James Carville coined it:

> [The economy, [censored]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_the_economy,_stupid)

### The law

The law can be a great tool. If the company breaks the law or a court of law agrees they renege on some of their obligations then that's a fact you can use to convince investors to push for change.

It's also a good way to convince others in the community who aren't aware of wrongdoing. Nobody likes injustice, not even those who work for Stack Exchange. It may compel change, and it may empower others to stand up.

The question, of course, is whether there is a legal case. I can think of at least one, that's already working, as [SE staff says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338271/387405):

> This has taken a legal turn and we want to be as transparent as we can. Under guidance from our legal team, we are not able to respond to anything regarding Monica's situation. We will not be answering any questions or comments about that going forward.

That's great. Teams are expensive, and legal teams even more so. Let investors know they're spending their money in the courts. I'm sure they'll wonder if that's really necessary and if it wouldn't be more economical to have better policies that don't end up in court.

And if SE wants to play dirty, go ahead. We have larger numbers. Some states in the US legal system allow SLAPP, and this may be an opportunity to use it for good and to compel the network we love to change for the better. And compelling it is. From [Wikipedia's page on strategic lawsuit against public participation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_lawsuit_against_public_participation):

> In the typical SLAPP, the plaintiff does not normally expect to win the lawsuit. The plaintiff's goals are accomplished if the defendant succumbs to fear, intimidation, mounting legal costs, or simple exhaustion and abandons the criticism. In some cases, repeated frivolous litigation against a defendant may raise the cost of directors and officers liability insurance for that party, interfering with an organization's ability to operate.

The only downside to this is that it takes money to take it to court. The upside is that it only takes one person with a load of money to overwhelm SE. And again, don't worry about the company. Even if it breaks, someone else will buy it and they'll want to keep the good elements. Worry about the community, not the company.

Comment: You are right that SE, even when damaged, is still superior to any other alternative, but that doesn't mean an investor would ignore damage to his investment.

Comment: @Fermiparadox I'm not sure if they're going to interfere in any particular case. They may, however, request that this be investigated internally and seek assurances that this doesn't happen again. Seeing how a lot of people have been asking similar things here, I wouldn't be surprised if it's only shrugged off and ignored.

Answer (score -9):

I suggested a protest action as an answer to a separate but similar question: [How can we resolve the current drama without causing any more harm to vulnerable groups?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335772/630222)

The idea is to paradoxically ease up on the pressure in order to give SE room to safely act, give our community a chance to heal, and build unity.

The proposal? For two weeks:

> - Refrain from discussing the CoC changes, or the pronoun elements of the incident. No upvotes either.
> - Be nice. Be very nice. Channel your inner Mr. Rogers.
> - Redirect users to this answer when they do try to discuss the CoC.
> - Continue with other protest actions that don't conflict, and don't let the core issue die.

In that last point, "don't let the core issue die" refers to the behaviour that led to Monica's termination, and everything that came after. Namely:

- Failure to follow due process.
- Lack of respect for, and trust in moderators.
- Lack of engagement with the community.

The [original post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335772/630222) goes into much more detail, especially about the why. It needs some community love before adoption, specifically in crafting realistic demands. Help is appreciated!

Comment: Two weeks where no one posts about the CoC? The SO team would be relieved and overjoyed! "*Finally, a break, from those pesky meta users who never stop complaining.*" They might even think that users have forgotten about Monica and how badly they treated her.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Focusing on SE's treatment of Monica instead of the CoC changes is the point of this action. Demanding respect for our moderators is something everyone in the community can get behind, whether or not they agree with the CoC changes. Kind of a "stay on message" kind of thing, not a "go away" kind of thing.

Comment: @Mari-LouA in the last point "don't let the core issue die" although I could have elaborated more. In the original post I describe it as: SE abruptly fired a community moderator without due proccess, spoke to the press about her in a defamatory way, and will not participate in two-way dialogue with her about it."

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've clarified a bit in this post.

Comment: I'm not against easing the pressure as a tactic, but this answer doesn't begin to indicate what's the overall strategy other than that.

Comment: Seems to me that what you consider the core issue is only part of much larger issues that have been festering for much longer than just the recent CoC debacle

Comment: @einpoklum do you mean this answer specifically or the linked one? If it's this answer specifically I may just block quote the majority of that answer to clarify. If it's that answer obviously I need to rework it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA that was their excuse, but the real problem was the lack of warning, due process, communication and respect. I think we can focus on all of those things without making it about pronouns.

Comment: @charlietfl I agree; Monica's termination is more of an inciting incident than a core issue. Part of resolving the core issue is resolving that incident, but doing that won't fix everything. I'll take a stab at improving that part of the answer.

Comment: @charlietfl Okay, made an edit attempting to improve on that.

Comment: Logo has been around for decades I had it on my amstrad 6128 back in the 80s, indeed it is a turtle app, down, lt 90, fw 100, ... to make it draw like an etchasketch