# Has there been a significant change of activity in the 29 old beta sites that graduated in August 2019 since the graduation?

Tags: discussion, statistics, beta-sites, site-lifecycle, full-sites

In August 2019, [29 of the oldest beta sites graduated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta) (in name at least) in an attempt to "mean the end of the monolith we currently refer to as "Graduation" in favor of a well-defined set of small targets to achieve the various elements that made up "Graduation"".

This is now more than six months ago and I wonder what the practical impact was on the sites' activity like visitors, number of new questions, answer rate, number of votes, user happiness, ...?

One could for example compare activity with the six months before August 2019 or use a control group of old beta sites that are still beta (Genealogy & Family History, Robotics, Politics, Sustainable Living, Tridion, Reverse Engineering, Open Data) or graduated sites that have a low number in questions per day (Anime & Manga, Bicycles, Christianity, Quantum Computing, Photography, Movies&TV, ..).

Comment: I've written some SEDE queries to compare the number of posts and votes in different periods: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334638/295232 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339471/295232

Comment: @Glorfindel That will be very helpful. I haven't managed yet running queries on different sites databases at the same time.

Comment: Very nice query @Glorfindel ran it on a period last september and a period in the end of january. Some sites really grew (% in the + 100's) and some sites really dwindled down to 1 or 0 Q+A per week. I imagine those are more or less dead.

Comment: There wasn't a lot of time between graduation and the giant mess, on Outdoors.SE a number of the most active users quit or reduced activity due to that, so I don't know a direct comparison will be all that helpful

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh You could try to detect effects relative to control sites. The fallout might have influenced all sites equally on average. But it's an important thing to keep in mind.