# "The Loop May 2020" contains inaccessible image with no transcription

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, accessibility, the-loop

In the latest blog post, [The Loop, May 2020: Dark Mode](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/05/26/the-loop-may-2020-dark-mode/), there's an image directly after the first line. It contains a chart and looks like it contains useful information, which is nice.

However, if you can't see images (or are using a screen reader or something), then... you can't access any of the information on the chart. This is what it looks like if I disable images:

[image: Screenshot of the blog post, showing the first line of text, a big blank space, and then a continuation of the text.]

This is a regression of sorts; in the Q2 Community Roadmap blog post, there was a very nice chart included that was *not* in image format (which has the additional benefit of being able to copy-paste, and of being dark when dark mode is enabled):

[image: Screenshot showing text chart in the Q2 Roadmap blog post]

Could you please either *at least* add alt text for the image in the May 2020 Loop blog post, or, preferably, abandon the chart-in-images thing and just use the text charts?

Comment: I do realize this was posted after the feedback post was posted, but I was writing this before it was posted and didn't realize that the feedback question had been posted in between me starting to write this post and hitting "post".

Comment: Related: [Who in the company is responsible for accessibility?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342787/336163)

Comment: @mindstormsboi - That blog post... is what this question is about...

Comment: This post is the one you're talking about: https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/05/26/the-loop-may-2020-dark-mode/?cb=1